# Is it bad to delete my own posts?

Tags: support

I know this answer exists but I didn't see it. Say I write and create a long question on SO and while working through it, I am able to write it much more succinct.

- Should I just create a new question and delete the old one or edit the old question itself?
- Would deleting a bunch of my old questions cause me to get banned on SO?

Comment: It'd probably be better to edit the question as opposed to deleting it, as deletion can have adverse affects on how close you are to a question ban.

Comment: Also, editing the questions bumps the question back up towards the top, as though you had just posted a brand new question. I don't know whether there is a major difference in that behaviour between new and edited question, but at the very least, you don't need to create a new question, if you're also concerned about your existing question not getting viewed after editing.

Comment: ahh, thx. good info. mostly concerned about question ban - good to know about editing going back to the top. I guess also if I want to put a bounty, it gets faster to period where I can offer.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that deleting questions is going against what Stack Overflow is all about. Stack Overflow is a place for problems to be posted and *answered* so the next user with that problem can easily find their solution. To create, basically a database of questions with answers to help out everyone and those with problems to find their solution. If you answer your question or it was a small error, *post* your answer or edit the post.

I truly believe that deleting post is a waste of people's time who read the question and tried to help.

Also, to answer the question at hand, yes it will cause you to get banned. Deleting one every once and a while probably won't get you banned if you keep a good rep and contribute to the community.

Comment: I think you're assuming every question is helpful. If a question has a bunch of negative downvotes and obviously doesn't benefit anyone, then the traffic (i.e. view count) it generates will simply represent those individuals that have wasted their time.

Answer (score 2):

If it is bad depends on what you delete. If it is only negative scored, non-accepted posts you'll be out of trouble (unless you're in or close to a question or answer ban) but deleting posts that are accepted or have a high score might be a case of destroying valuable content. That can be reversed by undelete votes from users with delete vote privileges.

Remember that you are already limited to only delete 5 answers per day as explained in the [answer from Bart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270275)

In some cases your delete actions raise a moderator flag. The system detects certain delete behavior (upvoted posts, accepted answers) so a moderator can step in to prevent any loss of quality posts due to rage quits or other cases of abuse or mishaps.

If you are close to question or answer ban (a warning is shown when you post something) deleting negatively scored posts might bring you quicker to the ban.

The purpose of Stack Overflow is to be a repository of quality questions and answers. If you feel you need to delete posts often go ask yourself if you should have posted at all.

Putting effort in editing your posts into shape is preferred above deleting and starting over.