# You have deleted 5 answers today, further deletes are blocked

Tags: support, vote-to-delete, rate-limiting

I have decided today to just delete some of my zero-voted answers that I found redundant (better answer was there). I did not delete those that were alone (the only answer) or at least could help (not that bad answer). But the system prohibited me to delete 6th (as the tooltip state: *You have deleted 5 answers today, further deletes are blocked* or something like that).

I wen to Help Center and typed *"further deletes blocked"* to find why. No good answer. I have started writing this and checked all the suggested topics. No... can you tell me **why is it blocked? Is this *potentially* a bad behaviour?**

---

**EDIT**: Some quotes from this [meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98747/245167) pointed out by [Infinite Recursion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2982225/infinite-recursion):

*Then [this bug report from Mar 31, 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85523/148310), indicates that the problem has risen from the dead -- [despite this moderator's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82884/148310), saying:*

> **Each time** that I've seen it (pruning subpar answers), it's been a user who **is deleting their own redundant zero-upvote answers**. Can you
>   tweak the algorithm slightly so answers with less than one upvote
>   don't count towards tripping this flag?

[**Accepted answer:**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98747)

> This limit is not a bug but intentional, it is meant to prevent
>   rage-quitting users from deleting all their answers. But you're right
>   that it ideally should not prevent you from cleaning up your
>   substandard answers. We only want to prevent users from deleting
>   valuable content, so **I'd support leaving out unaccepted answers with 0
>   or lower score from this calculation.** Though upvoting behaviour
>   depends on the site and the tag, sometimes good answers don't get
>   enough visibility to receive upvotes. One could also make only
>   negatively voted answers exempt from the limit.

Comment: It's blocked because people tend to delete all their answers when they are rage-quitting. Everything on SO  is rate-limited for a reason.

Comment: [Related post1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98747/245167) and [post2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85524/245167)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: Thx, I will read that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As described in [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide), you indeed have a maximum of 5 answers you can delete each day.

This limit exists because it does happen on occasion that an upset user rage-quits and wants to take all "their stuff" with them in the process. So you get to delete a couple, but can't go on a mass-delete spree.

Comment: OK. So, it was not that bad idea (they were really redundant and not that good as the accepted answer), but I have just faced the system created to protect rage-quits (mass-delete spree by angry user).

Comment: @firda if you have determined you can't make them better answers other than repeating what others have already stated, it's not necessarily bad. Now, there might still be an influence on an answer-ban at some point. Perhaps. So you still don't want to go too crazy. But occasionally cleaning out an answer when you have plenty of others that are positively scored, I don't think is a problem really.

Comment: I cleaned up the comments here, which were going completely off topic from the question and answer. If you wish to have a discussion about the legality of content licensing, please ask another question about this so that it can be discussed there.

Comment: @firda - seems like the reasonable thing to do would be to take a day at a time :)) (I'd only need a month to remove all my redundant stuff...)

Comment: Coincidence on the avatars of Bart and the most recent editor, @CodyGray?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Looks like Cody likes to keep an eye on Bart...

Comment: Are Bart and Cody Gray siblings or something?

Comment: We are still trying to figure out which one is the sock puppet.