# Why are there so many rules and restrictions?

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting, rules

For example, I've ran into these types of restrictions:

- can't mark an answer as correct within the first 10 minutes of posting a question
- can't delete more than five posts a day
- can't comment more than X times per minute
- etc

It just makes life harder because I have to go off and do something else for X minutes and then come back when I could just do everything I want to do on the site in one go.

Comment: It's because of all the bad robots.

Comment: Related from MSE: [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

Comment: because we are different...

Comment: Because of the great curse of SO: anonymity.

Comment: Each of those restrictions were added after repeated Bad Behavior by other users. It's an *effect*, and those rotten apples were the cause. And we have to suffer for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers & comments. What's the reason for down voting the question?

Comment: @migu: Lack of research. As indicated in Pekka's answer, at least some of the limitiations you mention have already been discussed on meta.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The rules *(well most of them)* exist for good reasons!

> can't mark an answer as correct within the first 10 minutes of posting a question

This allows other people to have a chance to provide a better answer than the one you would've previously accepted.

> can't delete more than five posts a day

One reason this is in effect is to stop rage-quitters from deleting all their good answers. We don't want good quality posts being removed just because someone is not a fan of the site anymore.

> can't comment more than X times per minute

Never ran into this one. But I know there is a can't comment more than once every 15 seconds rule. This is to help slow down users from leaving the same comments over and over again on many posts. For example "check out my question here" comments, or "please upvote my answer", etc.

Answer (score 15):

Many limitations and rules on Stack Overflow may look bizarre at first. However, most of them have a complex history, and are a solution to an actual problem that occurred on the site at some point in time.

The limitations on deletions, for example, came from users rage-quitting the site, deleting all their previous questions - and more importantly, the answers to them. The rate limit is one of several restrictions designed to fight this kind of vandalism.

Many restrictions are controversial among the community. We all [hate the comment rate limitation too, for example.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35501/please-return-the-comment-rate-limit-to-a-flat-30-seconds)

Most of these limitations have one or more related Meta discussions that help understand the reasoning behind them.

- [Here's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270274/you-have-deleted-5-answers-today-further-deletes-are-blocked%20abou) discussion on the delete rate limit.
- [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47448/allow-me-to-accept-an-answer-immediately) is the reasoning behind not allowing accepts immediately