# Why was BalusC temporarily suspended from SO?

Tags: discussion, moderation, users, banning

I hope this is the right place to ask this, but I was just browsing the JSF tag and saw BalusC, one of SO's top users, was banned.

See https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc

Now I looked at the rules in the provided link at
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box

None of these seem to apply to this user. If anything, this concerns a top SO user whose public behavior is an example to most of us. His answers are very much respected in the JSF and Java communities and not having BalusC here anymore would be absolutely a negative thing for both SO and all users who use his answers.

Is this maybe a glitch in the SO system or is he really banned?

Comment: Well, seven days are bearable. I've been myself there as well :-P.

Comment: The suspension was for 7 days, and its for "cooling down" so maybe he was just upset? That reason is also used for ragequitting users. Obviously we probably will never know the *real* reason for privacy reasons. AFAIK suspension reasons are private unless the user chooses to reveal them.

Comment: The reason for a time out given to a user is private between them and moderators, but no this is not a glitch.

Comment: It is *really* difficult to imagine BalusC doing anything that would get him banned like that. But then, I'm sure there was due diligence etc.

Comment: Here's a small clue as to what triggered this: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28622773/revisions , http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28635413/revisions

Comment: His deletion policy is definitely not in line with community guidelines, but with over 15,000 answers authored, perhaps some leeway should be granted. And if there really was no communication about this beforehand (like, ever) then a ban seems extreme.

Comment: All I can say is that it's generally standard policy to briefly suspend someone who appears to be rage-quitting by deleting a ton of content. That prevents further deletions while this is being discussed. I can't speak for the moderator responsible, but that's possibly what happened here. Usually, this is handled quietly in a private discussion rather than on Meta or on Google+, but I guess we're past that now.

Comment: @Brad but in this case - if BalusC's account is correct - he was banned without warning, then sent a canned message inviting no discussion at all, not even mentioning a lift of the ban as a possibility! If that's standard policy then the policy needs to be changed, right now.

Comment: Wow, this is bad, bad publicity for SO. I'm fairly new (activly) on SO, but was thinking of doing quite similar things. I can imagine a 7 day ban if this happened repeatedly and only then if it still happended after good proffesional communication between grown-ups.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Typically self-destruction of content comes with a suspension, regardless of the user involved.  If the user responds to a message explaining their actions, etc then we can lift the suspension and in some cases do lift it.  But we can't know what the user was doing or why without feedback from them.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm not sure how the SO mods handle this, but in cases where something destructive is going on I probably wouldn't modify the mod message template and just try to stop the problem as fast as possible. In cases like self-vandalism suspensions aren't meant as punishment but mostly as the fastest way to stop any further actions of that user. The message template might be somewhat misleading in such situations, but any reply would be taken seriously (all mods get them).

Comment: @bluefeet What do you mean by "without any feedback"? [Here's more than enough feedback](https://plus.google.com/+BaukeScholtz/posts/GRjfSAXYw9t) to lift the ban at once, because this is clearly a misunderstanding.

Comment: I dunno. Sure suspensions are supposed to be private between the user and the moderators. But when the person involved is such a high profile individual, trying to keep it secret is like trying to hide something while being the president of the US. It doesn't work, it will get out and everyone will know.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It's great that they decided to make this public on a site outside of the SE structure but they received a mod message and they should respond to that message explaining their actions.  The point of the mod message is for the user to respond internally to SE and to the mods.  There should be a trail of what happened here on site, not somewhere else on the interwebs.

Comment: @bluefeet *but the message doesn't really invite any response.* It says that if you feel you were justified deleting the content, you should contact *Stack Exchange* "through the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the page" - not the moderator. As to the mod, you can "let me know if you have any further questions." It's a terribly worded canned message, adding insult to the injury of a suspension for someone who's been active on SO nearly every day for more than five years.

Comment: Also I don't buy that a canned message had to be used to stop him from deleting more content; surely applying the suspension and sending the message are two separate steps?

Comment: There could perhaps be some tweaking of the canned message.  But the mod was right here-  we don't want people deleting their content because of "lack of feedback".  Deletion should only occur because of extreme situations-  such as suddenly discovering your answer was badly wrong.

Comment: @Pekka웃: It is not possible to suspend a user without sending a message, but you are allowed to write your own message instead of using a canned one if you feel like it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 When a message is sent to a user, there is an easy way for them to respond and many, many users respond to the messages.

Comment: @Pekka웃 No, you can't suspend without sending a mod message. The templates are from SE, they are not editable by mods. You have to send some message when you suspend, mods can edit it but they can't decide to suspend without any message.

Comment: @Pekka, okay, I was afraid my hunch about that was right, but... are you really implying the moderator should have known better *because the user who exhibited "destructive" behavior towards their own answers was well-known*? That's... not how I see moderation taking place, really, you know, in real life with actual humans. After a while, I suppose the usernames don't make a difference anymore and you're only judging behavior. And I think that's a good thing. Ideally, moderation should not even need to know the users it applies to.

Comment: @Gabe yes, his deletion policy is wrong. So you send him a moderator message and discuss it with him. When that fails, repeatedly, *then* perhaps you suspend him, after long and careful deliberation with your fellow moderators.

Comment: And in that time he deletes another dozen of his posts in a rage quit leaving a mess for the moderators to clean up.  And the content is lost in the meantime.  Sounds like a lot of effort for very little gain.  Whereas a rational user would have gotten that message and tried to contact moderators on his own, rather than grinding an obvious personal axe on social networking.  Yeah, I don't think the moderators did a thing wrong here.  I don't think Balus did anything horribly wrong either, this should have been fixed by 1-2 emails.  But of the two Balus is far more in the wrong, and not helping

Comment: @Gabe the worst possible  BalusC *could* have done is [deleting 5 answers per day.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270274/you-have-deleted-5-answers-today-further-deletes-are-blocked) How is that a rampage justifying an immediate suspension with no actual attempt to reach out to the user first?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi if you are a member in such exceptionally good standing as BalusC is, then yes I except moderators not to apply preferetial treatment, but *to assume a bit more good faith* than with someone who's been a member for two weeks. *Especially* since the "destructive" behaviour in question is deleting a number of answers that you can count with one hand, and no actual irreparable damage was being done.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Because the moderators can't read minds, can't know that's what he's doing, and have to act assuming the worst case.  The fact that he's an active user does not and should not buy him special privlidges.  Nor do I see any attempts by him to bridge the gap.  Balus is in the wrong.  Although I do think that as soon as he stops pouting he should have a quick email or two with the mods and get this straightened out.

Comment: @GabeSechan If I were a responsible moderator, I would think twice before suspending the 3rd highest rep user on a site with millions of users. Clearly there was either some serious oversight, or there's more to the story which neither side has disclosed.

Comment: @Pekka, the content in these answers was actually replaced by statements that... express great disappointment with their questioners, in no uncertain terms. I honestly think the moderator did not even *read* BalusC's username before acting, because the urge to act either came from a system-generated alert or from a flag. (And I'm surprised none of you veterans mentioned mishandling a flag -- that's still where most of the moderation "mistakes" are made, right?)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi can you point me to the statements you are referring to? I can't see them in the links Brad posted above, perhaps you are seeing something I'm overlooking. (If you mean "No Feedback, bye", it's clearly something to educate the user about, but hardly grounds for a suspension, no?)

Comment: Having read the comment thread and (highly originally) upvoted all of @Pekka's comments, I suspect that some sort of official documentation on moderation policies is in order... 5 answers a day for a newbie could be a rage quit but for BalusC or other high-rep users it can hardly be misconstrued as such. Time for another of your popular feature requests Pekka?

Comment: @Pekka, combined with *Not worth the effort anyway*, I can see a moderator suspending the user in good faith, yes. *Regardless of who they are.* But you're right, "replaced" was wrong in my previous comment, the message was sent in the edit description (as I often do myself).

Comment: @Mysticial Of course there is-  read the Google+ post, there's obviously a personal issue on at least one side.  But I don't think the mods should care how active he is-  in fact I'd be disappointed (and a little surprised) if they even looked at the karma count before hitting the suspend button.  He was doing something detrimental to the site, the standard policy action was taken.  Now if Balus has been trying to clear this up and is being ignored, you have an argument.  If he isn't, then he is the problem here and his suspension is probably a good thing.  Let him cool off.

Comment: @bradlarson I checked the activity log of BalusC before posting this and just checked it again, but didn't see anything that indicates rage-quitting.

Comment: @GabeSechan "the moderators can't read minds, can't know that's what he's doing..." Okay.... "and have to act assuming the worst case." Er...what??

Comment: @MikeBraun You can't see everything on another users account. Example, you can't see deleted posts, etc.

Comment: @KyleStrand Because assuming worst case means no additional harm done.  Assuming best case means additional harm done.  If you saw a guy standing next to your house shaking a can of spray paint which would you assume-  that he's going to use it or that he isn't?  Better to act defensively then to have a bigger mess to fix.

Comment: @GabeSechan As pointed out by Kukeltje, this meta question, and Balus's G+ post, are evidence of harm done. Balus isn't standing next to anyone's house shaking a can of spray paint.

Comment: @KyleStrand Yes, he was.  He was deleting content, sometimes in an insulting way.  Its the moderator's job to protect content.  THey have to assume that he was going to continue to do so, and protect the website.  They did the absolute right thing.

Comment: @bluefeet okay, I'm not such a power user so I didn't know that. I do think that for such a well known poster here on SO the suspension reason could be a bit more clear for the thousands of users who read his answers and look at his profile.

Comment: @GabeSechan we're talking about a max of 5 additional answers that could be deleted right? That's a *tiny* risk and IMHO well worth it to take to try to contact him first. As for the paint, if you saw your beloved spouse with whom you have no argument or fight stand next to your house with a miniature can of paint, would you also assume the worst and let the cops pick her up "just to be sure" without even asking her what she's doing?

Comment: That could be deleted-  he could still have edited out any number he wanted.  The mods acted correctly.  Remember this is a suspension, not a permanent ban.  Expecting the mods to talk to everyone first is completely unreasonable, as is giving him special privlidges (because having modded forums before-  respected member go rogue frequently).  You suspend them first and talk second, which is exactly what happened.  Balus should have talked to the mods rather than whined on google plus, it would have been cleared up in an hour or two.

Comment: @GabeSechan: deleting answers doesn't remove them irretrievably. As you can see in this case, the moderators can undelete. Even 5 such deletions a day is not a tragedy.

Comment: @JohnSaunders nor is a temporary ban, especially one that can be discussed and revoked.  Although I do agree with improving the language of the templated email.

Comment: @GabeSechan: my point is that what Balus was doing does not require "protection of content", since the content could easily be undeleted. And only 5 per day can be deleted.

Comment: @JohnSaunders SO if I go and edit every post I've ever written to "You didn't give feedback" that's ok because the posts can be reverted?  That's a silly stance.

Comment: @GabeSechan: I think it argues against an immediate suspension of a long-time user who does not have a history of causing trouble. Now, if he had a history of this, that would be a different thing. Then it would be reasonable to assume that his intention was the same as it had been in the past. But since there _is_ no past, I see no reason to assume the worst.

Comment: @GabeSechan: "Its [sic] the moderator's job to protect content." Really. [No kidding.](https://pinboard.in/u:dandv/b:6e91b9606eb8)

Comment: For users above a certain rep level (e.g. 250K on SO), there should need to be a quorum of mods to put a suspension in place. This would help to: respect the contributions the user has made to the site; eliminate the possibility that this is a personal issue between mod and user; and make it less likely that snap decisions would be made. This wouldn't exempt high-rep users from moderation - it would just remove many of the doubts over why a particular action was taken

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288274/please-implement-clause-7b-of-the-cc-by-sa-license?cb=1

Comment: Mistakes can be avoided if some people weren't so happy about how fast they can pull the trigger.  George knows BalusC, he's been around long enough to know him.  He should of reached out to him to make things right.  Instead he pulled the trigger too fast.

Comment: @JonH: that's a perfectly valid view, though having read George's answer here, I'm not minded to agree that he was seeing "how fast [he] can pull the trigger". Sounds like some lessons will be learned, anyway.

Comment: Shrug I hope some lessons were learned, I've been on this site for quite some time, pretty much BalusC and about 12 others BUILT this site based on their experience.  Without their knowledge this site would have not taken off like it should.  Does that not warrant a personal one on one to ask why this has happened.  Do we have to snoop so low to "deactivate" people who are at his level?  Its a total turn off to other users to see how much we are valued.

Comment: @JonH:  Do we *have* to put them on such a pedestal?  I can appreciate that the guy was around since forever, but **deleting content is unacceptable.**  Regardless of their motivations, the content isn't there for *them*, it's there for **everyone**.  At the bare minimum the moderators acted in the correct way, and the changes in line for situations like this will definitely improve this edge case.

Comment: Wow, it's true : the bigger they are.. they harder they fall. I got helped by balus before, great guy. It's a shame that this happened. I hope Balus doesn't quit, ... but who knows

Comment: But isn't BalusC a moderator also? I thought mods were immune?

Comment: @MikeBraun - *man* htis is getting emotional

Answer (score 249, accepted):

We have three problems here that I see:

1. A well-respected member of the community saw fit to delete (and deface) a few of his (many) answers. Why he did so I can only guess based on what he wrote; his reasons are his own.
2. The system sounded an alarm based on... fairly stupid heuristics. 5 deleted answers in a day is pretty alarming for most users, but when you average > 2 answers per day *every day* it's hardly a real problem. By volume, this is hardly a great loss; by % of total contributions, it's nothing.
3. The pre-written message created for these scenarios is... Well, it hits some sour notes, which isn't particularly great when someone actually *is* rage-quitting and certainly counter-productive when used in cases where the recipient *isn't*.

I can't fix #1. I hope BalusC sees this discussion - regardless of his rationale, it's clear that others here also feel that deleting answers like those that were removed is a loss *for the greater community* - regardless of whether or not the original recipient cared. IMHO, the essence of Stack Overflow is who the *asker is and whether they respond shouldn't matter* - we're writing for the ages here, whether we think about it that way or not; askers are but the providers of grist for that mill.

We *can* fix #2 and #3 though - **and <s>we will</s>** [Update 4/7/2015: *we now have*]. I've already discussed a better trigger mechanism with George and some other moderators, and a better canned message with Robert Cartaino - we'll try to get both of them updated ASAP.

This is my fault; George acted in good faith, based on the information he was given in the little time that he had to do so. But I've known this was a problem waiting to happen for at least 3 years now, I've had to clarify it too many times for mods on other sites, and yet I never got around to changing anything. I'm ashamed - moderator tooling and guidance are linchpins for this system, and I let this one shear off. I sincerely apologize for my neglect.

Comment: A similar thing happened to me in my former membership - whether by mistake or not, when I had the deletion countdown happening, I received that canned message, was suspended, and could not stop the countdown - but that is past (and nothing needs to be done) - my point is, good on the team for fixing this up.  Onwards and upwards!

Comment: @SabreTooth: Wow, the suspension made it impossible to stop the deletion? That's a major bug SE has to correct, whether you ever again request deletion and get suspended or not. Though it's quite obvious how that could creep in.

Comment: I've occasionally deleted answers when I wanted to disengage from a question, when I've decided that the question wasn't a good one and my post was keeping it from getting swept up by the roomba, or when I decided (based on lack of feedback from the OP) that it wasn't a good answer and because of my answer there discouraged others from trying to provide a better answer. Are these actions helpful or hurtful to the site as a whole? And if the answer is "it depends", then shouldn't it be a discussion between me and a mod about the quality of the posts rather than a push of a button?

Comment: Yes, @MichaelT. The irony here for me is that I've probably deleted a greater % of my answers than most other people, and of course was never suspended or even warned about this *because no checks for such behavior were added until much later*. I used to tell the Progse mods that their job wasn't done until my profile was mostly grey...

Comment: @Deduplicator it was a little while ago, I am good now - having fun on SE again

Comment: For me, the canned message is quite good. The only issue was using it with a high rep user instead of writing a tailored message. Balus deserved more attention/respect due to his large contribution to SO (even being wrong in this case).

Comment: This is, quite simply, an absolutely fantastic answer, one of the best examples of this kind of thing I've ever seen, and a privilege to read. Massive kudos to you, Shog.

Comment: I disagree with #2 being a problem. BalusC didn't realize that his behavior was a problem, and it could have continued indefinitely if it hadn't been flagged. But, it would be nice if those heuristics would alert the user in question first, so that user has a chance to correct that behavior.

Comment: As balus mentioned himself why in the world is there a delete button if he shouldn't be deleting.

Comment: There's a direct answer to that question which would fit in a comment and explain nothing ("because sometimes it's useful to delete posts"), and there's another answer that won't fit in a comment but might actually cover some of the historical tensions that exist behind this, @JonH. If you want the latter, post a separate question, please.

Comment: @JonH why wouldn't there be a delete button? Say a user posts a useless or wrong answer to a question which is then downvoted. It is a net loss for everybody if that answer is not deleted, and a time waste to delete it through review queues. If the user self-deletes, it's a net win for everybody involved. It is _not_ meant for deleting useful content (which is why it's heavily rate limited), and especially not when the reason is something as inane as OP not accepting or responding to an answer, as was the case with at least one of BalusCs posts.

Comment: Just a quick suggestion, since this seems like such a hot topic.  It appears that SE has some fine-grained control over alerting (even if the alert triggers could be better defined).  But, like most sites, does not have fine-grained enforcement.  If a user is perpetrating action that triggers an alert, then should there not be a way of suspending just that particular action? (in this case, the ability to delete content).  To my mind, every action should be (or have a corresponding) permission that can be granted or denied.

Comment: Its a hard thing to automate correctly.  I have a few questions that I realize were of poor quality for various reasons, and that cannot be reworded to work because the very premise of the question is off.  I am somewhat fearful of deleting them because of these rules, and to see a top ranked member get banned is icing on the cake.  Please strongly reconsider how the robot is going to work into the future, as well as providing a special warning to users after deleting many posts *before* they get banned (something more substantial than the current little popup).  Im glad to see this is a WIP.

Comment: My proposed adjustments to this trigger are in the dev-work queue for next week, @BAR - they make this a *lot* more strict, focusing on activity that is clearly both unusual and very likely harmful. The intent of this trigger was to identify rage-quits, not micro-manage deletions - I'm bringing the actual test inline with that goal.

Comment: The system worked as intended. An user deleted useful content without appropriate reasons. I don't think we should change the trigger. Even high rep users get hacked or have bad days and it's helpful to give them a timeout to rethink their actions. In this case the suspension did hurt the community more than the deletions, therefore it would have been better to disallow edits of old posts (without review) and deletions but allow new contributions.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer The bigger system worked as intended, but on a much deeper level than that. A controversial action was taken, the community was able to openly discuss and express their opinions, the opinions were considered seriously with a bigger picture in mind, and a reasonable resolution was presented. Can't ask for much more than that. Regardless of the details of such-and-such warning triggers, I'd call this a great success for SE's model and philosophies.

Answer (score 110):

There are a few parts here; I'll explain each of them separately.

The user in question recently defaced a number of their upvoted answers; it was brought up through an automated flag (deletion of content).

Here are some of the answers that were defaced ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28622773/revisions), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28635413/revisions), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29051229/revisions), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29032361/revisions), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28622804/revisions), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28608122/revisions), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28586829/revisions), [8](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28839360/revisions), [9](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28865372/revisions), [10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865563/conditionally-render-a-ui-element-in-jsf-2-0/28866285#28866285), [11](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19679973/revisions), [12](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28557207/revisions), [13](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28538554/revisions), [14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535797/how-to-resolve-com-sun-faces-config-configurelistener-contextdestroyed-during-mi/28538147#28538147), [15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320220/commandlink-do-not-pass-request-parameters/28320449#28320449)...(of 20 that I counted so far).

Clearly, this is concerning. Any time a user not only deletes their content, but purposefully obsfucates it; we want to figure out what's going on.

We take destruction and defacing of content seriously. It makes sense, since without content, we don't have anything.  That's why we don't let question askers unilaterally delete their own questions with upvoted answers; and that's why we have a mod message specifically tailored to destruction or defacing of people's own content.

In this case, a very high percentage of content had upvotes -- in most cases it had multiple upvotes, meaning multiple people found it useful.

It's normally strange to find users deleting their own upvoted content, it's even more strange to have it defaced as well.  A plausible scenario would be someone hacking into their account to 'get back' at them.  With that many answers, it's not surprising if it went unnoticed.

I sent Balus [the message linked to in his Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+BaukeScholtz/posts/GRjfSAXYw9t).  There are a few important things to note about this message:

- It's a templated message. This is so that moderators speak with a unified voice; and don't have to rewrite the same thing over and over for very common issues.
- The suspension was 'automatic' on the part of the message. If you send someone that message, the system strongly recommends suspending them. Since this was the first 'infraction' (if you can call it that), 7 days is the amount the system chose.
- The purpose of the suspension is to put a stop to the defacing, and figure out what's going on.

The final part is that I've been on a plane for most of the day. When I issued the message and suspension, I was about an hour outside of Portland with 10% battery left.  I did leave a note for the moderators in the Blue Room so that if something happened, they'd know what and why.  This is literally the first thing I saw when I opened my laptop at the hotel; and I'm responding as such.

In general, answerers should not deface their own content, whether it's deleted or not. If you find yourself deleting your upvoted content, the question is: Why?  If it's due to a lack of feedback, remember this:  answers don't just help the OP, they help everyone that has that same issue.

If you believe the question is never going to be of use to anyone, vote to close or delete the question (if it fits one of our stated reasons for closure).

I've reached out to Balus as well.

Comment: This makes it totally understandable what went on - even though it arguably would have been best to just reach out to him first, without the suspension. But it's always easy to judge in hindsight when you're not involved. Then what remains is that the message template sucks. It is badly worded, doesn't invite any actual interaction with the moderator about the issue at hand or the penalty, and should be fixed to address cases like this.

Comment: Yeah, that templated message feels like a slap across the face with a cactus... ([specifically this species](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opuntia_chlorotica#/media/File:Opuntia_chlorotica_7.jpg))

Comment: @Pekka웃 That's the problem with templates. Unfortunately, taking the time to write a tailored message to everyone takes more time than understanding is saved (prohibitively so). Most of the time people don't respond to our messages, and if they do, it's not usually a very nice response.  It creates a negative feedback loop for us where it's advisable to just say what needs to be said and not invite a discussion on the topic.  You're right; it sucks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this rule to delete / deface your own answers is not really clear. I wasn't aware of it for one. If this behavior can be auto-flagged, can't the system generate a warning for the user first? I agree that SO needs content, but we also need people answering! And people like BalusC are rare, we don't want them to stop answering here, do we?

Comment: @MikeBraun there are two separate issues: 1) Yes, the system should let someone know they're doing something we think is 'bad' without requiring moderator intervention. 2) People do not get special treatment; that strikes at the heart of fairness and does more to hurt the impartiality of moderators than anything else. More than anything, we strive to maintain our fairness and impartiality.  All that said, we're currently talking about ways to improve this flag and lessen its... harmful effects.

Comment: True, templates generally suck, but this one could really be improved with little effort. Feature request [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288238/fix-the-mod-ragequit-message-template-to-not-sound-like-a-jerk)

Comment: Template or not, only if it was a fully automatuc process, I can understand it. Otherwise, /"taking the time to write a tailored message to everyone… "/ BalusC is not everyone… So I hope the ban is reevaluated soon… But I appreciate the clarification

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in 7 days of suspension SO is going to lose (as in "not gain") more answers than those 20 that he erased. Please talk, understand each other, resolve this issue and remove the suspension.

Comment: **answers don't just help the OP, they help everyone that has that same issue** And that makes it even worse to deface it after "weeks with not feedback" (paraphrased from the G+ post). The OP already got their answer, so what's the point of punishing every single other person who might have benefited from it in the future? The only person this **doesn't** hurt is the OP of the question. That's the part about all this I really can't wrap my brain around.

Comment: @georgestocker about the "special treatment", isn't that strongly ingrained in SO's rep system already? The more rep I got the more things I was allowed to do here. If we treat everyone truly equal, should we just give every new user access to every feature right away?

Comment: @ivarni I can't really understand the reason to delete those answers either, so I think it's good that some action was taken. But, to immediately suspend a user of the kind SO and the community greatly depends on, without prior history and without any warning, that's problematic. If next week John Skeet makes a mistake and is immediately suspended and slapped with a canned msg, then gets angry and decides to leave, SO will not become a better place for all of us.

Comment: @Pekka웃 *"been best to just reach out to him first"* - surely the point of the auto-suspension is to *stop the behaviour*, quickly, in case it is a hack or deliberate defacement or whatever. Then the reason behind it can be investigated without the risk of the behaviour continuing. As far as I can see, this worked pretty much how it's supposed to.

Comment: @MikeBraun I don't agree with this having limits on privileges based on rep ensures that before gaining certain privileges a user has had a taster of life on SO and hopefully once they reach a certain privilege level they are a responsible enough member of the community.

Comment: George - You sometimes go too fast when it comes to being a moderator...I've seen it before from you.  Don't you think you should of reached out to one of OUR BEST users of the system before you pulled the trigger?

Comment: Obviously this situation is regrettable.  I'd point out that both removing content from the site and failing to engage the site properly (if you ask a question, you need to upvote and accept of "the right" answer) are bad for the "community."  Why is a temporary ban a better or easier resolution than just letting it slide?

Comment: @tmyklebu: Failing to accept "the right answer" is not something the system can detect ***at all***, much less automatically, since the right answer is specifically defined as the answer that worked for the asker. It is therefore completely absurd to suggest temporarily banning anyone who fails to accept answers "properly"; the only possible option, then, is to let that slide. But this should not prevent all other unhelpful actions from being appropriately dealt with, especially when they are active instead of passive and remove content instead of failing to mark it as precisely as possible.

Comment: @JonH Deface and Deletion of Good Content has historically called for the action I took. This is not new. The purpose of the suspension is to stop the deface/destruction and then figure out from there.  Normally users simply send us a message and say, "Yea, this is why I'm doing this" and we reach an understanding (which isn't always the same).  As Shog9 has written in his eloquent (and spot on) answer, it's been somewhat broken for three years at a system level, so I'm not sure it's fair to blame a moderator for doing exactly what we were supposed to do.

Comment: @JonH That said, if you want to have a separate conversation about my propensity to 'pull the trigger'; let's talk about that.  If you'd like, bring it up in a meta post with examples or I'll jump into chat with you and we can discuss it. I do work for the community, after all.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Failing to accept and upvote the "right" answer messes with the incentive system that makes the site work.  Two wrongs don't make a right, but I understand why the guy's pissed off.

Comment: What about deleting my own answer with zero votes? or negative votes? Is it also considered destructive?

Comment: @Noseratio No; it's not. Deleting your own content is not destructive in of itself; it all depends on the how (do you deface or straight delete), and the type of content with the type of question it answers.  It's taken in sum.

Comment: George since you deleted my comment as usual I'll take you up on your offer...when I get some free time I'll look you up on chat.  Your moderation skills to me are gun happy and just from your content alone I can see how much you love that power.  Hmmm when are elections again...

Comment: Probably next month, @JonH. BTW, George didn't delete your comment - there are a few other mods around.

Comment: @tmyklebu: You're apparently missing my point that it is literally impossible to do anything at all about failure to accept/upvote answers, and that it is ***not*** impossible to do something about ragequitting or what looks like it. So again, arguing that we should *of course* do the same nothing in all cases of "makes the site worse" is just sophistry. That's not to say that Balus has no point here; no one* is arguing this turned out well. But the general motive behind this mechanism is sound, even if the details are distressingly shabby at the moment. (*For suitably low values of "no one".)

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Well, Balus *can't* really take all his toys and go home---it's not clear that a ban is the right default course of action for high-rep users with tons of answers.  I understand why this all happened, of course.  What I wonder is whether, for high-rep users, some investigation and a balancing test before letting the ban fly would work better.

Comment: "without content, we don't have anything" -- Without users like BalusC creating well articulated answers, we don't have anything.  It's foolish to brandish the CC clause against anyone in such a bull-headed manner.

Comment: @peterporter what use are those well articulated answers if they've since been deleted by him?

Comment: Pekka for moderator. After reading this, that's my only conclusion. I'm not passing judgement on anyone else.

Comment: I only looked at the first three, but BalusC was the author of each of those posts. When an author discards their work, it isn't "defacement." Defacement is a loaded term, it indicates prejudgment of the situation, and that poisons further discussion.

Comment: @erickson: It seems reasonable enough to me. If an artist paints a nice painting and then, on finding it's not received well by critics or a client or something, grabs a can of spray paint and slaps a hasty coat over most of it before throwing it away, is that not both defacement and discarding? That's closely analogous to a) editing to remove useful content and then b) deleting the post entirely. Which is what happened.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Your analogy would be fitting if a) The spray paint could be removed without a trace at the click of a button, and b) the trash can was never emptied. BalusC has stated that when the content was indeed useful, he has applied his deleted answers to other questions.

Comment: @erickson: Then of course your opinion is that SO never suffers defacement at all, of any variety, since essentially *all* defacement can be reversed with the click of a button. (You can't reverse defacement made within the five-minute grace period, but that's an edge case.) Sauce for the goose is sauce for the gander: if blanking someone else's content with ellipses is defacement (and it *is*), then it's defacement on your own too.

Comment: @NathanTuggy You are presuming a lot, and exhibiting exactly the kind of prejudice I wrote about in my initial comment.

Comment: @erickson: How so? It's a simple matter of fact. BalusC did deface his own answers, by definition. That wasn't a good idea, but he should have been corrected verbally. The mods and SE team have learned from their mistakes and corrected this situation in particular. All is now solved, but to pretend that there was no problem at all is disingenuous: there *was* a real problem that was simply hammered far too hard.

Comment: @NathanTuggy "Then of course your opinion is ..." isn't seeking to understand. It's assuming you have all the answers. I never said there was no problem, I just said that the some of the loaded language being used doesn't facilitate solution. Don't put words in my mouth. The only fact here is that you are no mind reader.

Comment: @erickson: Well, OK. Thing is, logically, I don't see any way you can avoid that implication, so was taking a bit of a rhetorical shortcut to point out: this doesn't work the way you said. What *would* you consider defacement, out of interest?

Comment: Replacing correct content with incorrect content, abusive content, advertising, etc., would be defacement. In other cases, intent could make the difference between BalusC's actions being defacement or not. And in fact, his intent may have been to deface. The point is that coming out of the gate with an accusation of defacement would raise hackles for most people.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: once you post your answer is not yours alone, also it is better for the community to leave an answer. His behaviour will harm only the community and not the person who asked the question. A better analogy would be if he was working in a charity building wells in Africa and if he came back to destroy the wells because the guy who asked it in the first place did not say thanks without caring about the rest of this community.

Comment: @erickson: Defacing also covers blanking, replacing with meaningless punctuation, and similar, by general dictionary definition. (I refuse to link to a specific entry, because I don't want to be That Guy.) If you spray paint on a painting as in my analogy, that's defacement, even if you're not painting something else on top or scribbling profanity or ad slogans. Merely covering it over is sufficient.

Comment: @bluetrin but then take a guy who created 25.000 wells and works day and night to create more wells. Now 10 obscure wells in total in bad places with questionable water are closed by this guy. Without asking him for his reasons to do so, without negotiating with anyone, one sole guard tells this guy he is not longer allowed to create new wells, depriving thousands in real need from their water.

Comment: I agree that it should be 'suspension first, ask questions later'; I was suspended once for getting into a petty 'fight' with another user. When I received the automatic suspension message, I messaged back and admitted that it was entirely my fault; I was unsuspended as I admitted it was my fault & I apologised for it. TL;DR: The mechanism would never work if the user wasn't suspended in the first place.

Answer (score 23):

I would like to see we as a community respect moral rights. It's perhaps not something known in the US but CC-Licenses as being internationalized handle it IMHO.

- [What are moral rights?](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#what-are-moral-rights)
- [How do Creative Commons licenses affect my moral rights, if at all?](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#how-do-creative-commons-licenses-affect-my-moral-rights-if-at-all)

That means if it's a valid decision of the author to delete the content - even donated earlier - this might need to be respected.

This means: It's too easy to say it's just against community policy. It's most likely also too easy that CC won't allow to do this. There can be reasons you deny to use content given under license.

But the limit is very high.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288274/please-implement-clause-7b-of-the-cc-by-sa-license