# In Stack Overflow elections, should the vote counts be hidden until after the election?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderator-election

In the current Stack Overflow election, I noticed that the vote counts are displayed alongside each candidate. I wonder whether this leads to a 'hive mind' where people who already have a lot of votes attract more votes.

In real life elections, [reporters are often banned from reporting poll counts until voting has closed](http://www.article19.org/data/files/pdfs/publications/opinion-polls-paper.pdf) to prevent this from happening.

Do you think Stack Overflow elections should do the same thing?

Comment: Keep in mind this is only the primaries, and the top 10 move on. The final phase does keep votes hidden. (I'm not however defending this, just giving information)

Comment: Oh right, I couldn't remember what happened last time round.

Comment: Obviously this is happening with Martijn's election.

Comment: Yes, they should be hidden.

Comment: I am fairly certain Martijn would have just as many votes hidden or not.

Comment: I agree they should be hidden as I saw Martijn's score and considered voting on another (as he seems assured and there are a number of excellent canidates) but decided I should act in the same manner as if I didn't know the score as this would be a more honest

Comment: Related [Do not show the score for users during primaries](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76412/213963) (and also the linked questions to that one).

Comment: @JGreenwell Note that you can vote on everyone, so you don't have to be conservative! Not really sure how Martijn got 35 downvotes.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I can (and did vote on at least one other person) but I just wanted to point out that it could alter a person's voting

Comment: @JGreenwell Just to make sure you understand, you can cast a vote on *every single candidate*. (30 votes, in other words). Thus, not voting on someone because they are "assured" doesn't make sense, since the vote doesn't cost you anything (including the opportunity to apply that vote somewhere else).

Comment: While I'm not easily influenced myself, and plan to still revisit all candidate profiles, I agree that not showing the scores would be better. I don't see any benefit in showing the scores, and it could certainly give the candidates who get an early lead an advantage with voters who don't want to read all 30 profiles. Kind of interesting that negative scores are clamped to 0.

Comment: I do not know most of the candidates personally and looking back, I realize I felt compelled to vote for the best voted candidate.

Comment: @jakekimds have you considered voting on *all* of the candidates based on if you think they would make a good moderator or not?

Comment: @MichaelT Most of their pages look the same. I have never seen them before. I wouldn't know who makes a good moderator.

Comment: @jakekimds you read the [questionnaire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290096/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire). You look at their meta activity. You look at their reviews. The nomination post itself is often not enough, but that doesn't stop one from digging more - and the page itself gives you some of the tools to do it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: "Not really sure how Martijn got 35 downvotes." Because the downvoters were exercising their votes liberally :P

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I think votes should be hidden.

I just cast my votes and looked at the candidates. You can see the walking dead there just by the vote counts. Lot's of people having no chance at all and you don't even bother reading their text anymore.

It is not in the interest of the election to have a self-reinforcing effect/bias. Votes should be independent from one another and time-independent (they're not right now since later votes are biased by earlier votes). That's why we are randomizing the display order as well. Humans are easily biased.

Here's an idea:

```
.votecell .vote-count-post { display: none; }
```

Comment: I agree with you, they must be hidden, I don't see any advantages to show them. I just voted, and being honnest with myself, I could see that my finger wanted to click on the candidates that already had high counts. I finally decided to modify the CSS property of .votecell .vote-count-post and add display:none in the inspector.

Comment: Agreed. I found myself ignoring all the candidates with 0 votes, and figured that the community had already done the hard work and selected the best candidates, so I may as well agree with them. I just don't have enough time to read every candidate's description. It seems like a randomised order with no vote count would produce the most balanced election.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't even going to read the 0-score answer below this one, but then I read Blowski's comment and felt obligated to read it. "0" has powerful psychology. "These are not the candidates you are looking for, move along"

Answer (score 3):

I personally think the counters should been invisible until the user has voted. After a timer let's say 5 minutes after the last vote  (of the user) or a click on a *lock my voting* button the current results should been shown. So the user won't just follow the counters. The random order is also a good idea, just when there are the huge counters the lower voted candidates have already lost IMHO.

Comment: There's one huge problem I see with this: Not every candidate has done their questionaire yet. I don't know how many others did, but a few of my votes changed after reading answers to those 12 questions. I would have to wait until the very last minute to vote if votes got locked in on this at all. And if it was an optional button, I would certainly never use it.

Comment: About the questionaire, I also almost forget to answer them (even I already answered the top ten in notepad 3 days ago). The nominated users should been informed about that IMHO. However I get your point, that means you would upvote an user just because he added a *good* questionaire?

Comment: To be fair, if they look at the "Featured on Meta" posts, it is right there. My point is more that locking in primary votes is a bad idea. People can vote on their initial feelings, then, like me, read those answers, or check  more at how the candidates act, or anything like that and change their mind on someone. I don't care if the votes are hidden or not (but it's fun to go back and look) but it likely would cause a lot of people to wait until the last minute to vote/lock-in just so they can have a chance to change their minds. Probably why there is no lock-in on the primary election voting.

Answer (score -5):

Its still a valid topic after all this time.  Whatever ones' opinion is at this moment in this topic doesn't even really matter.  Peoples minds are very easily tricked in making subconsient decisions.  Everone is susceptible to it.  Examples enough. commercial spots of .2s interleaved into someones TV progr. makes you buy the products.   higher prices  / origin (made in 'germany') give people sense of value.  you see and hear it everywhere in society (where there is smoke there is fire...).  people are easily influenced and it is backed up by research.  I think its a bad idea to include votes.  In the end, the value of votes previously casted are just amplification of this type of influenced behavior. self-fulfilling proficy.

Comment: Did you know Baum mit Augen was made in Germany? I think it's working...

Comment: Did you know the american president has a tendency to bend facts to whatever suits his ego?  I think it's become an american thing...

Comment: I am quite aware. Not sure what that had to do with anything you or I were talking about here.

Comment: like i said... not related comment with no inherent value, ridiculizing/trivializing the posters' view.  same as yours. i've proven my point.

Comment: It was a joke. You were making a point in your answer about the efficacy of subliminal advertising, and you happened to use "made in germany" as an example. There was no bending of facts here, and no attempt to trivialize anything. Just a regular old joke.

Comment: I agree.  and yes, I did know he was German. It was just sarcasm about it being hard to try to post something contributing around here.