# Show current votes when skipping (or perhaps abstaining from) a review

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

The reviews in which I am unsure of the correct outcome and skip it, I would often like to see the votes so far.  Really, these are generally the ones I would be *most* interested in seeing the community's consensus (perhaps enabling me to make a more informed decision next time, or just satisfying my curiosity).  The only way to do this that I'm aware of, is to wait until the review is resolved (i.e. some unknown amount of time) and view the final results.

This would somewhat interfere with current functionality of skipping, particularly that it is possible to come back to a skipped review later.

Maybe instead of changing how skip operates, I would like to be able to *abstain* from voting, without leaving the possibility of returning later, and move directly to the current votes.

Comment: Hear hear! I've often thought this too.

Comment: You can always just open the page in an incognito window.

Comment: Wouldn't that create a bias?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I believe the OP means that they would like to see other votes & reasons once they have already made the decision not to review.

Comment: @Undo - Hadn't thought of that, to be honest.  That works for me.  Thank you.

Comment: @Undo Since that "hack" exists, one can question why the other votes aren't already accessible to begin with. It is almost as if we trust anonymous no-rep users more than we trust high-rep users with review powers.

Comment: But it's possible for you to skip a review then go back to vote on it if you just revisit that URL. Skipping doesn't mean you can no longer review, just that it's removed from the queue. This would mean it's incredibly easy to check consensus, go back to that url and then match the existing consensus.

Answer (score -7):

This would create a bias in the long term. Not for the current review, of course, because the stats would only be shown after you have made your decision.

But in the long term you would become more in-tune with the way the "group" thinks. Instead, you should be aligned with the rules and with what makes sense. It is not a good thing if you decide based on what others would decide.

We should not encourage group-think and conformism.

[A similar issue exists with the moderator elections.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290097/in-stack-overflow-elections-should-the-vote-counts-be-hidden-until-after-the-el) Quoting some related text:

> It is not in the interest of the election to have a self-reinforcing effect/bias. Votes should be independent from one another and time-independent (they're not right now since later votes are biased by earlier votes). That's why we are randomizing the display order as well. Humans are easily biased.

Comment: Nope, don't think I buy it.  If that were a concern, the votes should remain hidden even after you complete a review.

Comment: Priming is a problem, yes, and one which current review doesn't deal with entirely flawlessly, but *deliberate*, conscious consensus-building is not something to fear. If you can't learn from what others have decided in past situations, what on earth can you learn from? (Clearly, highly-upvoted meta posts should be right out.)

Comment: Learn from the rules and official policy. As an example for group think, most performance questions receive an impulsive "Measure it!" comment which is unhelpful and does not provide understanding to the OP. Stack Overflow is *very* prone to herd behavior. Programmers in general seem to be.

Comment: @boot4life: And is that sort of comment from review? Does it come with specific vote behaviors that would be affected by showing/not showing other voters' choices in review? Or is that just bog-standard knee-jerk reactions in action?

Comment: In my mind it's group think because the behavior spread around and many users are now doing it. Seems like a fashionable thing to do.

Comment: I mostly agree with you, but let me put something clear: if the group decided by discussion interpret guidance certain way is not "group thinking", but consensuated decision.

Comment: That is valid but you can't tell that from seeing voting results. You need to read a text where somebody presents an argument. Then *you* need to decide whether he is right.