# How do I decide on who to vote for in elections?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

I see that I'm asked to participate in elections. I've not really much interest in reviewing the behavior of each candidate and looking to see if they behave the way I like or not. Like a lot of complainers on this site, I'm sorta annoyed with the overzealous closing and whatnot.

How can I vote against this kind of thing, easily? (And thus, allow more users to vote and push back on behaviour that we're too otherwise spread-out to care or do anything about.)

Or am I just way too out-of-touch with how SO/SE runs overall?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but if it's "how do I vote for the candidates who will help keep more questions open", then you need to read the bios of each candidate and see how they responded when prompted with that or similar questions, and vote accordingly.

Comment: There are also answers to the questions [showing up](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290096/289086). You may desire to hold back on voting in the primary until you read those. Or you may not. How you vote is up to you. With the primary you can vote up or down on each candidate.

Answer (score 17):

Well, the only way to know how a moderator thinks and is likely to act is to read their nomination message (and [questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290096/871050)).

However, do note that the focus of all Stack Exchange sites are **quality**, closing and downvoting are tools to that cause (on the well known expense of user happiness). Moderators are generally expected to close and delete a lot more than normal users.

Comment: "on the well known expense of user happiness". Improving the quality attracts more experts who answer questions better, and users like that. So I think closing and downvoting create (long-term) happiness :)

Comment: @Oriol It's a love/hate cycle really. People hate being downvoted and closed, but that's the essence of what makes Stack Overflow great.

Comment: I could not agree more. I would add that I think some of the healthiest feedback to get is a quick close with a reason as to why (even if it is as embarrassing as "you didn't search hard enough"). Embracing a close or downvote for a poorly worded or misguided question can still help with development, although it does challenge that age old paradigm of "there are no stupid questions". However closing or downvoting without giving feedback is very, very poor form, and goes against the culture we wish to create here at Stack Overflow. So in short... close fast and hard, but at least leave a note.