# Can votes be changed in election phase?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

I see only 20 of the 29 candidates have answered the [questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290096/2246380). Some of the candidates likely to make it the election phase of the election have not answered the questionnaire yet. I want to vote based on all the top 10 candidates responses.

The [election phase](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) just started, Can I vote (pick 1st, 2nd and 3rd choice) and change them based on the answers added by the candidates yet to the answer the questionnaire?

Comment: yes.  You can change your vote until the election is over.

Comment: Thanks. I just cast my vote.

Comment: I cast 2 of 3; awaiting more pandering from the contenders

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. Though it doesn't say so anywhere on the actual election page, when you cast your final vote, this is displayed:

> You have cast your third vote, thanks for voting!
>   You can still change your votes until the election ends.