# Remove the limit on deletions for old zero vote posts

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, vote-to-delete, zero-voted-posts

Inspired by the new profile page, I was attempting to clean up some cruft. Deleting my old answers (more than 30 days old) with no votes (up or down) and other answers.

But there is a limit of 5 deletions a day. I would suggest to modify the limit on self deletion so that answers without activity (up or down votes or comments) do not count. If an answer has no votes or comments, it seems unlikely to have helped as either a positive or negative example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those SO "rules" that have gotten completely out of hand.  Your request has been posted many times before, always ignored.  The *original* goal of the delete limit was to stop rage-quitters from destroying their posts.  But it is blindly applied to *any* SO user today and requests to change the rule have been consistently poorly received.  People have been [thrown in the slammer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288229/why-was-balusc-temporarily-suspended-from-so) over this, most of the new moderator candidates will instantly suspend your account.  Just check the responses to [question #3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290096/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire?cb=1).

The weapon of choice to deny you managing your account like this is the CC-by-SA license that you implicitly agree to when you post an answer.  In which you implicitly give up ownership of your answer and agree that SE can keep a copy of it in perpetuity.  That also buys you the duty to maintain your post for the rest of your natural life, no matter how outdated and unhelpful it gets.  Particularly so when it is marked as the answer, you can't delete it at all.  And SO-users will remind you about that duty constantly.

Frankly, this is massively unproductive.  I personally don't post speculative answers anymore, just posting a comment instead.  Sometimes that works and the OP acknowledges that the guess was accurate.  But doesn't happen very often, most questioners are not very interested in building a Q+A artifact and just use the guess to move on with their job.

I did find an angle in the CC-by-SA license, there is a clause that hints at a *moral* right to no longer be associated with your post.  It found [somewhat receptive ears](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288274/17034), it is however not treated as an urgent matter right now.  Maybe that will change some day.

Meanwhile, as you can tell, SO users will continue to downvote these kind of proposals.  Much easier than actively being involved in collaborative editing.  Be careful what you post, you might regret it some day.

Comment: I'm not against the CC, and I understand the answer isn't for the person asking the question, but if there are multiple up voted answers deleting a years old answer with zero votes seems like the thing to do, for the sites sake.

Comment: I hear you.  It is not a factor at all in blocking you or generating the alert, but the odds a moderator will throw you in the slammer ought to be pretty low.