# Transparency request: why was this user suspended for posting two (now deleted) questions to meta?

Tags: discussion, moderators, account-suspension

So, [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3733568/user01928374655647382910019283) just came to meta to complain about another user who allegedly used sock puppets to gain a considerable amount of rep. He posted one question to the main site with links to offending posts, which was migrated to meta - and swiftly deleted by a mod. He then posted a second question directly to meta, which also got deleted instantly, and furthermore earned him a one month suspension.

My initial reaction to this is: What's happening? Here we have a user who is interested in keeping the site clean by reporting when they come across behaviour that seems to be against the site rules - and while their way of going on about this might not have been the best, it seems extremely out of line to suspend them for it. Second, swift deletion makes this completely intransparent - instead of posting any form of answer or comment to one of the questions and explaining to the user whatever they did wrong, the posts were instantly deleted and the user suspended. This feels like the worst action to take in this situation. IMO, the mod should have simply explained why the user was wrong without deleting anything or suspending anybody.

In the interest of transparency, I'd like to know the following:

- Why was the initial meta question deleted? I figured it might be because it linked to the user they accused of misbehaviour, but other meta questions frequently do so without getting deleted.
- It seems like the user was suspended because they basically reposted the gist of their deleted question. Why suspend a user for this long when all they did was reporting a perceived rule violation?

I hope I don't get suspended for asking this question...

Comment: i was present when it happened, he get an answer in comment, then 2 min later he asked the same question with a new account on SO

Comment: [Linking his new post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663353/reputation-gained-through-fake-account)

Comment: he asked more than 2 question for the same purpose, plus without real evidence of fraud, yes there was an old fraudulent question/answer but  nothing to panic about when we check the full profile of the targeted user

Comment: This came up on meta also last month, possibly same user just being insistent that "something" happen when it's already been dealt with. Wording is consistent. They just don't seem to accept that the situation has been handled and they've had it said to them multiple times.

Comment: I'm not accusing any mod of going on a rage suspension spree (if they would want to do so, I'd recomment visiting the java tag instead of meta); the suspension may very well have been the right thing to do. But I simply see no reason to delete the posts instead of leaving any kind of answer as to why the accusations are incorrect (or closing as a dupe, if it has already been discussed).

Comment: I have to add that the most recent incarnations of that question is a copy-paste of one of the comments I left under their first question a while ago. So not only is that questioner completely stubborn, they also keep posting content that is not theirs.

Comment: One person is for sure targeting that user for a reason... probably there is just one person behind the scene.

Comment: Initially I had assumed this was about something I did, and I was puzzled because I did leave a [comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296139/analyse-this-users-comment-and-reputation#comment202952_296139) explaining that they were in fact reposting the exact same meta post from last month (as @TZHX pointed out). Turns out, just *minutes shy* of the suspension, they had posted *yet again*, which was quietly removed by Martijn Pieters.

Comment: Removed the unnecessary swear word *albeit slightly censored*

Comment: This user has also **created yet another account** to get around their current ban: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296155/needs-validation-logic-in-so-system-for-any-user-to-earn-reputation-in-a-cheatin

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Because they **keep on asking it**:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294891/3001761
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294909/3001761
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294983/3001761
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296139/3001761

Apparently on multiple sites/accounts (the irony of creating multiple accounts to get around a suspension for insisting that a user with multiple accounts to get around self-voting restrictions be punished more is not lost on me...):

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/30663353/3001761
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296155/3001761

They have been repeatedly told that the issue is closed (the rep gained by cheating was removed years ago, so it's only the *legitimate reputation* from other users that remains), but are apparently unwilling to leave it alone.

---

As to why it gets deleted, to quote [Brad's answer on the original post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294934/3001761) (emphasis mine):

> I will probably delete this question once you read this **to avoid
>   public shaming of this user** for something that was addressed a long
>   time ago.

Comment: I agree with the user's account being suspended, but I still would like to know why his post in meta has been deleted (instead of just closed).

Comment: @Blas possibly because it serves no purpose but to point out a user who did something bad a long time ago, and has (presumably) redeemed themselves.

Comment: What @BlasSoriano said - that's a valid reason for the suspension, but I'm still on the fence about the deletion. The correct thing to do seems to be to answer this once and simply close any reposts as a dupe.

Comment: But if you answer or comment on that post, I could learn something.

Comment: What could you learn? Not to use sockpuppets for rep-whoring or you'll get caught? You should already know that.

Comment: I could learn what behaviour is needed to avoid (ranting, wrting without relaxing...) and how that behaviour should be addressed if I encounter it. The last edit seems ok as a reason to delete it.

Comment: I accepted this answer as it explains what's going on, although I don't entirely agree with the reason given by Brad for deleting the post(s). I would value transparency more than protecting the user in this situation, as it's not protecting something important (e.g. the user probably won't lose their job if their employer finds out they cheated on SO ages ago) but simply protects their imaginary internet points. But I guess it deescalates the situation - with the exception of alienating random bystanders like me who can't possibly comprehend what happened.

Comment: Don't know about the original post, but we're deleting the reposts simply because they have no reason to exist besides adding unnecessary clutter. Nothing to do with (avoiding) public shaming.

Comment: It's truly amazing, the amount of time and energy some people are willing to invest in acting like jerks.

Comment: @T.J. That's what the Internet is for, isn't it? Or was that porn?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder IMO this is another sign of our own success; we easily grow fat because we don't have to move much anymore to do our work and get our food. Similarly, acting like a jerk on the net takes very little time and effort with almost zero repercussions; you can do it without ever leaving your chair. And lo and behold; the world is full of overweight people and the internet is full of jerks and gigantic jerks. That's progress!

Comment: @Gimby: True that.

Comment: @l4mpi - Having that post up serves no positive purpose. The actions being complained about were taken care of two years ago, and the person responsible (despite the allegations of this user) gained absolutely nothing from it in the end. There's nothing educational there aside from "don't cheat the voting system or you'll be caught", which everyone already knows. I answered the user who was concerned about this, so once they had read that there was no reason to keep this up, particularly once I saw several people from Meta starting to attack the subject with concentrated serial downvotes.

Comment: @BradLarson while I agree that such a question isn't valuable, deletion doesn't feel like a good solution either as it's completely intransparent. I remember a similar situation a while ago where a user used a friends account to complain on meta about a long suspension (for rude comments, I think) - the question was swiftly deleted, and the friends account (which seemed to be in good standing with close to 1k rep) was either deleted or long-term suspended as well. For normal users, there is no way of knowing if such an action was reasonable or not, without asking about every single instance.

Answer (score 26):

Just a note to the suspension itself (in case you wonder if 30 days might seem a bit excessive) - this isn't the first time this has happened, the original suspension was for 2 days which (to me) seems like a pretty fair 'woah, cool down a bit' period.

As this is *meta* where folks are supposed to come with concerns and complaints, I'd normally undelete the *first* question, but it's speaking to something that happened and was settled a *very* long time ago, focusing the attention of the meta community on the user this person was 'reporting' would be completely unfair. It can be like being an ant under a magnifying glass, which is why we ask folks to hold back *particulars* and contact us directly with them instead.

Comment: Yet another example of why your account creation procedure is so broken.  Dump OpenID, impose a wait so you can slow these clowns down.  Which reminds me, you still haven't addressed [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288274/please-implement-clause-7b-of-the-cc-by-sa-license).

Comment: Hey Hans, how have you been? :P

Comment: Being new to Meta, I have to ask: How is _"contact us directly"_ done ? In my case a gold user marked my question as Duplicate and asks me now explicitly to post the same question again. I posted the problem on Meta, but didn't get any help besides one upvote on Meta. Can anyone from Stackover be contacted to have a look into this ?