# Why should I get downvoted if I don't get editorial control?

Tags: discussion, edits, downvotes

I answered a question a while ago on a Stack Exchange site, maybe *[Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tour)*. Recently it was transferred to Stack Overflow - which has a totally different user base. (I'm not going to link the question or I'll get lots of meta downvotes - which is a problem for another question.)

My answer was edited for the new audience and got many downvotes. The tone of the answer was written for a different audience, and it had a line that was called a trolling answer, that was removed. It probably was, but I felt was a poetic response to a flawed question, and highlighted many problems with the questions. I felt that the answer needed the comment and was lacking the full point without it.

I got the first editor to put my comment back up. And then another editor removed it again, and removed all the comments of me asking to keep the comment there! So I deleted the answer as it was clear I would not be allowed to give my answer. And to top it I got the peer pressure badge! NO, I removed it because I am not allowed to have my answer, not because people don't like it.

Why bother with downvotes if editors have so much power? Anything you don't like just edit it till it's good. Downvotes allow me to help others with a point that maybe most won't understand and can indicate to others by downvoting. But the few can learn from.

I would have answered differently if the question was on the Stack Overflow site, yet the audience of the question was moved behind my back. To answer a question the same for all sites is a bit silly, as technical skills differ across the sites. And my answer is changed in a fundamental way, so I have no control over the answer. So in the end the answer that the user downvotes (or upvotes) is not my answer. So why should I get the downvote? And not for example the editor or whoever moved the question?

Comment: *I would have answered differently if the question was on the stackoverflow site*: so why *hold on to that remark* then? The answer now is on Stack Overflow. You were automatically notified the post was migrated, you had an opportunity to adjust your answer. Editors tried to help you do so. What did you expect to happen instead, that everyone pretends the answer is still on the other site?

Comment: Being able to see deleted posts, I'm interested in seeing the original answer, so I can put this story into context... It really is a shame you don't want to link it.

Comment: @martijn I did not get a notification it was migrated.  Ive no idea what you are referring to. As it is clear from my question I would expect the editorial to take some of the responsibility.  And you say nothing about my main point

Comment: I don't get the "no editor control" complaint.  You have plenty, you can rollback any edits, edit yourself, delete the post.  In 6 to 8 weeks you can hopefully [do this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288274/please-implement-clause-7b-of-the-cc-by-sa-license).  Not everybody likes to have their post edited, the SE sites are just not a happy place for them.

Comment: Deleting the post because editors dont allow expression is what happened.  I edited it, rolled it back, and more edited it. Clearly as you say you dont get the point.  The answer is not mine, but the editors.  So why do I get the downvote.

Comment: @Jon: you have editorial control, you just chose not to use it. That is something different. When a post is migrated to another site you get a notification on the original site. You can always convert the post to Community Wiki if you feel it is no longer your own, or ask to be disassociated from it.

Comment: Not exactly the "editorial control" the OP had in mind though @Martijn...

Comment: Having located the post, I note that your post received several *Low Quality* flags, and the post isn't great with or without the trolling line. Someone removed that one line, you protested, it was rolled back. You are getting the downvotes because it is **your own text**. Nothing was changed by anyone else that caused it to attract more downvotes. I'm not sure why you are going on about having no editorial control here, because your post was intact until a moderator removed the line again in an attempt to address the LQ flags.

Comment: If someone had made the post *worse* by adding other text, or something, you could perhaps have a point, but I fail to see why it is anyone else's fault but your own here.

Comment: The text was removed and I got downvotes after he removed it  What are you talking about.  Whether you like the post or not is irrelevant to my question.   It is much worse without the line.  The fact you disagree is my point which you completely miss.  I am not allowed my answer because you or your like dont like it.  But the downvoters are not downvoting my answer.  Understood if you dont understand personal expression but then maybe this is not a question for you to answer.  Cause you dont get it.  But my answer should be there for those who do.

Comment: So really you're looking for people to just agree with you? Then why post this on Meta in the first place? If you would have posted a different answer  here on SO, edit your answer to reflect that. If it's good after that, you should be just fine. If it's still not ... perhaps deleting it would be the right thing to do?

Comment: Em did you read the question?  I deleted it because I am not allowed to give the answer I want.  The question again is - if the answer that is being voted on is not the users' answer why does the user get the up/down vote.  Agreement is irrelevant.  Again no doubt you down voted the question yet you dont understand it.  If you spend more time reading the question you would not come to the nonsense of So really you're looking for people to just agree with you?  Can someone actually address my question?

Comment: I did not vote on any of your content, so there's that. If you feel like your content is inappropriately edited, roll back. If it keeps being edited, flag for moderator attention. If you no longer want to be associated with the content, ask to be disassociated from it (a right you have as per the license). That's all there is to it.

Comment: Except for the question which you are ignoring.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see what really happened with your contribution, so this is perhaps all going to be a bit more "general case" than would be ideal. If you want a more direct answer to your specific situation, you'll have to point the exact situation out to us. But let's give it a go anyway.

You do have editorial control over your content. If people edit your content to an extent that you feel uncomfortable with, you are free to roll it back. It should still be your content. And that's why votes (up or down) still affect you even when edited by someone else.

If this runs the risk of going into a back and forth, flag your content for moderator attention. Ask them to have a look and perhaps prevent an edit-war. That's part of what they are there for. Whatever you do however, don't edit in meta-commentary regarding the editing of any of your content. (I can't tell if that is part of what you've done, so if not, ignore.)

You are going to have to live with some edits happening. The kind I have made to your question here for example. It's part of our effort to improve content and make it as good as we can.

Now let's assume that the community and even moderators feel the edits are appropriate, but you can't live with the edited content. It happens on rare occasions. What may seem like harmless minor edits to some are a big deal to others.

You at this point have two options, the first of which I would prefer:

1. Have your content disassociated from you. This is a right you have per the license of the content.
2. If your answer has not been accepted, you can delete it.

But for as long as content is on the site under your name, you're going to have to deal with the votes you get.

Comment: Yep, and with the utter lack of specifics provided by  you, that's about the best that any of us can do. Perhaps you were completely mistreated in the handling of your post. Perhaps edits were made that would explain why you are so upset. But we can't tell. So you are going to get a generic "here's how to deal with it" because generally your content shouldn't/won't be edited to where it's unrecognisable as your content. And the votes you get are your votes as a result. If you want more, you're going to have to give us more. Or contact the team/moderators and have them have a look in private.

Comment: Its a general question that needs a general answer.  Not why did it happen to me.  But if I am not allowed to make my own answer than the votes are not on me.  You say it should still be your content.  Maybe that is where I am having the issue.

Comment: That's all based on the assumption that "I have been unfairly treated because my answer was edited to a point where it was no longer my answer and that abomination got voted on". The bottom line is, if that is indeed the case those edits shouldn't have happened. The whole issue of voting is then ultimately secondary. But that's a whole lot of assumptions right there that I can't verify.

Comment: Too ask a different question, if I think my answer has been abominated and you don't - why is your or the entire community together opinion correct against mine?

Comment: That gets to a point that is difficult to convincingly discuss here. Ultimately, the community has over time developed a sense of what is good for the site and what is not. It's why we have a certain scope. It's why we close questions. It's why we delete content. It's why we edit. And to some extent you are going to have to put up with that. And if you can't live with it, perhaps this is not the site for you. But that is very general and may not apply to your situation. So this is by no means a "go away".

Comment: So "It should still be your content" means - any abominations are still your content if the community decides the abomination is good for the site, and thus not an abomination.  I mean that answers all the questions really.  Maybe I am the only one who has a problem with that, based on the feedback.

Comment: @Jon You think it's an abomination that a snarky comment not relevant to the actual answer is removed?  Seriously?