# What is the proper route for a disassociation request?

Tags: support, disassociation

I have [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081797/why-cant-i-use-20-in-a-string) that I asked a couple of years ago, that didn't go down too well (it is too specific and is extremely unlikely to help others, even if the upvotes on the answers say otherwise). I requested deletion via a custom flag a couple of times a year ago, and today (I was reviewing my declined flags):

[image]

Needless to say I didn't read the second flag (*stares at floor in shame*) and my third (from today) got the same treatment. I then [asked in the SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30651586#30651586) what credible reason I can use to have the question deleted; the advice that I was given was that I should **request for it to be disassociated**, not deleted.

I also asked how I file such a request; via a custom flag or via the 'Contact Us' link. I got a mixed response and there doesn't seem to be any clear answer on Meta or Meta.SE.

**To request a question be disassociated from my account, should I custom flag it with the request, or contact the Stack Overflow team directly using the 'Contact Us' link?**

I don't want to waste any more of other people's time than I already have done.

Comment: Being a non-well received question doesn't imply the answers will be downvoted too. E.g. image a badly rant question where the OP "gets owned" in an answer... the question is going to get lots of downvotes but the answer may receive a lot of upvotes by people thanking the author for destroying the OP arguments... and this fact doesn't make neither the question nor the answer good. So: votes > 0 doesn't mean the answer is useful and hence the question is good... it just means some people like it.

Comment: any reason why you rolled back @braiam's edit?  Seems that a more general disassociation tag would be better than a specific one for questions since the process for both question and answer disassociation is exactly the same.

Comment: related: [Please implement clause 7b of the CC-by-SA license](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288345/839601) and [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC:WIKI?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/183280)

Comment: A canned comment with a link to this post was previously popular as a response to self-vandalism. However, the current consensus seems to be that linking to the dissociation policy  in that context is more distracting than helpful. The currently popular canned comment instead notes that vandalism will be rolled back as a matter of policy. It is available e.g. from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372007/should-we-say-vandalizing-to-refer-to-defaced-content

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please refer to the following post on Meta Stack Exchange (not copied here since the content may change):

[How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732)

Make sure you read all of the content so that you understand the process and how it affects you.

Comment: *flags as not an answer* :P

Comment: I cashed in my Exception Rewards Card Points on this one. ;) But in all honesty, this is a sensitive subject that we're having difficulty controlling, and we really want everyone flowing in through a single point.