# Deleting answered question

Tags: bug, vote-to-delete, popup

My first question on SO was not a good one. It attracted four answers, but none actually answered the question (IMHO). Neither the question nor any answer has received a single up-vote in two years.

Today, I decided that it really was not worth saving and tried to delete it. I got this popup:

[image]

Well, that's fine, I understand that, but in this case, I feel the deletion is justified. So I clicked `Delete` and got this one:

[image]

OK, so I have now flagged it for Moderator attention. My question is, why did I get the first popup in the first place?

Having searched here on Meta, I now understand the reasoning for multiple-answers blocking deletion, but then pressing "Delete" on such a question should go straight to the second popup, rather than saying

> "Are you really sure you want to delete it?... Well you can't, so there"

Comment: They want the UX for deleting questions be so bad that you never try that again ... [tag:status-bydesign] ... ;)

Comment: The pop-up is a last chance to redeem your soul. If you click "delete", you permanently make it onto Santa's naughty list. *One does not simply delete a question on Stack Overflow*. Not one with answers, anyway.

Comment: I don't think the mod flag is going to help, but FYI you can contact them to [disassociate the question from your account](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/2333214).

Comment: @TJ. Thanks, but I don't think it warrants action that drastic. If my flag gets declined I'm happy to leave the question there - it's not that embarrassing :)

Comment: If you delete a question on which others have spent time and effort, that question counts as a black mark against your account.  The more time of others you waste, the worse the mark.  The actual algorithm is secret, but this part is known.  Being <2k, you could possibly get autobanned if you do enough of this kind of thing.

Comment: You can also flag and request the question be disassociated from your account.  That allows it to remain but it won't look like you asked it.

Comment: Try editing the question to clarify what you are looking for and why the answers so far don't seem to address that.

Comment: You could down-vote the answers, and I think you could do this with a good conscience, if you think they really are not answering the question. This might get the answerer to delete them. Also, I think if you get them to low enough votes (negative? zero? I have no idea), then you can delete the question even though it has answers. Of course if the answers have a few upvotes, your downvotes won't be enough.

Comment: Have you considered answering it yourself now? You can always add an answer yourself and accept that one, downvoting the other answers if they really don't answer the question. That is, if you know what the answer is by now.