# Introducing the Staging Ground, an attempt at improving the first-time asker experience - What was asking your first question like?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users, user-experience, staging-ground

Stack Exchange sites are some of the best knowledge resources available. The Stack Exchange network is built on the premise that good questions (asked with a good process behind them) can get good answers. However, it can be pretty daunting for newcomers to get that process right, and current new user onboarding is less than ideal for getting them to a place where they can start asking quality questions and knowing how to write them.

I know this from my own experience. I once participated in a coding boot camp. I was taught that Stack Overflow was the best online resource to get help with programming questions. Most of my questions were not answered. Why not? Like many new users, I thought Stack Overflow was where anyone could come and get any question answered. One of those questions had well-intentioned comments such as, “I think if you read the docs all of your questions will be answered.” which was accurate but not the help I was looking for.

### What we are doing about it

We have seen sites like Worldbuilding, Puzzling, and Code Golf have successfully created their own question-asking sandboxes on their meta sites. Recently, we have been actively thinking if we can create a sandbox-like built-in solution that would allow more experienced users to interact with new users in a space away from the active questions on the main site, get some advice and avoid common question closures. The initial research on an approach of this nature has confirmed our belief that this would be a valuable way to approach the problem of new users being able to ask good questions.  We want to ensure that new users ask quality questions when they are introduced to the format of Stack Exchange sites and that they are provided with actionable and concrete guidance in case of an issue.

### What do you think?

This is the first in a series of posts that will be exploring:

1. Some of the issues that exist right now with new user onboarding and introducing the idea of the Staging Ground (this post).
2. [Summaries of the different stages of research that have been conducted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416652/16680213), which led to our proposed test for the Staging Ground.
3. An overview of the workflow of the Staging Ground:

   1. [Question Details & Actions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416851/staging-ground-workflow-question-details-actions)
   2. [Listings, Filters, Quality Control, and Notifications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417271/staging-ground-workflow-listings-filters-quality-control-and-notifications)
   3. [Question Lifecycle Overview](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419746/staging-ground-workflow-question-lifecycle)
   4. Discussion on [Reviewer Motivation, Scaling, and Open Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417932/staging-ground-reviewer-motivation-scaling-and-open-questions)
4. Crowdsourcing for [Canned Comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420897/staging-ground-workflow-canned-comments) and [Revisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421896/staging-ground-workflow-canned-comments-revised)
5. [Beta Test Announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421718/help-needed-a-call-for-volunteer-reviewers-for-the-staging-ground-beta-test)

We will be happy to hear your thoughts and address your questions about the research, and Staging Ground on the future posts dedicated to these topics. We’ll also ask you some specific questions that we’d like to hear from you. The first of these:

**What was your experience like when you asked your first question on Stack Overflow or on the Stack Exchange network?**

Comment: Why is this on Meta.SO instead of Meta.SE, which is more applicable to the broad audience of the whole network?

Comment: This staging ground sounds similar to the experiment a few years ago: [Stack Overflow Mentorship Research Project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project) – was that part of the initial research?

Comment: @Mithical We will be testing exclusively on Stack Overflow to start with. Then depending on how that goes, it will be shared on MSE.

Comment: Even if it's being tested on SO first, if the eventual plan is to go to the entire network, MSE seems more appropriate; especially given that this is an information-gathering post in particular. Cross-posting seems like it would be the most effective way for this to work.

Comment: @Mithical While we hope that Staging Ground will eventually graduate and be made available to all sites on the network, the main use case (and the highest demand for it) will be on Stack Overflow. Thus, our initial series of posts will be on this site. When we are ready to talking about if/how these new tools can help on sites across the network (and what adaptations might be needed there), those discussions will be on MSE.

Comment: I can't remember, but I know it went well enough for me to get an answer quickly, I didn't even get downvotes on the post until 6.5 years later, when I got 3, cause you know... cUrAtOrS eViL.

Comment: "Recently, we have been actively thinking if we can create a sandbox-like built-in solution" - you mean a queue? Because creating a MSO question ain't gonna work, and chat-based mentoring didn't work last time. Starting with SO is arguably an awful decision. it's easy to apply to the rest of the network if it works, but if (when? ref. H&I, review overall, the "mod tools" related to articles, the latter of which is the most applicable example) it's poorly implemented, that's a lose-lose for everyone involved.

Comment: Also, we're already struggling enough with first questions and answers as it is. Could we please get more focus on our already broken tools before piling on with even more tools?

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine First answers is not struggling. And First questions is doing remarkably better than it was a few weeks ago. But beyond that, this is not an attempt to pile on more tools. As will hopefully become clear, we are trying to test out what will be a change to the overall onboarding experience for new users on the site - proactively trying to help with that experience (and quality). Versus review queues which are by definition reactive.

Comment: "You mean a queue" - no, we are not adding a new queue here. Future posts will introduce more about the way that the Staging Ground will work.

Comment: I think any step in the direction of reducing poorly asked questions is a good step. I await to see what this will result in, but I am happy either way to see SE trying to tackle this problem.

Comment: This meta question seems to be mostly about announcing the Staging Ground. Perhaps split it into two when what it *should be* about is actually user experience?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "Perhaps split it into two when what it should be about is actually user experience?" This will be covered in some future posts

Comment: @YaakovEllis I don't understand your reply. This post is already asking about user experience, so I don't see what you mean when you say a *future* post *will* cover this.

Comment: Fair warning, this block of comments is going to jump in topics because writing hard. "no, we are not adding a new queue here" - not necessarily in the old system. Could be a mod flag-style queue, but if you're not adding any type of queue, then you're probably doing mentoring 2.0, and that did not scale the first time around. Either that or you're essentially reimplementing asking, but without asking and without votes, and without closure, but possibly the option to answer either way, and poof, you have an abuse vector with a huge throughput that mods have to manage, assuming we get tools.

Comment: "And First questions is doing remarkably better than it was a few weeks ago." -- for now, yes, and you already know why. If you hadn't worked on it to sort out a flaw, nothing would've changed. My "fear" here  "But beyond that, this is not an attempt to pile on more tools" -- admittedly poorly phrased on my part. Granted, [it could reduce the workload on other queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/347781/6296561), but that assumes it's implemented properly, and preferably while we have the entirety of reviews under control.

Comment: My personal opinion has shifted since that question was asked, largely thanks to [some events from 2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385023/6296561), largely by completing the split between user and curator. I'd also like to point out Mith's answer, which shows a real-world demonstration of the system failing in practice. As a new user, this could potentially help, but what about the other side? Someone has to actually review in the staging area, and guess what? Enter abuse vectors.

Comment: Notably, and the reason I've personally stepped away from the staging concept, is that this is essentially asking a question with extra steps. Someone has to review it prior to it being posted, which makes several assumptions. It assumes the reviewer doesn't just answer the question, eliminating asking and consequently rep gain and loss, altogether. It also assumes the asker follows up on the staging area, but that's a concern regardless of the model, so it's not as significant. You may not call this a queue, but when you have an asker, and someone giving feedback,

Comment: that sounds a suspicious lot like a review to me. Now, since this isn't a queue, that means we, straight off the bat, don't get review bans, unless it's reinvented. This facilitates for the fantastic situation where a reviewer and/or asker intentionally abuses the staging area for something beyond question quality. This does assume there's freeform input involved, which I assume there has to be for this to work. I can't imagine you lot implementing an entire staging area to reduce the pressure on what close votes already do.

Comment: To be fair, there's minimal information on the table, but even then, I fail to see how you're planning to do this without essentially being close votes in several stages, mitigate bad reviewers ("feedbackers"?), while balancing the extremely fine line that is created when you create a privilege to let people give feedback. Incidentally, not privilege locking it also has the same consequences, but with a _lot_ more participants.

Comment: re: "pile on more tools", rephrased more sanely: the point was that instead of addressing existing issues in the major queues, several of which are backlogged, a brand new tool with its own issues gets dropped in as well. This won't help with the severe problems we have elsewhere. Small sites are at a substantial advantage in SE's model. SE's core moderation model, while I'm a fan of it, and while it's relatively efficient with enough people, doesn't scale. The amount of content generators grows exponentially faster than the amount of reviewers, especially as a site goes public.

Comment: This is a known problem, and is one that has been discussed in more depth than anything I can get together in a couple hours. Having too few reviewers and/or curators has been a problem [since at least 2014/2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285438/6296561). This is why smaller sites excel; they have a, percentage-wise, larger amount of curators, compared to the volume of posts. Unfortunately, this means that some sites (including softwarerecs) struggle if they get [even a fraction of SO's traffic](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2809/65219).

Comment: [Here's a FR with similar wording](/q/385509/6296561). This entire thing seems like it's oriented towards askers, and seems like it'll have serious implications for content quality. Moreover, we're either going to have a shortage of serious reviewers and abuse, or different types of feedback that honestly just seems like close votes without the actual downvotes and closure. If downvotes and closure are included, then that's just asking a question in a fancy wrapper that takes away from the other problems, including the ones I've outlined here.

Comment: SO's moderation model relying on systems that don't scale is a _huge_ problem. If we stop doing the fast-paced pipeline reviewing style we currently rely on, the entire system is going to backlog substantially faster. How's that for a first question experience; not even being able to ask because it's in a limbo that is a staging area. Admittedly, there is a chance that we have substantially different definition of staging area, to the point where your vision of it is just a feedback system on public questions beyond what downvotes and closure reasons currently convey.

Comment: Again, I'm making a lot of wild, but semi-educated guesses here. I could be completely off-base on what your actual idea is, but I genuinely fail to see how this can be implemented in a way that doesn't do one of at least: increase review workload, facilitate abuse, vote evasion and dodging Q-bans before they arise, result in a situation where curators don't have as much of an option to take action because of a lack of tools, or users end up with a worse experience because any number of factors result in a huge backlog.

Comment: These aren't far-fetched. Unless it's completely reimagined from the failed mentorship project, and fixes several of the major issues with the current review system, while not impeding curator and moderator ability to take action against problematic users or reviewers, it's going to resemble articles, and it's going to cause problems for a grand total lose-lose situation; new users get stuck in a limbo, and curators and moderators get even more work.

Comment: If (or more likely when) this fails, the actual consequences on the new user UX isn't going to be what you're planning to outline in your research. I have no idea what it is, and I don't really need to. The consequences and real-world artifacts are what you're going to discover with this test, that's once again shifting the limited developer resources away from working with the tools we have, to adding another tool with its quirks and issues on top of our existing problems.

Comment: There is an off chance that this becomes an energy efficient way to reduce CV/other queue workload, but that makes one assumption about the askers; it assumes they actually follow up on the advice, and don't post it anyway. Assuming that's a thing. If it has to be greenlit by reviewers (i.e. a glorified pull request system, of sorts), we suddenly fall back into the system we currently have, but with a lot higher expectations now that the "big bad moderators" are preventing questions from being asked to begin with. The window to make this work is tiny, and the conditions for it aren't met.

Comment: **TL;DR:** I don't see any way this is going to work, unless the existing, huge problems with the moderation systems, that severely drag down efficiency at the scale SO operates on, are worked out first.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: Would you be comfortable converting that block of comments to an answer? While recognize that it started in response to the OP's comments, and doesn't answer the final prompt, I also think it would be easier for the rest of us to follow (and, if appropriate, respond to) if it were structured as a separate post, and especially since the OP will almost certainly have further responses.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine This is a lot of good feedback. Thanks for taking the time to share. I want to acknowledge that some, if not all, have been brought up internally. As I mentioned in the post, we will be doing follow-up posts that share some of our research, design mockups, etc. I think you will find the direction we chose satisfying, if not looking forward to your critique to point out what we may have missed.

Comment: @KevinB While I was not around for that project, I would say that the desire to improve is similar, but the approach is quite a bit different.  Stay tuned for the follow-up posts in the coming weeks, and you will see how.

Comment: The problem: The vast majority of the time people shouldn't be asking a Stack Overflow question. At the core, it will have a trivial answer. If not, it will be a duplicate. A good, original question is so awesomely rare that it just isn't funny. I'm 100% behind making people ask better questions, be it through the server badgering them or education in effective problem solving techniques and debugging, because the end result will be fewer questions asked due to self-service. That said, I love the sandboxing idea, but I join others in not believing that it will scale.

Comment: problem is that the rep < 100 user base is entirely different from the rep > 10k audience. Its almost like we need a noobs.overflow.com. I enjoy helping struggling beginners, but others do not.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine "I don't see any way this is going to work". Thanks for your comments. But we haven't defined anything about how Staging Ground will work thus far, so I think that your determination here is very speculative and a bit premature. We will be devoting other posts to going over how it will work, and those will be the more appropriate places to have this conversation.

Comment: My first question [pissed off Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362140/1324033)

Comment: I'll tell you once I have a question that is not asked already. So far after 11 years... it hasn't happened yet. So I am not too bothered by my own question experience, I am quite happy with the question experiences of other people though :)

Comment: Yeah, great idea. Reminds me a bit of similar initiatives of the community for the last say 8 years that got not much attention so far are were shut down like [StackOverflow Academy](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17088/boundary-between-stack-overflow-academy-and-meta-stack-overflow), so you may be a bit late to the party, but it's definitely the right direction.

Comment: "We want to ensure that new users ask quality questions when they are introduced to the format of Stack Exchange sites" That's the holy grail. I guess everyone wants that. I'm looking forward to the ideas of the company about that. It's clear though that something has to change. The ratio of number of answers to number of questions gets lower and lower every time indicating serious problems with the quality of questions (for many years now).

Comment: @Sayse I really want to go find that post now...

Comment: @user692942 - Luckily its lost in the ether but round 2 is still around - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315007/alternative-to-system-encoding (I don't work there anymore)

Comment: @Sayse uff, that’s some Skeet sass! :D

Comment: @YaakovEllis "Future posts will introduce more about the way that the Staging Ground will work." I guess the fear is that this staging ground will either involve a lot of additional work or may end up deserted and not very useful. I'm curious about it. Are these future posts weeks or rather months approximately away from now?

Comment: Amusingly (well, I think so, anyway). My first question was also [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327775/deleting-answered-question)

Comment: @Trilarion As far as future posts are concerned we have another one that will drop this Thursday, regarding the research. Then the following week much more concrete details on the workflow.

Comment: I don't believe there is a need for any new "tech" to help the new user-experience. Instead, the solution is a human one. Far too often new users are berated and chastised with a flurry of downvotes and no comments about what is wrong with the question. I've always taken the position that people come here for help, and providing a comment with suggestions to correct the question and -- providing a reasonable opportunity to cure the defect is the best approach. No tech involved, the comment suffices, all you have to do is be a helpful human on the other end.

Comment: I've been cagey on wanting to engage on this question [since I don't have confidence that the company listens to feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375489/175248).  What assurances can staff provide that the feedback would be heard and considered, and what is your ultimate goal with this kind of information?  Why do you seek to improve the *asker's* experience on Stack Overflow?

Comment: You're not likely to get a realistic spread of answers here, because you're not asking anything remotely close to a representative sample. The vast majority of people who have asked a first question and had a bad experience won't come back for more. They aren't on stack overflow meta. They won't ever see this post. And they definitely won't answer it.

Comment: Many people on this site are more concerned with grading your question rather than actually answering your question. People here love judging your format, the question itself, the terms you're using, etc. In fact, this comment will probably get downvoted or removed for one reason or another. If you're on this site, you should be here either to help people or to ask a question. Yelling at newcomers over formatting and protocols is not helpful. Just click away if you can't answer the question. There's no need to bully

Comment: @Jacobjanak You can't downvote comments. By the way, if a janitor in your building at work asks you to stop peeing all over the floor, do you also get upset with them?

Comment: @Stuntddude Even the people who frequent SO Meta probably don't remember their first question as they will have been around a long time and if they had a first question it might well have been bad and since been deleted or disassociated. I'm a (relatively) top Meta user and I couldn't tell you what my first question was anymore because I asked for it to be disassociated from my account like 6+ years ago. I know it was bad, though. Like how to select an element in PHP or something embarrassing.

Comment: Something like this is sorely needed.  Most newbie users have a pretty horrible experience on SO at first.  Many are afraid to post here because of the unfriendly reputation SO has for newbies.  I answer a lot of questions on SO, many from newbies.  Questions often start out lacking.  Half of the issue is not understanding how the site works.  Half of the issue is poor communication skills, either because English isn't their primary language or just poor communication skills in general.

Comment: My guess is that this will be a hard problem and it will take significant persistence to get it right and get it to where it really works. Please stay the course and figure it out. As one who has supplied 13,000+ answers on SO and regularly try to help newbies clarify their question in an effort to be helpful rather than just downvote and close, I'm willing to participate in this process if that would be useful. I'm also regularly frustrated as questions get closed right out from under us while we're working on clarifying things and trying to teach the newbie how to fix their question.

Comment: FYI, I tried posting this (now deleted) [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416833/do-we-want-stackoverflow-to-be-hostile-to-new-users) earlier today on meta about hostility to new users and was pretty much told to get lost (via comments, downvotes and close votes).  So, there is plenty of hostility out there (at least in meta) to extending any olive branch to newbie users or helping them interactively "fix" their question.  This will be an uphill climb.  It will be worth it if you figure things out, but the cards are stacked against you at the start.  A mod pointed me here.

Comment: This is a great endeavor, don't let the haters stop you. Too many naysayers around here. The community needs it, whether some recognize that or not.

Comment: @Mithical there is now [a question on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377768/51) that is to serve as a place for asking questions about the Ask Question Wizard and the Staging Ground on the greater Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 86):

I asked my first question in 2014. It was a really basic problem that was more caused by my inexperience with JavaScript than anything else. I got three answers that were all very helpful, explaining my error using the keywords I didn't have the experience to google, and guiding me towards best practices. It was intimidating, but positive.

I think my positive experience was because I had used Stack Overflow a lot before making an account, and absorbed some of the rules just by seeing how others formatted their questions. I wouldn't say it was a *good* question, but it had all of the elements of one: code example, description of the problem, and links to other results I found while searching for an answer. Most people just want to know you tried.

I learned from my early questions that learning the technical terms to describe what you're trying to do in a language is super important. Once you know the keywords to search for, it's almost guaranteed you'll find a solution to your problem. I learned if I can't find a solution to my problem, it's probably because I don't have enough of a basic understanding, so I brush up on my basics and vocabulary.

I've only written five questions in the last 8 years. My last one was in 2019. I still use the site constantly, but I don't work with bleeding edge tech and I've learned to fish, so there's no need to ask anymore.

Comment: This behavior is very recommended! And it can be summarized by two words: _“[lurk moar](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/lurk-moar)”_.

Comment: Similar experience here. I'd been finding answers on SO for years before creating my account last year to ask my first question. A few times I nearly created an account, but whilst creating a minimum reproducible example to back up my question, I worked out the answer myself so didn't need to ask it after all. When I did ask my first question, it got two upvotes within a day or so (possibly from the first questions review queue?). No answer yet, but that's OK. I'd consider my experience to be positive, and I'm fairly sure that's because I'd already been lurking for so long and reading the help

Comment: @sbridewell Very likely from the queue. I never posted a question on Stack Overflow (never felt the need to), but when I posted my first answer — it was a mediocre code-only answer to a question that should’ve probably been closed as a dupe — I still received four upvoted very quickly.

Comment: "I think my positive experience was because I had used Stack Overflow a lot before making an account" - indeed, you set yourself up for success that way. First you learn, then you participate. Alas many people come to the site with a mission: they need someone else to make their error go away, FAST.

Comment: This was my experience as well. I browsed SO for about a year, and then joined. Even in the two months I've been here, I haven't asked a question. I think most of the questions people ask are easily solvable by googling, but they don't do it. We should encourage people to do research.

Answer (score 79):

Before answering the question, let me say I'm expecting this project to fail horribly. This is iteration #9001 of "let's help new askers" and it doesn't seem to be any more focused on *reducing the amount of questions asked* on this site. IMO the majority of new questions in my main tags (python, java) should simply not be posted in the first place, and the offending users should not be asking SO but read tutorials or docs, or experiment in a shell. That might not be "welcoming" but the current interpretation of "welcoming" resulted in a situation where literally the only thing I do on SO is downvoting, closevoting, and writing the occasional meta comment or post.

---

Re the topic - I asked my first question almost a decade ago, while I was still a student, in a language I'm not terribly familiar with (C/C++). It went well because **I researched before asking the question and prepared relevant code snippets**. There was minor debate about the tags I chose (I used both C and C++ as it was an interop problem between a C lib and a C++ codebase), and that was it. I got good, useful answers, no closevotes, and the question has a score of +7/-1 (the DV might even have been a random "revenge" vote at a later time, I don't remember).

In summary, I didn't even think of asking SO before doing some research and experimentation, and knew what was expected of me, both of which sadly isn't the case for most questions asked nowadays.

Comment: I agree, and I suspect there might be some generation clash here. I started learning programming in the 1990s and the Internet barely existed. You _had_ to use conventional methods of learning: reading books and taking classes, a very well-tried and refined method of learning that existed for several thousand years before the Internet. Now there's the Youtube generation who somehow think that they are the chosen ones, who suddenly don't need to use these conventional means of study unlike some hundreds of generations before them.

Comment: @Lundin not sure if it's a generational thing. IMO it's not so much books/classes vs the internet, but the willingness to experiment and learn by yourself. I learned Delphi in highschool in 2003-5 (at a very basic level), and while I already spent a lot of time online I didn't use it much for coding related things. I wrote bad breakout clones and other small games for fun but didn't learn much. Only got serious about programming a few years later when changing masters to CS, and picked up most of my CS knowledge from the net, not books/courses (only coding book I read was SICP for the memes).

Comment: It completely blows my mind that people on a Q&A site believe that the best way to fix the problem of "bad questions" is to keep telling people to stop asking questions. Sure, we need people to stop asking questions that have been repeatedly asked to death, but even duplicate questions have value when they point to related questions with good answers. And really, the only way people get better at things, like asking questions, is to do more of it, not less. "Practice makes perfect" not "shut up and do it perfectly correct the first time".

Comment: @computercarguy are you going curate all that? Oh, no your not…didn’t think so.

Comment: @Lundin I almost never believe generational temperament differences unless proven without reasonable doubt. Another hypothesis might be that there was a strong selection bias towards people who will learn by themselves back in the day because programming was, comparably, quite inaccessible.

Comment: @computercarguy Practice, yes. Practice anywhere at anyone's expense, no.

Comment: @computercarguy "we need people to stop asking questions that have been asked to death" - from my perspective that includes the endless questions from users who don't even know the basics of programming (basic syntax, concepts like variables/methods). The overwhelming majority of those Qs are very localized and thus not useful to anyone else, and would also require the answerers to teach a lot of simple concepts to the OPs. When I signed up SO was about building a high quality content repo for professionals in Q/A format, not about mentoring people who fail at coding hello world in python.

Comment: @user692942, I'm of the camp that thinks SO/SE should be curating their own content, not require the free work of volunteers to keep the business running. If you have a problem with there already being too much work to curate as a volunteer, you should take that up with the website owners, not the people using the website.

Comment: @PasserBy, so where do you suggest people practice asking questions that are as tightly restricted as SO/SE and follow the exact same rules? You won't get that at Reddit, which many people get pushed to when they don't immediately know 100% of the rules on the first try.

Comment: @l4mpi, this is why having a more formal intro to SO/SE is so important, so we can tell beginners to get more help offsite before they ask super basic questions. Right now, we basically yell at them to RTFM and close or delete the question before they have a chance to see any kind of response. And yes, I've seen questions closed in under 6 minutes and taking +3 days to get reopened after it was edited, as well as comments that specifically said "RTFM" and nothing else, not even a suggestion as to what manual they should be reading instead of the one they likely are reading.

Comment: @computercarguy You won't get the exact same thing. But you don't need to. The huge majority of closed questions are due to missing skills that aren't exclusive to SO, such as how to read the rules and how to be nice humans.

Comment: @computercarguy Good luck creating a meaningful "formal intro" that reaches people who fail to search for their problems, fail to read the docs or a tutorial, fail to read SO guidelines, and even fail to ckeck the question preview before asking trivial stuff with broken formatting and missing content. You would probably have to strap them to a chair and force them to watch a video, clockwork orange style. And I don't see a problem with there being more friction for reopening initially-bad questions than to get them closed (although IME garbage is often answered badly before it can be closed).

Comment: @PasserBy, I've seen plenty of questions that were closed by people who could use those same "be nice humans" and "read the rules" skills. Of the few questions I've asked, I've had plenty of "feedback" by those types who have far more rep than me. Also, many of the rules aren't in a easily accessible centralized area. They may "all" be on Meta, but even as long as I've been on this network, I'd never seen many of the rules posted that got my questions closed or at least CVed. We need to do better than that as a community.

Comment: @l4mpi, I'm not saying it'll fix 100% of problems, but it will fix the problem of people earnestly wanting to use this network, yet not having even 25% of the necessary information available to them to ask an appropriate question. As I just mentioned to PasserBy, I've had rules commented to me about my own questions that I've never seen, even as long as I've been a member. And many high rep members seem to pick and choose which rules to enforce and when to enforce them either randomly or on because they don't know them all, either. (cont)

Comment: The rules around here are extremely subjective and therefore not very friendly to newcomers.

Comment: @computercarguy people who "earnestly" want to use SO already have a ton of resources and ways to wrap their head around this site (the help center, the sidebar on the "ask" page, meta, lurking on main, etc), so "not having even 25% of the necessary information available to them" is IMO simply incorrect. And again, the main issue is not askers who don't understand all of SO's rules, it's askers who don't know programming basics and fail to do their own research and experimentation, leading to useless localized questions. You can't fix that by throwing more info about SO in their faces.

Comment: @l4mpi, really? Is that why every question that I've asked (other than on Meta) has gotten massive pushback about dozens of different rules and regs, even though I've been "lurking" on and reading about rules on this site for nearly a decade? I've answered over 100 questions, so you'd think that I'd have learned all the rules there are, yet I have DVs on 2 out of the 3 questions I've asked. And I'm pretty sure I've had at least 2 questions deleted in the past 2 years, so your assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: Throwing info in people faces is exactly what we do in comments, and what we shouldn't do in trying to train people to use the site.

Comment: @computercarguy no offense, but that's _your_ experience. As described in my and other answers, other people have had significantly different experiences. Have you considered it might be a problem with _you_ instead of the site?  But anyways, I don't think it's fruitful to continue this conversation, as our viewpoints on the purpose of the site don't seem to be compatible.

Comment: @l4mpi, here's an example of what I'm talking about: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/23323/stepper-motor-connector-identification/23329#comment37853_23323. The comment makes a judgmental comment about my question when they could have just asked for more clarification. This is very mild compared to some of the comments I've seen around, and not just pointed at me. And your comment about it being with the way I use the site, instead of the site in general is also judgmental. If this is supposed to be a professional Q&A site, we should leave off those judgmental comments.

Answer (score 64):

I asked my first question in January 2012. It wasn't good. I got four downvotes (+0/-4), and it was rapidly closed because I did not "demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem" (not inaccurate). One user was so incensed by my question, and my question alone, that they proceeded to serially downvote me, which I flagged, but the votes were never to my memory reverted. I got one answer. The answerer, to credit, did help me understand where the error in my thought process was.

On my third attempt at asking a question, I finally received my first upvote. After that, I dedicated most of my time to answering questions, and sitting around Meta Stack Overflow. I amassed a fair bit of reputation that way, but it was slow work.

It's a miracle I'm still here. That account no longer exists. If I were anyone but me, with my weird fascination with people and systems, I'd be long gone. But I stuck around because I *didn't* understand. I kept trying because I don't mind looking like a fool in public - never really have. To me, embarrassment and shame are temporary. The lessons they teach are imperative. Who will remember some learner stumbling in public over reading data from DirectX?

Important context: I was also very, very young.

---

Three things characterized my experience starting out on Stack Overflow in 2012.

1. **I felt exposed - and not in a good way.** This isn't necessarily something Stack Overflow can control, but I (and I think a lot of people now) believed that asking for help is a sign of vulnerability. What to me was an expression of vulnerability was met with some fairly harsh reaction.
2. **I got my answer ("you don't know what you're doing"), but the way it was communicated was frustrating.** Analogous to #1, the way people and systems communicated this message to me was mysterious. The way it was presented (here is the list of people who think you don't get it) was certainly a hit to my ego.
3. **It took a *long* time to reach the point where I could contribute productively, consistently.** And the only way I got there was by participating actively on MSO for an extended period of time.

'course, things aren't done the same way around here, anymore. 2012 was a long time ago.  This experience needs to be read in a historical light. Certainly some of this still happens today - I am sure the timbre of this is familiar to many here. Even though it'd be hard for me to say I'd have an analogous experience today, I hope a bit of history proves useful.

Comment: (Also, for clarification: Not currently involved with this project. Just saw the question pop up on an internal channel.)

Comment: It might be good to think about what would have been helpful to avoid the negative experiences. Like being exposed: not showing the name of the question creator if not wanted (only in the edit history maybe), ..

Comment: Notably, taking hits to ones ego is not necessarily a bad thing, particularly not when one is young and dumb. I started programming as a hobbyist and thought I was pretty good, then I took some actual classes in school and realized that I didn't have a clue. Then after those classes, I thought I knew everything... then I went to university and realized that I still didn't have a clue. Then after an engineering degree, I thought I was awesome at programming, then got my first job and realized that I still didn't have a clue.

Comment: This from someone making an actual effort to learn. We have extreme amounts of new users who think they have made an effort at learning after watching a 5 minute long youtube video by some quack, then post their first question here. It might be very healthy for these kind of people, often of the young & dumb variety like in my example above, to get brought down back to earth. Will it be a positive new user experience? No, it will be the opposite but that's because of the inflated ego they are bringing with them, not because of the site.

Comment: @Lundin You make some good points, but I like that Slate highlights that *the way it was communicated was frustrating*. Whether at SO or at work, it's good to have your ego deflated a bit, but especially when it is done kindly. I love that the top item in SE's "Expected Behaviour" is *[be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)*. The other side of the coin is that we can't jump in assuming that *every* new user has an inflated ego. Some will be suffering from years of mental health challenges, and not in a good place to 'take it on the chin'. Being kind/nice is the best place to start

Comment: @SteveTaylor On the other hand, SO is quite polite and civil compared to the average social media out there. Chances are that if you don't have thick enough skin to use SO, you might not have thick enough skin to use the rest of the Internet either.

Comment: @Lundin - it's also quite polite and civil compared to schools or prison, but none of these has really got anything to do with the culture we're building together on SE. Our shared vision of 'expected behaviour' is the bar to measure it all by, so let's not lower it unless we really want to. If somebody isn't emotionally or mentally ready for other Internet sites but can feel safe on SE, that's a win in my book.

Answer (score 28):

I got question-banned. Then I learned. Asking on Stack Overflow is a privilege, not a right. That sentence isn't emphasised as much as it should be. NOTE: It wasnt just a single question, I asked several all very poorly written which resulted in the automatic question ban.

Comment: You were *suspended* for asking a question? Was it against the ToS/CoC then, or do you refer to the automatic question ban?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine No idea, Question was poorly formatted as well as possible a duplicate, and there were prob like 3 such question of mine. So the suspension was valid. It was a while ago so I dont remember all the details, but I was in the wrong ofc

Comment: Ah, the automatic question ban then - the term suspension is commonly understood to refer to what you manually get when mods determine that you violated the rules (there are also review suspensions, but that's its own can of worms) of the network in some way, so I wanted to clarify.

Comment: *"Asking on Stack Overflow is a privilege, not a right"* - quoted for truth. The first question experience is often dictated by your knowledge and understanding of how asking a question is a last resort, it is not the primary function of the site.

Comment: Not to denigrate your experience, but this is factually incorrect: no user is ever question-banned for a *single* question, so this cannot accurately represent your experience asking your *first question* here.

Comment: @CodyGray It is factual that you didnt read everything. I stated in the comments that there were several poor question. Not just one.

Comment: I see. I confess that I didn't read all of the comments, I only read the answer. The way the answer is worded, it implies that your experience asking your first question was that you "got question-banned".

Answer (score 26):

I'll chime in because I think my first question experience was probably very different than others.

I had already used Stack Overflow to find answers before, but during an internship I ran into a problem neither I nor my mentor could solve. My mentor was well versed with Stack Overflow and helped me polish my question until it fit all of the guidelines *before* I posted.

The question was well received and I got my answer.

He explained the rules to me and encouraged me to participate in the community. I've been lurking on meta ever since.

It is not easily implemented, but I think if everyone had the privilege of an in-person SO guide, the onboarding process would be much easier!

Comment: See also [this suggestion for an opt-in mentorship program](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254205/248627)

Comment: Yeah, if only the site didn't have millions of active users. Think of what could be possible if the site was really small scale, the size of say... a classroom. But it isn't possible, we have to deal with this monstrosity instead.

Comment: I would put emphasis on **in-person**. Talking to (possibly anonymous/pseudonymous) strangers while being anonymous/pseudonymous themselves is a vastly different experience.. imo.

Comment: The only comparable thing I could see at scale is if SO hosted "community outreach representatives" to give an introduction to best practices, in either college or at companies. The representatives would just be volunteers with a proven track record on SO, hopefully people at those organizations themselves.

Comment: But honestly, SO should just do a better job of explaining its rules :) They have control of the whole process from account creation to post writing. There is no excuse.

Answer (score 21):

I asked my first question ~12 years ago.  If I recall correctly, the guidance at that time on how best to ask a question on SO was:

> "Try not ask a question here."

Followed by a list of steps to try first:

- Paste the error into a search engine
- Explain it to a [duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)
- Write a simpler example of the problem

Then, if I had done all those things, and still hadn't make progress, then it was time to ask a question, and I'd have all this good material to use in the question.  So many questions that I almost asked, got answered by either the search engine or the duck!

When I finally had a question to ask that blew past those 3 first steps, I got an answer within minutes.

Comment: Honestly, even as a relatively new user who complains about downvotes and unfriendly culture, I would prefer if all the new onboarding stuff was replaced with just this message in big bold text. It sets expectations in an honest way that feels like it would be much more effective.

Comment: Seriously, this is the best.  I think some of the answers to SO's current problems lie in SO's past.

Answer (score 20):

I've been a member for only 6 months, so my user experience is quite recent. I started out by answering other questions, before I asked my own. I asked my first question in August 2021. And the response was; well, impersonal. For two days, it sat; no votes, no comments, only a few views. Then, I got a comment from the [Community `Bot`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) saying that my question wasn't clear enough. To this day, the question has no votes, no more comments, only a few views<sup>1</sup>.

I do admit, looking back on it now that I've learned more, the question *is* quite broad. If I saw someone else post that question now, I'd probably downvote it, thinking that it's not a great question, and is too broad to answer.

And yes, I was quite nervous about asking my first question. The tags I frequent ([python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter)) have a *lot* of new users asking poor-quality/duplicate questions, so I'd seen a good deal of questions that had a negative net score, and many that were closed. I was fearing the worst; but while that didn't happen, the best didn't happen either.

Which brings me to another point: my user experience was better than some for a couple reasons.

1. I'd already used Stack Overflow to solve coding problems, so I had an idea of what it was like.
2. I'm (I admit it) a bit of a sucker for rules, so reading the tour and the Help Center, and following the regulations, came quite naturally to me.

So, all in all, my experience has been rather neutral. But it's always good to bear in mind: many (not necessarily all) new users look up to you genius high-rep users, and there are few things more crushing than being looked down on by someone you look up to. I'll try to keep that in mind when commenting on low-quality posts, and I think y'all should too.

---

<sub>1. The question is now deleted, with one downvote, due attention drawn to it by this answer.</sub>

Comment: "doesn't quite deserve a downvote, and is too broad to answer" That is a contradiction.

Comment: @philipxy Correct. Updated my answer :-). I also deleted the question, since, now that it's being talked about on Meta, it's receiving more attention (which brought it to _my_ attention). I really should have deleted it long ago, but it wasn't foremost in my mind until I saw this Meta question.

Comment: "...the question has no votes, no more comments, only a few views..." There are really a lot of these questions. If they do not get immediate attention after creation and do not generate a lot of traffic, they might be sleeping for a long time. There is an automatic cleanup for downvoted questions (roomba) but un-voted, un-commented questions are basically unknown unknowns. If people have time they should dedicate themselves to these questions and try to at least vote or comment once on them. That would probably be very useful.

Comment: @Trilarion Agreed. However, that way is probably less attractive for some users, because there's less of a guaranteed return (in the form of reputation). Also, depending of course on the age of the questions you look at, some may not be relevant any more. I do enjoy occasionally going through and looking at old [tag:gtk] questions, and I have answered a few; maybe I should do that more often, and with more tags. I complain about low-quality posts on SO, but the search bar _does_ give me the ability to ignore those low-quality posts if I want to.

Comment: Sidenote: prefer to improve a question to deleting it because deleted questions are the invisible part of the iceberg that sunk many a question-asker to the bottom of the Question Ban Sea. Some questions cant be improved, but when possible, improve.

Comment: @user4581301 Sound advice. I do prefer to improve the question when possible, but that particular question is not improvable given its coding circumstances. You can [view it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68975134/16775594) if you like (since you have >10k rep), so you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 19):

I'm still fairly new to Stack Overflow. In fact, I asked my first question less than three weeks ago. I found it easy to initiate the question-asking process, although wording my question in an acceptable way (i.e., such that it would post) was a bit tricky. I received a helpful answer from user @rdelrossi rather quickly. Great first experience!

Answer (score 19):

My initial experience was great, due to several factors.

I started by answering, not asking, in areas where I was experienced developer, and  accumulated some initial reputation rather quickly.

Looking back, there is definitely one thing that I was completely unaware until much later, even long after I have unlocked close vote privilege. And that was a post ban. I knew there were some rules about which questions can be asked, and I knew that answer section is not for comments, and that you get downvoted for poor or off-topic posts, but I never knew that doing so may prevent you from posting again.

This is critical information that is not presented to new users. I have read the tour and I have read the help section. Only when I started to participate in [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) and on SO Meta I realized the full implications of posting unsuitable content (that is not spam).

Additionally, the fact that there are some rules for asking questions I knew more by luck and because I was visiting SO for years before I joined, and not because the site did excellent job in presenting those rules when I finally joined and started posting.

I would definitely have paid more attention to what I was posting if I had known more about the strictness of the rules. Not because I would be especially afraid to participate nor would that stop me from participating, but because some of my initial posts could have been better or shouldn't have been posted at all - for instance answering poor or off-topic questions.

Answer (score 17):

My first question is probably a massive outlier.

I joined Stack Overflow in 2012, in my final year of university having spent the last ~9 years on the internet making a fool of myself and learning how to conduct myself the hard-way.

People can't wait ~9 years to learn how Stack Exchange works though.

---

My first few questions that I asked were in [fortran-90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran-90). My guess is that tag has a different user base, that rarely got questions, so I was welcomed differently. No body had asked what was a very simple question, so it got one slightly snarky comment (probably deserved) and a good clear answer.

I'm extra cautious when asking in JavaScript these days, even with all my experience; I know what to expect.

But if I had joined SO at the same age I'd joined the internet I'd have had a much much worse time. There's no proving ground, or casual forum environment to cut your teeth on where the stakes or investment is lower (the three main places I browsed early on were all traditional non-Q&A forums).

Comment: I had a similar path but my first introduction into the site was not to ask questions, I wanted to answer them because I came from the casual forum environment - and started to treat SO in exactly the same way. Your background does not really help to prevent misuse of the site, but it does help when you have learned the discipline to assume you may be mistaken when things don't go your way. That is what I miss in a lot of newcomers, they come to the site expecting the site to bend to their will. And then get upset when it doesn't and they have to learn a big pile of rules.

Comment: Well, SO *does* have casual and low-stakes environments, like chat and some parts of Meta...but they're all walled off behind Rep requirements that deliberately exclude new users.

Comment: @samuei yeah that's an issue right?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Definitely

Comment: No it isn't, you need only very little reputation to open them up globally. They are walled off with a purpose, the same purpose of why the site has a tiered system for opening up site features to you. And the simplest explanation really is that people need to be triggered to ask "why?" - and seek out the answer.

Comment: @Gimby in my experience either the wall is too low (a user who isn't prepared on how to ask and/or answer gets through 'early') or it's too high (first-time user who *is* prepared has to answer as a comment or make nugatory edits to get around this wall). Rep is a bad indicator for experience with anything but this website's nuances

Comment: @AncientSwordRage: "nugatory" – [Thanks for teaching me a new word!](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nugatory) :)

Answer (score 15):

I asked my first question in October 2018. It went fine. I quickly received a helpful answer. And, the same was true for my next 6 or 7 questions. That said, SO isn't my first rodeo. I've participated on numerous technical forums over 2 decades (both asking and answering complicated questions). So, I know how to research problems, and how to ask a good question.

It wasn't until question #8 (or so) that I encountered that "Stack Overflow attitude" I've read about. :-) I was trying to figure out the steps to decode a bitmask with bitwise operations. However I didn't know what a bitmask was, so I used poor wording to ask my question. (When you don't know the jargon, it's hard to ask a good question.) The question was closed as a duplicate, so I can't reference it.

Here is my complaint: the referenced "duplicates" didn't answer my question. In fact, they had nothing to do with my question. I even commented that they weren't helpful. User comments weren't helpful either. Eventually there were enough votes to close and it was gone. As a result, I didn't learn anything to improve my question and gave up.  :-(

When the need returned, I did more googling and eventually learned enough to ask a decent question (including 'bitmask" and 'bitwise operations' were the magic bullets). I got 5 helpful answers. :-) (Who says there's 1 obvious way to do something in Python?!?)

Based on this, a process to improve questions should provide guidance to:

1. Improve the questions, and
2. Improve the feedback intended to improve the question.

Comment: It seems the referenced duplicates encouraged you to do the research necessary to ask a useful question, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ it's very difficult to have a conversation when there's a language/terminology barrier involved.

Comment: Scratching my head here a little - if it was only closed, why would you not be able to reference it - I assume it was deleted afterwards? If so, was it you deleting it, the cleanup script, or the community at large?

Comment: @Oleg Valter is with Ukraine that question doesn't appear when I view "All Questions" from my SO profile. I _assume_ it was deleted because the cleanup script deletes questions "Closed as duplicates". But, I really don't know.

Comment: Since recently, you can view all your deleted posts in the activity tab in the respective sections - the link is at the bottom (an intentional choice by SE), btw

Comment: "When you don't know the jargon, it's hard to ask a good question." Only in the sense that people are not used to writing clearly & *that's* hard. Instead of actually clearly saying what they mean, talking about the parts of the things that they are working with & trying to accomplish, they use fuzzy abstract words & too few words, so that they do not communicate well. Jargon is not necessary. (You could remove all the bitmasky terms from your current non-deleted non-editied bitmask question & they wouldn't be missed; you aren't using them in an essential way & you are communicating.)

Comment: PS It would be interesting to see your original post. (And I see that while I was composing these comments accessing it has come up.) (However in the visible post just giving suggested-duplicate links & saying "but don't answer my question" is not helpful & not communicating.) (Of course, SO Inc does not manage to communicate to users what they need to know to have a good experience.)

Comment: @philipxy Sometimes it's mandatory to know [the jargon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405828/should-the-help-centre-link-to-specific-meta-questions-that-provide-additional-c#comment830385_405828) ; ).

Comment: @Teemu OMG I just realized I missed  "Metanical Turk(ey)". PS Your "mandatory to know" is about reading, mine is about writing. *Given* jargon one can research. (Indeed, only given clear writing one can reasonably (re)search for jargon.) (Yes I knew that only those smelling "antidisestablishmentarianism" would get the pun "antidocumentationarianistic". Nevertheless if the pun is lost the latter still makes (some) (joking) (hyper-affixilated) sense.)

Comment: I understand that people ask for some effort before posting on here, as it is obvious that nowadays you can find a lot on the internet, but I am not so sure I agree on this site using the rest of the internet as a garbage bin like "look around in those other places before even thinking in coming here". Like, if every place on the internet was like that, then how would you learn? Why does StackOverFlow have the exclusive *right* of being the last-resort place (so it has the best researched questions)? And what is the amount of effort required? What if someone is in a hurry?

Answer (score 15):

My first question was back in 2011. I worked out a solution I wanted to share with the world, so I posted a question that had my solution within the question itself and the title had a suffix of "Solved".

I still recall the sting of being flamed for poor formatting and answering within the question itself - not realising that one could post and answer to one's own question.

But I was thick skinned enough push through onslaught and I started contributing, a lot, and never looked back.

Had I been less thick skinned, I might have run away and been put off for life.

Comment: Yes, I can relate to that. People that take negative feedback mainly as a chance to improve but are otherwise convinced of their own value have definitely an easier experience here than otherwise. What's needed is some kind of: "I will listen to your feedback, but I will always reserve my right to disagree with it." attitude.

Comment: "Had I been less thick skinned, I might have run away and been put off for life" people nowadays(including myself) should learn from this.

Answer (score 13):

First off, I'd like to address

> We have seen sites like Worldbuilding, Puzzling, and Code Golf have successfully created their own question-asking sandboxes on their meta sites.

Having been active on Puzzling when the Riddle Sandbox was implemented, it was, to begin with, [an unmitigated disaster](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5358/25966); it caused more problems than it solved. It made the whole process of asking a riddle more frustrating, opaque, and not communicated well.

After it was no longer *mandatory* to use the Riddle Sandbox, it became a more useful resource where users could give feedback on questions before they were posted, identifying possible improvements or flaws in the way the riddle was posed.

---

As for the first question I ever posted on SE, it was [closed as a duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73247/why-cant-harry-see-the-thestrals-before-seeing-cedric-die?noredirect=1). It was a frustrating experience, because the question it was closed as was not the same question that I asked. It was closed because an answer on the proposed duplicate question answered the question that I had asked. It's an annoying policy that wasn't communicated clearly at the time, and one I've been fighting for the past seven and a half years, with little success. (To clarify: In this particular instance the closure was justified. There are other cases on SFF where "it's answered in this other question" is used as rationale for duplicate closure where the questions have nothing to do with each other but the answer happens to be the same. That's where my issue lies, aside from the poor UX around dupe closure in '14.)

Comment: In regards to your duplicate, having the same answer in multiple places is a never helpful. If the same answer answers (slightly) different questions, then closing as a dupe and having the (hopefully) well asked duplicate act as a sign post is a much better UX.

Comment: It was *mandatory*? Ouch!

Comment: @Larnu Perhaps you were using hyperbole in your "never", but I can certainly think of situations where this isn't true.  For instance, I've seen situations where the existing answer is one good solution to the second question, but it's not the only (or necessarily best) one.  And the other solutions are completely inapplicable to the first.

Comment: I really don't get the second part of your answer. You're complaining about the fact that your question got closed as a dupe of a slightly different question where the accepted answer _perfectly answers your question_? You got a great answer but got frustrated - why, because it wasn't under "your" question?

Comment: @l4mpi - No; once I found the answer it was fine. It was frustrating because what a duplicate was, or why I was being told that "this has been answered at <question title that wasn't specifically what I was asking about>", wasn't being clearly communicated. The UX around that has changed pretty significantly since 2014, though.

Comment: @Mithical ah, that makes more sense. I don't remember the old UI but I don't remember it being significantly worse. But well, once you understand what a dupe is everything but the link to the duplicate becomes fluff, so maybe my brain just filtered the bad UI parts out.

Comment: @Mithical this is a good point because a lot of people don't read the duplicate they just see the title in the comment and start complaining "it's not a duplicate of that!". When raising a duplicate flag I tend to try and edit the comment before the 5-minute edit window is up to add some context to why I'm flagging it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Larnu, sorry I can't agree with you. If I'm googling to find solutions to my problem, the fact that there is a solution in an answer to an otherwise unrelated question will not help me-- I won't find the answer unless I'm already including terms from that (for me still unknown) solution in my search.

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins no, you find the sign post from your search, which takes you to the dupe, and would mean the system is working... *Good* duplicate questions aren't deleted, they can, in fact, even continue to attract upvotes because they are good and then the (duplicate) questions they lead to and their answers also then get upvotes.

Comment: This problem wouldn't be a problem if the closure message specified the answer that is relevant, rather than the question that isn't. While this is can be handled with a comment specifying the answer to look at, it frequently isn't, which makes the closure seem unfair to the user and increases SO's reputation out in the world of closing everything as a duplicate of a completely unrelated question.

Answer (score 11):

My first question was bad, because I didn't read something. And, especially when reviewing, I'm seeing a lot of people without any badge, which means a lot of people that have their post in the review queue didn't take the tour. And I think that, without the [new question creation workflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416322/10952503), it can be an important issue.

People, such as me at the beginning, make basic mistakes explained in other posts here, such as don't show what they tried, don't show the actual working code or not enough explaining the issue.

The experience can only be better by taking the time to read resources **or** help people to do as the resource said, but without reading them.

Also, the "duplicate" field always proposes low upvoted posts instead of very upvoted ones and don't show very relevant ones. Which also makes new askers think that they can help the site, such as they are coming with a new question (which is—in lot of cases—wrong).

Answer (score 11):

I asked my first question in 2012 after I had come to Stack Overflow for many times as a visitor. My first question got a downvote right after, but later also got upvotes. I continued asking and starting answering and also flagging and reviewing. After a couple of attempts I got the hang of it and it all made sense. I have learned how to ask and answer good questions here.

Issues I remember:

- I was totally surprised at the speed of the feedback. First downvote within a minute, comments within 5-10 minutes. I still tried to figure out how to answer the first comment, when I already got the second one and an answer. Maybe slowing down things a bit, would have helped there. The parallelism of feedback overwhelmed me. Later I learned to stay online and reactive right after any contribution.
- The formatting of my first contributions was not optimal. I used "P.S." to add information to questions. I should have just inserted additional information in the question.
- Searching for existing information was always a major part of the effort, even more so than just presenting the question. I would basically first search for the issue, then write up the question, then search again and maybe find an answer and cancel the question asking process.

What could have helped me:

- Optimally timed feedback
- Clear feedback on optimal layout
- Strong advice emphasizing the importance of research (should now be even more important than then)

Comment: "slower feedback"? How would that be achievable without rate limiting interactions of other users with the question? It would not make sense for DVs/CVs, which are a form of feedback. Wouldn't work for comments either, because SO would need to automatically decide which comments are useful (e.g. trivial version- and data-ambiguous python questions with incomplete code regularily get comments asking about the version or input data before someone mentions the missing code parts, if you rate limit this it might effectively just block the few useful comments).

Comment: @l4mpi "How would that be achievable without rate limiting" Do view selection instead. Do not show all new questions to all users but only a random subset to everyone. Show preferably uncommented, unvoted questions. Anyway, I just wrote what I experienced and what might have helped me there, because I was simply too slow for the speed of SO and if I would have had more time, maybe some other feedback would not have been needed. Not sure if this is still the same nowadays. Others, especially younger ones here seem to have experienced rather silence and would be happy to get a comment or vote.

Comment: I can second that (even now) the rate of feedback can be too much. People end up tripping over themselves to comment or completely ignoring the question at times

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Problem might be that we immediately bump a question upon activity. That might be wrong. Maybe we should bump it only after some time.

Comment: I think slower feedback is a misnomer, it is a means to an end. The end is to have _clearer_ feedback.

Comment: @PasserBy Just tried to describe a problem I faced and a possible solution. Instead of slow one could maybe settle on optimal. I want to make the point that timing of feedback can be an issue and that there might be an optimal timing.

Answer (score 11):

I don't post on Stack Overflow often -- sometimes there's more than a year between two of my questions -- so I feel like I'm a first time poster almost every time. And the experience is the same to me most of the time.

When I post here, it's usually because I'm stuck with something, I've spent hours reading through documentation and trying various solutions, but to no avail.

As a last resort, I reach out to the online forum which is known for being helpful. However, the experience is quite ironic. In order to have my question considered good enough, I have to read through Stack Overflow's codes of conducts and user guides. And even after doing so, the act of posting a question and getting a constructive answer will still take quite some trial and error from my side.

In other words: finding help is sometimes a tedious process, which I am not prepared for at a moment where the tedium of the problem has made me all but give up.

It's of course important for a website like Stack Overflow to maintain a certain standard of high-quality questions. My personal feeling is that this is something that needs to be weighed against the need to make a friendly and approachable impression towards new users, and this balance has always felt off during the 10+ years that I have been using this site.

Once you're an established user who has a good grasp on how the website works, this place is fantastic. But you're a new user, already demotivated by the problem you're facing, the experience does leave some things to be desired.

Comment: _"However, the experience is quite ironic. In order to have my question considered good enough, I have to read through Stackoverflow's codes of conducts and user guides."_ I fail to see the irony in that? Isn't that how _all_ websites work?

Comment: @Cerberus If you're someone who simply treats people with respect and who refrains from controversial behavior, you can use any online forum without ever needing to read the rules in detail. This is in part because users know that every online forum largely uses the same set of rules.
You can blame the user for taking an assumption on that, of course. What I am pointing out is that Stackoverflow is an exception to this. Instead of entering a constructive discussion with the user, we tell them to read documentation or tag their question as problematic, and that's it.

Comment: Well, yes, but that's because of the sheer quantity of questions SO gets. The users that answer here, all volunteers, don't have time to enter a constructive discussion with each and every author of a lacking question.

Comment: @Cerbrus I have addressed this point in the second-to-last paragraph of my original answer. I am not here to convince you; I am here to share my experience as asked in the above question. The mere fact that you are trying to invalidate my experience is a fitting example of the point that I am trying to make.

Comment: I'm not trying to _"invalidate"_ your experience. I'm trying to provide an explanation.

Comment: Re *"I've spent hours reading through documentation and trying various solutions"*: Does that imply also searching for similar questions on Stack Overflow (not a rhetorical question)? Why or why not? (It can be nontrivial to find such questions.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I can't speak for everyone, but in my case I'm inclined to say it does. For me, the typical escalation path of a problem is: 1: read documentation, 2: search on google, 3: search on specific forums (including StackOverflow), 4: post on a forum. I'm a typical software engineer in the sense that I don't ask questions when I haven't explored my own possibilities yet, but that also means that I'm typically at wit's end whenever I do reach the point of asking a question.

Comment: @LeeWhite [so] search has never been great, just combine 2. and 3. into `site:stackoverflow.com your search` as your Google search and you'll get far better results.

Comment: "But you're a new user, already demotivated by the problem you're facing, the experience does leave some things to be desired." That's why in already in 2015 some people proposed StackOverflow Academy, a place to learn how to write good questions that will be well received. At the time the idea was rejected. Maybe it would have helped a bit.

Comment: @Trilarion I don't think something like this will help. Because many newcomers treat SO as tutorial site, or something like this. One thing is posting bad question, other thing is spamming and asking for help before trying to learn programming or going to college; some comments are harsh for reason. I never posted anything on Maths or Physics site, not because I was never interested, but because I don't know this topics too well to make meaningful contribution.

Comment: @LazarĐorđević There used to be a "minimal understanding required" close reason, but that was abandoned and now you can ask even the most basic question, but only once and chances are incredibly large it has been asked already. So yes, asking a good new question is incredibly difficult. SO is mostly meant for reading and editing, a bit like Wikipedia. It's not an "ask anything" service. That's probably the common misconception.

Comment: @Trilarion To but it very bluntly, that comes down to the fact that Stackoverflow looks and functions like a typical Q&A website but its community doesn't want it to be used as one. I do not think that the website can ever get rid of that perception from new users, so long as it continues to offer asking/answering open-ended questions as its main functionality.

Comment: @LeeWhite Bluntness appreciated. I understand that and that's why I have given up reviewing, voting and answering new questions already some time ago unless I stumble by accident upon one I really like and feel like it. Everyone uses or doesn't use SO as he/she sees fit.

Answer (score 10):

What threw me off was the experience of writing a first question on a different SE site, as an experienced user on another.

Because they are all SE sites, a user might expect that they would "work" in similar ways, and the user's experience on SO would translate to knowing how the other SE works.

However on the network, I found SE sites can operate quite differently depending on the mods and 'culture' and what is seen to be a good question, and even what is not off-topic despite the SE name, among other things.

As a moderately experienced SO user who would think they know how to write an acceptable question, my first-question experiences on various network sites have been a mixed bag.

Some SE's are quite challenging to write a first question on that will be well-received (Travel.SE, for example) while others are quite lenient and helpful.

Especially if you think you know how to write a good question, you end up spending half an hour or more writing the first question on a new SE, and then that rankles a lot more if the question gets summarily closed without the chance to receive answers.

(Should time taken by the user to write/edit the question be displayed or considered as a metric?)

At the end of the day new users care more about receiving an answer as a one-to-one transaction between them and the answerer, rather than about site norms and the content being helpful to other readers.

So new users can be left with a feeling that if only the busybodies didn't interfere, someone or the other would have answered, regardless of question quality.

Comment: Yeah, this is a huge, huge problem. At some point, the moderators and/or "communities" on other SE sites decided that they could subvert the Q&A model that was established by Stack Overflow (and the other trilogy sites), creating policies that are, in some cases, in direct contradiction to fundamental and strongly-held beliefs of the core Stack Exchange platform. This has done untold harm, and resulted in endless confusion and conflict.

Comment: "time taken by the user" - nah, simply not worth the hassle. If a user leaves the tab open for two weeks, then submits the question, does this tell us anything useful? Nope, the question might still be utter crap, and even the information presented would be false to begin with. The rest of the answer is fine, IMO

Comment: @Oleg Valter is with Ukraine: *Statistically* it could make sense (the example would be an outlier, easily filtered out)

Comment: @PeterMortensen yeah, I was trying to express that an indicator of time spent writing a post is not a reliable source for how much effort a user put into the post - the user could've spent half the time making coffee, falling asleep on their keyboard (with many questikns it seems exactly like what happened), you name it. We could start tracking time with screenshots like freelance platforms, that would be fun :)

Answer (score 9):

I asked my first question in 2019. I was in a class taught by a mentor of mine, and he also didn't know the answer to my problem. I got 7 up-votes on that question, which really surprised me, as I had heard pretty awful things about the SO community.

Asking my question in person first really helped me boil down my question to its core components and reduce scope. I think that some of the questions I've asked since then could have really benefited from that.
I'll try to consult my rubber ducky before posting my next question.

Another thing that I think helped my question succeed was that I specified what I was trying to do on an appropriately low level. I didn't ask *"How do I write code that does "High Level Result"?"*. Instead I asked *"I'm trying to use "Specific Language Feature", but having this issue. How if at all can I use "Specific Language Feature" here?"*.

What helped me understand that I should ask my question that way was having read about the philosophy behind SO. I feel like emphasizing that for new users could be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the hint "I'm trying to use "Specific Language Feature", but having this issue. How if at all can I use "Specific Language Feature" here?", will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 8):

The first time I asked a question on SO, I had a really vexing problem getting my Ruby script to generate a GUI correctly.  It was the first time in several years that I had used Ruby so I took my time writing the question to make sure I was including all the details that might be relevant.  Before I completed writing the question, I saw a sidebar that listed a couple of potentially-related questions.  One looked promising, but upon further inspection it wasn't quite the same issue.  That question  *did* however have an entry in its "related questions" list that answered my question exactly.  My first question was over before it was ever asked.

My first several dozen questions all ended the same way.  I found that if I wrote a detailed question, the suggested posts would either answer my question or lead me to the answer in fewer than three hops.  The sheer amount of good content on here means it took me quite a while to find a question that wasn't already answered.  At some point, I stumbled across a comment where someone described some of SO's advanced search syntax (tags, etc).  Once I learned how to do that and how to use google/duckduckgo to search the site, I got a lot better at finding answers to my questions before trying to ask them.

My first couple of questions that actually got asked all went the same way.  I had been reading and answering questions on SO for several years at that point, and had seen plenty of examples of bad or unanswerable questions.  I knew how much time many people (myself included) put into writing a quality answer, so I wasn't going to just slap together a question in a minute and expect someone to spend 10x that long on a quality answer.  I set aside about 20 minutes to write up my question, re-read and proofread it, and ensure that it contained all the information needed to understand the issue while not being overly verbose.  By the next morning, I had a couple of answers and comments already.  Definitely a pleasant surprise.  My first questions were on fairly niche topics so I wasn't expecting a lot of activity.  Some were even from fairly high-reputation users, which felt particularly nice.

The order in which I participated on SO really had an impact on my experience.  I spent a long time answering questions before I ever asked one.  That meant I already had firsthand experience both with answers people valued and accepted, and with answers that were largely ignored.  I was able to read a question and have a good instinct about whether it contained enough information for me to write an answer that people would find useful.  I had seen questions that made you just *want* to answer them, and others that made you hit the "back" button after reading halfway through.  That kind of knowledge enabled me to write questions that were received better than someone who doesn't even create an account until they need to ask a question.  I also felt like other users were more likely to answer a question posted by a user with a non-trivial amount of reputation than a question by a fresh account with single-digit reputation (and on the flipside, users who have answered several questions seem significantly less likely to ask bad questions).

The other big thing that impacted my overall experience was searching.  When searching for a programming topic on Google, SO content tends to be in the first couple of results.  As you click on SO content more and more, the Google algorithm starts showing you more and more SO content in your search results.  At the suggestion of a coworker, I started using DuckDuckGo instead of Google when searching for programming-related topics.  I still get plenty of SO content, but it seems to be much better about including official documentation, relevant blogs, etc. in the first page of results.  These non-SO results are the type of content that we tend to point people to when they post extremely low-quality questions.  I've always been curious how many of the low-quality questions get asked by people who came here from Google and have been filter-bubbled to the point where it's hard for them to find answers anywhere else.  They get here, the site's built-in search doesn't help much, and they throw together a question not knowing what else to do.

Comment: "not knowing what else to do" Maybe we could point them to official documentation instead. So as soon as they enter tags, we give them a list of official documentation related to the tags (from the tag wikis maybe) and ask them to consider searching there too before posting their question. Even if only a low percentage of new questions doesn't need to be asked because of that, it might be worthwhile.

Comment: @Trilarion That would indeed be a nice enhancement to the tag wikis.  Something like that might have existed when the "SO Documentation" project was active, but it would be helpful if we had that functionality now.

Comment: I like your answer very much, I'm happy to learn I wasn't the only one writing a question for several minutes to find out the answer already exists (a couple dozen times for me), thanks to related topics crawling. Each time I felt immediate horror spike feeling followed by a deep relief "thank God I didn't click that Post button" (plus the bonus solution to my issue). Your experience (the way you share it) deserve to figure in a documentary video about SO, "What is it for and how to use it", ie, don't wait to have a question to ask to participate.. and also, never skip the "search more" phase.

Answer (score 8):

My first question ended up fine, but only because the question happens to interest some people and they had the patience to tell me how to write a question on SO. Despite the common sentiment that newcomers won't ever read a guide, I did look for one but never found it. You had to know SO pretty well to know how to crawl through meta and that caused unnecessary friction on both sides.

What really stung was a later attempt at a Q&A. It sucked. And it got deleted. The sad part was that it was decent content that took a lot of effort, but not in a format fit for SO. There is no reason that should happen, that someone determined to contribute and *wanted* to conform to community standards, couldn't.

In both cases, I took negative feedback way too personally. It may be obvious from the perspective of experienced users that the feedback is aimed at the post, but it isn't at all clear to a newcomer, especially one new to the interwebz. I have no idea why I stuck around, and I can understand if someone just gives up after such ordeals.

Answer (score 8):

My experience was just fine. But I was already a programming veteran when SO appeared, so my experience is not typical.

I'm actually writing this answer because I have a general objection to the idea that it is possible to make the first question on a general Q&A site a good experience.

**The first time you do anything is rarely a good experience.**

First time playing the violin, your first dance, your first marriage, you name it. You have no clue, and it shows. That's unavoidable. Don't try to "sugarcoat" it. Sure, the reactions should not be actively mean. But:

**It is not only unavoidable but desirable that people tell you that you have no clue.**

We really don't want your next question be equally stupid. Most good first questions have one thing in common: They were not asked.

Comment: "First time playing the violin, your first dance, your first marriage, you name it. You have no clue, and it shows. That's unavoidable. Don't try to "sugar-code" it." That's totally contrary to all music teachers I have ever witnessed. When they teach someone how to learn a music instrument they will praise the learner a lot during the initial time. Actually incredibly much. But then they get paid for it, so it may be a different thing.

Comment: @Trilarion Yes, it's their job to help the novices take the first steps. Is that the mission of SO, respectively SO's users -- us -- who constitute SO? Because SO is nothing but their users (and a clever gamification idea, and some code to implement it). I suppose that's the direction SO's owners are trying to nudge us into. I'm not particularly happy about it. And I don't mind helping the occasional newcomer, especially if their question cannot be directly answered by googling the keywords. It's just not the funnest part of SO; it's not the reason I'm here.

Comment: Something I'm not the only one thinking of: Perhaps we need an SO "bunny slope" where people are getting help with the first steps from users who know what to expect. Doesn't have to be a different sub (sub) stack -- even a "beginner" tag would help (but [the idea was not well received](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252781/would-it-be-a-terrible-idea-to-split-so-up-into-a-tiered-platform/306572?r=SearchResults&s=5|25.5500#306572)).

Comment: One way or another, for SO you are simply an unpaid volunteer. When they talk about idealistic goals like "open information" then they probably do not really mean it. Their goals might be different from your goals. See for example: [Who is the customer for the main site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387624/who-is-the-customer-for-the-main-site)

Comment: One of the better received proposals is *[Create a separate, independent advanced Stack Overflow, focusing on being a knowledge library (but still part of the network)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390983)*. And [Jeff Atwood supports it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jurlnqqWKA&t=43m32s): *"There needs to be a beginner version of Stack Overflow."*

Answer (score 7):

I prepared for the worst and hoped for the best, knowing of *Stack Overflow's* reputation. The site just expects a certain kind of work beforehand. So, knowing that, I read through the guide on how to ask a question, and everything worked fine.

After a few years here, I only got a handful of negative experiences, so I guess people should be bit more thick-skinned.

Comment: Re *"The site just expects a certain kind of work beforehand."*: That is a very succinct way of saying it. It could even be served to new users.

Comment: SO has a *very* friendly reputation compared to, say, the reputation of Usenet's comp.lang.c.

Comment: "so I guess people should be bit more thick-skinned." Reads like "I was ok, so clearly it's other people who have an issue." Which is really unempathetic

Comment: _Which is really unempathetic_: Can hardly argue that, but I stand by my comment.

Answer (score 6):

I only ever asked one question about an edge case of a Python script's execution in different programming environments. I think it's a fairly advanced problem. One downvote made me reconsider the wording of the title so that the content of the question becomes clearer in the title. I got a lot of helpful comments, but never an answer or could verify the suggestions in the comments. Very nice reactions and help from the community, but 7 months later still no answer.

Answer (score 6):

My first question (2015) was motivated by several factors:

- I was registered for two years and had already posted several answers long ago
- kind of understood questions requirements: no duplicate, ask something specific, what you tried/already know, etc.
- the perceived image of SO *before you ask* your first question is: **SO is THE resource** to learn. Most answers are already there, so if the question/answer is not yet there, you *can* ask that question (on topic: SO = writing code)

Like all first-time askers, I'm not perfect: I need to know what a concept does and how it works/how it fails to work ([async/await](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Async/await)) to understand it, yet, days if not weeks taking courses, reading books and blogs, watching videos (of experts) failed to explain those things to me (focussing on other matters like the result instead of the path and mechanism), I ended up with the wrong concept of the thing. I resolved myself to ask something specific on SO. Result: a question that has no meaning, failing to understand what the thing (async/await) is about in the first place.

**The problem** is not asking a bad question (it being a duplicate, a homework, etc.). It's the way you get harsh/lecturing comments, downvotes, flags in the first minutes, hours, or couple of days. Over the years, I've seen it so many times, especially around 2018-2020, first time question getting -10 and quite mean comments (not everyone is as strong as you, mentally).

I've recommended SO so many times, and got friends and colleagues yelling at me "SO is just a clan of people so full of themselves". I kind of understand what they meant. However, today, that is not really the case anymore.

What I believe are missing:

- clearly warn SO is not your average forum where anyone ask whatever ASAP. No, if you don't understand something, go google outside SO. If you want opinions or "where to find this", the same. etc. (off-topic)
- prepare to start with a bad reputation for some time. Nobody's perfect, everybody started there, and eventually, you'll get somewhere, so don't bother the (sometimes) cold welcome, just keep calm and get better little by little. I believe this is the best advice one can give.

Comment: I did mention that very issue during my interview with Juan Garza et Ben Popper, in Oct. 2021: downvotes and close vote are *immediately* applied. For a new user, this is not helpful.

Comment: @VonC is it better to have them falsely believe everything is fine while the votes keep coming in?

Comment: Re *"...clearly warn SO is not your average forum"*: There is little hope when even [the CEO thinks it is a forum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPbbt7Dg-2U&t=2m57s) (that was about 10 months in)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't knew that were that much video of the kind on YT. Not that I have that much time to have a look, but will surely care more from now on.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I understand the concern. I also don't want SO to have tons of garbage. However it's thanks to SO mainly I could contribute in my job, here and elsewhere : I was better prepared than others to pass the "first time question and the overall perception of that experience". "Rage-quit then wandering in the hell of smelly code" is a concern IMHO. Reviewing the DV system and disclaimer or not is up to who are in charge, we don't suggest here, it's okay. I'm not challenging your concern, just trying to poinpoint actual issues on the matter to ultimately help get the correct solution.

Comment: ex : I've read a vague question. Poster quickly got DV-ed. I checked the other topics (duplicates ?), then answered based on what I assumed to be the issue. At the same time poster complained about DV reasons, you could tell he was pissed. Later on, poster answered with his own solution, not anywhere near the explained issue; but the good thing is, the question got upvoted aswell as my answer, meaning at least it helped a few people. What would have happenned if I DV-ed, not answered and not shared what I believed to be the reason of the DVs.. this is not a rare occurence.

Answer (score 6):

When I asked my first question, I was already a veteran of message boards and a long time user of Stack Overflow as someone posting answers.

So my question was very prepared. It contained an MCVE and was very clear and focused. I would like to think that all my questions are. But they are not "easy". It takes time to read and understand them, even the boiled down minimum reproducible  sandbox version that I ask here.

And my first question had the same problem that many of my questions here still have:

A random person downvoted them once with no comment and nothing for me to constructively do about it. And then it sat there, for days with no answer and no traffic.

Granted, after a few days someone knowledgeable would come around and invest the time to read and understand the question and answer it. Sometimes the answer takes time. Sometimes it's something stupid I did and neither my sandboxing nor my colleague checking it caught (like using the wrong variable) and the answer is simple. And after a few *years* of people seeing it, a few upvotes will trickle in and override the downvote.

But the initial impact is rather negative. A downvote with no good (or at least explainable) reason, sitting there with no traffic, because it fell of the front page.

The *feeling* I get from this is that we have all those guidelines for good questions and we all love them and love to tell people they should abide by them, but we as a community are more interested in snatching green Internet points by telling kids with homework for the billionth time how a loop works, than actually investing time into reading and understanding complex questions, no matter how well presented.

As a perfect example I would cite [Custom GUID always return false on object.Equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51559229/custom-guid-always-return-false-on-object-equals). I think the question is okay, and it got a great answer, yet it has as many downvotes as upvotes without any obvious reason.

Comment: "investing time into reading and understanding complex questions" I would like to do that, yet increasingly feel like investing time *to find* such questions is getting ridiculous.

Comment: I would think this happens very frequently for beginners, particularly when they haven't understood the significance of tags. A post that for example lacks a major programming language tag will simply get lost in cyberspace without anyone finding it.

Answer (score 6):

##### The Code Golf sandbox is a bad example

The Code Golf sandbox is a bit of a special case. It doesn't apply just for newbies, it's strongly recommended that *all* questions go through that process. It's really hard to write a good Code Golf challenge, one that doesn't have weird loopholes or undesirable characteristics, and that is actually interesting to people. Quite different to StackOverflow where it's not particularly difficult to grasp the mechanics of writing a decent question.

##### In response to your question

My first question was so long ago (12 years!), it doesn't seem relevant. I think it was fine? My first two questions (looking them up) both got useful answers, although the first one was closed a few years later for being off-topic (soliciting recommendations).

Comment: Also good Code Golf posts should be interesting to anyone regardless of programming language, whereas a good SO post should be narrowed-down as much as possible. So the Code Golf sandbox could serve as a place to get feedback from people who know various languages that you don't know yourself. On SO, the people who would be most suited to give feedback to a properly narrow and specific question are those with domain knowledge of that specific topic. And maybe those would rather just answer the technical question instead of helping out beginners with how to communicate with humans in text etc.

Answer (score 6):

> Improving the first-time asker experience - What was asking your first question like?

Relatively painless.

Why? Because I spent many months answering questions on Stack Overflow before I ever asked my first question. Whenever answering questions, I took note of the kinds of feedback different questions were getting.

I acknowledge this is a minority position but I still think this is right - that SO participants should, ideally, learn to give better and better answers *before* they ever ask a question themselves.

It's worth noting that I have voiced this position before and my articulation of this position was downvoted to oblivion. I am very much encouraged to see that there are other like-minded members here voicing the same position.

I observe that these days my question-to-answer ratio is far higher now even compared to when I'd been a member of SO for 2-3 years.

**Before you ask others for help, *start* by helping others.**

Comment: "Before you ask others for help, start by helping others." In principle I full agree but I think there is a problem here somewhere. Askers may not always be proficient enough to answer before and if everyone would do it like this, who would still ask something then? Maybe people can learn how to ask a good question even without needing to answer before. Or maybe most good questions have already been asked and new questions are likely not good.

Comment: I absolutely see what you're saying @Trilarion, but for me this is the line. If a new member of SO absolutely cannot help any other member with _anything_, then... maybe they should come back to SO when they are in a stronger position to do so. I recognise that not everyone will agree on this point but, for me, a criterion for joining SO is (or should be): _"Can you help / guide / teach others?"_ And I don't think that's too stringent a criterion - I believe almost everyone can.

Comment: "Can you help / guide / teach others?" Yes, I know what you want. Just wanted to say that the number of those "others" that needs teaching would then go down a lot if everyone already had those abilities. We would simply be kind of professionals helping each other out with much, much less redundancy in newly asked questions.

Answer (score 6):

I asked my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16049381/2288578) in 2013. With the exception of a bit of unnecessary fluff (that was edited out by another user, to my great surprise at the time) it was well-formatted, clean and simple. It quickly got some upvotes and made me feel great about myself. I also received a clear and straightforward answer within a few minutes of asking, so this was about as perfect a first experience as you can get.

If I recall correctly, I was a lurker for a fair while before asking that question and I definitely understood the Q&A format.

I asked my second question only a few hours later and was disappointed that it wasn't upvoted, however it did get a good answer almost immediately so it was still useful.

---

If I were to post that first question today, I'd be pretty surprised if it didn't immediately downvoted. I would *hope* that it would get marked a duplicate, but my gut is telling me it would just get downvoted and that's all.

I have the sense that people were vastly more eager to get rep and help out back in 2013 than they are today. That's probably true, given there were less users, less terrible questions and less fatigue back then. I expect the novelty has well and truly worn off.

My personal experience is that asking a question today is terrifying and incredibly frustrating. I absolutely detest it. Even when I *know* it's a reasonable question and do my very best to ask well, there's a high chance that someone won't read it properly and will just do a drive-by downvote. That's their right, of course, but after the first downvote, it's much less likely to get an answer (or at the very least, feels that way). I'm firmly of the opinion that people are far too quick to downvote or closevote. My assumption is that this behaviour stems from the high number of poor questions in general, but that doesn't make it any less frustrating to the asker when the downvoter clearly didn't even take the time to read the question.

Comment: While often repeated, I've never seen any actual evidence that downvoted questions are less likely to receive an answer. Nor does it match with my experience. You are also wearing rose-colored glasses when looking back on 2013. I was there; plenty of questions got closed and downvoted, perhaps even more than now, because the scale of questions did not yet vastly outstrip the number of people with privileges to curate them. [Fatigue at the volume of low-quality questions was a big thing, too, even back then](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174097). Not much has really changed.

Comment: @CodyGray Rather than rose-coloured glasses, I would say these days I'm just more aware of how bad it feels to get instantly downvoted. As far as negative-score questions getting more or less answers... well I have no data to support that. It's just how it feels. You know that someone, somewhere thinks your question is bad, but is too high and mighty to bother explaining how or why. You're stuck hours-deep in a problem but someone only takes 2.5 seconds to scan your question, downvote and move on. It seems completely reasonable that if one person downvoted, probably others will too.

Comment: I know it sounds like I'm just being melodramatic, and rationally I agree completely, but when you've spent hours searching for an answer and it seems like you're the only person who's ever been confused by this, by the time you finally succumb and ask a question on SO, it doesn't take much to make you want to give up and cry. At least, that's my experience. It sounds really pathetic, but I'm certain that my experience isn't unusual so I think it's worth saying.

Comment: I'm still puzzled at why downvoting would feel so bad. I mean, being downvoted on SO wasn't the first time someone ever disagreed with me, or thought I was being unclear, so it wasn't exactly an eye-opening experience. *"but is too high and mighty to bother explaining how or why"* Nah, they just think the tooltip on the downvote arrow already provides an adequate explanation. Our own problems always seem more serious to us than they do to others; that's just life. Also, being hours-deep in a problem also tends to negatively impact our communication skills, so that's worth keeping in mind.

Comment: @CodyGray _"still puzzled at why downvoting would feel so bad"_ I think it's simply because you don't get a chance to defend yourself. Someone says "this is bad/incorrect/not worth responding to" but then walks away with their hands over their ears. Pretty unpleasant after you put so much effort into distilling the issue and writing the question. _"being hours-deep in a problem also tends to negatively impact our communication skills"_ 100%, I completely agree. I always try to write the question and then come back later and re-read it before posting. Same with writing messages while angry.

Comment: @CodyGray Downvoting feels bad because you aren't posting an opinion on Reddit, you're asking for help. Getting a downvote with no comment - along with a little notification that you've lost rep to guarantee you know about every downvote - is someone saying "I don't think this person deserves even the minor help of searching for a duplicate". I know all the standard replies to this, and none of them actually address the issue of the new user experience. As another answer said, asking a question by definition happens from ignorance. All the standard replies assume knowledge.

Comment: In a participant-centric perspective, it may seem counterintuitive to let people downvote without providing feedback. The thing is, Stack Overflow is primarily _content-centric_, so it is not that focused on the asker. It is important for everyone else that voting is frictionless, so that people in general obtain an aggregated rating of the post based on its quality and usefulness. As such, it's really best not to take downvotes personally. And if you are desperately in need of help after a closed question, there are other venues which can give you more of a helpdesk experience.

Comment: @E_net4standswithUkraine _"Stack Overflow is primarily content-centric"_ true, but that doesn't solve the awful experience part, and we can't insist it does when no new user gets it.

Comment: @E_net4standswithUkraine _"it's really best not to take downvotes personally."_ While I've been on both sides of that particular coin, when it actually comes time to ask a question, it's not possible (at least for me) to not take it personally. I mean, how could one not? A downvote says "your question is bad". Even if you're new and don't know how to ask a good question, imagine the real-life equivalent: you walk into a group and take your chair in the circle, then timidly ask your question. Everyone just frowns and says "wow, what a stupid question". Way to make you feel bad.

Comment: @Appleguysnake Actually, you reveal your fundamental misunderstanding of the purpose of this site when you say "you're asking for help". In fact, you are not. You're contributing a question to our knowledge base. The fact that the answer might help you is only a side benefit, from the perspective of the site's design and purpose. As it says in the [tour]: *"With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming."* It doesn't say, "We offer a help desk resource." I agree, though, the rep notifications should be removed.

Comment: @Clonkex It is not like that at all; your analogy doesn't hold. The better analogy is, you walk up to a museum curator and hand them a memento from your childhood. They frown and say, "That would not be a good addition to our collection here at this museum." Are you going to take that personally? I don't know; I guess you *could*, but honestly, I think it seems a bit silly to do so. In fact, I would even go so far as to say that taking that personally would be a sign of a dangerously inflated ego. Your childhood keepsake may be priceless to you, but that doesn't make it valuable to everyone.

Comment: @Clonkex By feeling very attached to the content of your creation on this platform (or anywhere else), you may fall into the trap of being emotionally struck by the society's rejection of that content. One part of that reaction is inherent to our nature, but is one that we also learn to overcome in a modern society.

Comment: @Clonkex _" imagine the real-life equivalent:"_ No, it is more akin to failing a school examination, not getting a job offering, or having an academic paper rejected for publishing. And likewise, no one here calls your question "stupid" when downvoting. Moreover, that example, once again, translates the environment of Stack Overflow into a forum or discussion circle, which is a very bad analogy for what is done here.

Comment: @CodyGray y'all can't even agree with yourselves on an analogy for how the site works, which is imo the best analogy for the problems with the site. That and pretending that anyone would ask a question if they weren't hopeful they could get an answer. The collection of questions come from humans, no matter how many times you link to an elevator pitch that isn't going to change how humans react to things.

Comment: @Appleguysnake Sorry, who is it that can't agree? Everyone I know is in agreement with the model stated in the [tour], that we're building a library of high-quality answers to questions about programming. In that sense, the model is more like Wikipedia, except instead of long-form articles, the information is broken down into bite-sized chunks asked in the form of questions. Where, exactly, are you seeing the disagreement? This is not a help desk; no one ever said it was. We don't care about the motivations of the asker. We only care about building our knowledge base and making it the best.

Answer (score 5):

My 1st question on SO was yesterday.

My previous experience in asking technical Qs was on the Google Docs forum, SO appears similar but the etiquette is much more detailed and enforced.

My question had a context, the goal, a link to a demo of the code/problem, a final specific question. It received a downvote and was closed for lack of debugging details.

I was a bit dismayed, but I read the message, and I did my best to satisfy the parameters, embedding code, highlighting sections...

While the question is still closed, somebody edited it and made it more legible, and I also received a comment (asking to use mock data which is more similar to actual data), so I improved the Q because of that comment.

Now I'm lost because I don't understand why the Q is still closed, who can see/ edit/comment/ answer it, if editing it will automatically bump it, how the community sees the practice of delete-&-repost... THIS IS FYI, because I think I'll find the anwers by digging in SO.

*EDIT 1: I did found the [Help section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help), and the answers I was looking for (and more). I wanted to post BEFORE doing some research to provide the thoughts of a newbie. Also, thanks to those who answered in the comments, it's encouraging!*

*EDIT 2: my question is now open, thanks at least in part to those who read this very post and voted the Q (thanks). Again, it's very encouraging :)*

Another thing: I stumbled here before getting 5 rep, and when I've seen that some people had issues getting any upvote in the first Q it seemed to me that this Q has a great barrier. If you want to help new users and hear their opinion you may want to remove the 5 rep requirement. (I don't know who upvoted my Q, but I'm thankful)

Comment: _"Now I'm lost"_ The help center covers one part of [how reopening a question works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions), although it could also mention that an edit can put the question in a review queue, in which users with the necessary privileges can make their own assessment of whether the question is ready to be answered. In this case, it has now received enough votes to be reopened.

Comment: A lot of the issues like delete & repost really isn't documented in a way that is easy to find. Some form of actual community editable wiki from the various meta posts could be really useful here as there are lots of good suggestions the community has made in the past about improving the help center that just never happened. (Prehaps this could be a use for the Articles feature).

Comment: Your first question is quite good. Congratulations. The sections headings do remind you to put sufficient information in the question and you did, but even more elegant is just using the suitable language elements instead. Use "I have ..., I want .... However, I get .... How can I ..." and everything will come almost naturally. Good luck in the future.

Comment: Thank you, both for the positive feedback and the guidance. I'll ask you: I like to start paragraphs with KEYWORDS which describes them, it's like tags for humans. I see you removed them from my Q, should I avoid them? (I've looked for info on this topic, but found none)

Comment: @DavidBevi We are humans and probably like to read text just fine. I often use paragraphs and keep the length as short as possible, but using rather generic paragraph headings is often not needed. See my example above "I have ..." is context "I want" is requirements "I get" is problem and "How do I" is asking for a solution. No need for additional headers there.

Comment: Deleting and re-posting shouldn't be encouraged and closing a question isn't the end of the journey. The OP can always edit their question into shape and it also means that any clarity through comments is not lost or being re-hashed in the re-posted question.

Answer (score 4):

My first question (and my only net downvoted question) was an issue I was having with a school assignment.  The question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467993/error-c2143-syntax-error-missing-before-constant), and the issue, as you can see, turned out to be '1' and 'l' look really similar in the font I was using ([Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio)'s default at the time).  It was obvious to see once pointed out, but an easy-to-miss mistake in that font.  Obviously I missed it, but also both friends I asked to help me missed it.  To this day it's also my second most viewed question (4k at time of writing this), so I'm guessing that other student's have been helped by it (can't see the views over time obviously)?

I really didn't want to ask at the time, because I'd seen a lot of questions that had a lot of downvotes and/or had been closed as duplicates, with comments along the lines of "this should be obvious."  This was somewhat confirmed when the question almost immediately went to -3 with no answers or comments.  Then went up to -2 and had 2 answers and several comments when I next looked.  The answers were exactly the problem, and it was embarrassing to not notice that, but I was (and am) happy that they were all polite/business like instead of what I'd seen on some other questions.  Overall I'd say it ended up being a neutral experience.

The question is now at a -1 and has been for years, so I feel like I probably managed to help out at least one other person with the same error.  If you ignore the color, I still have a hard time seeing the diff between 11 and ll when I look at that code in SE's code view.

Comment: Other ones, including invisible ones, like *NO-BREAK SPACE*, *[ZERO WIDTH SPACE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)*, *ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER*, *EN DASH*, *EM DASH*, *LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK*, *RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK*, *MINUS SIGN*, *LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS*, *REPLACEMENT CHARACTER*, and *ASTERISK OPERATOR*, respectively can also [be puzzling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/). They can arise from copying from other media, like web pages, Skype chat, and PDF documents.

Comment: For a more complete list, see https://github.com/reinderien/mimic

Answer (score 4):

My [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43414710/dynamically-instantiate-pages-tkinter) was the quintessential "newcomer" question. I was stuck on a tkinter problem, didn't know how to describe what I wanted to do, and created a phrase that I thought described the problem. It's also not even formatted that well. I got comments that, at the time, I perceived to be mean, but eventually got an answer that helped me.

It took a while before I asked my next question, but the more I participated on the site and learned how to properly debug programs, I realized why my first question wasn't well received.

There wasn't a good description of what the desired behavior was, nothing showing what was actually wrong, no real MCVE, and jargon that I thought was correct but wasn't.

I've come a long way since then, and I can quickly find answers to most problems that I encounter. The few corner cases I hit where I have to ask, I know how to write much better questions.

Answer (score 4):

I don't remember my very first question, but asking questions is generally unpleasant and I almost never use the site to ask questions unless I'm answering it too. (I do ask sometimes if I think I have a good question). It is a very good place to document answers however.

I think what is missed by many about question asking is that the question asker is necessarily asking their question from a position of ignorance. The whole point is that I am missing something and I don't know what I'm missing. If I knew what it was, I wouldn't ask. This means there is a strong chance that the question is "off" in some way, but it can't be helped because I am working with a blind spot on that particular concept. Question askers are often criticized (it seems) for this ignorance, when it is a necessary part of question asking. (This is why very often the best apparent quality of question comes from people who already know the answer, because they can ask it without the blind spot.)

Comment: It's not the ignorance, but the lack of effort. In this day and age, not googling something is unacceptable, and that's often what it takes. There's plenty of well-received questions born of ignorance.

Answer (score 3):

I was surprised by the first two responses to my first question.  They both indicated they hadn't fully read or comprehended the question.  I was asking for a simple shell-based convenience tool for filtering text copied from the clipboard at the [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) shell command prompt, without having to divert through an intermediary file.  Both responses said to use a file, even though the question was specifically asking for a technique which did not use that.

Comment: Then maybe the question was unclear?

Comment: It was not.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71351092/

Comment: Not completely convinced the question is actually on-topic here. [how to copy&paste cleanly into grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71351092/1426539)

Comment: That's a different issue. In hindsight the question would fit in Unix&Linux.  The boundaries between stacks is not always clearcut.

Comment: The downvote here _might_ be because you're asserting that the user that commented on your question (and is trying to _help_ you) hasn't read the question fully. That assumption can't be verified, and is unconstructive. 2 Minutes is plenty to read this question.

Comment: As you can see, there is often a good reason for the reception that you obtained. Please keep [Hanlon's razor](https://fs.blog/mental-model-hanlons-razor/) close next time, before posting the kind of comment you made here.

Comment: Yeah, well, this comment chain illustrates the issue perfectly

Comment: @Paul Is it an issue that people are subjected to constructive criticism when they post anything on this platform?

Comment: The problem is more that the criticism was not constructive,

Comment: The criticism here is constructive much more often than not but of course humans can err. So in the end nobody knows for sure who's right and wrong, but the amount of feedback might be a strong hint.

Comment: So far all the comments posted here have been constructive. However, that still doesn’t stop certain users saying this comment thread "illustrates the problem perfectly". When in fact, it’s more their comment that illustrates the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly new to Stack Overflow and have only asked two questions overall. As I had already been contributing to the website, I thought I knew how to ask a question (especially one in the same tags I usually answer questions in).

So I did the necessary: did my fair share of googling, was straight to the point, added code, data sample, desired output, explained the issue completely and precisely. I basically wrote my questions the way I'd want to see them asked when I'm the one answering.

The first question got two downvotes and two upvotes, and got some quality answers. The second question got four downvotes and was closed, because "it needs to be more focused and has to be updated to focus on one problem only" (it was straightforward and definitely focused on only one problem).

I'm very open to criticism, but the most frustrating (and infuriating) thing was getting downvotes and my question closed without any indication as to how I could improve it or what was so wrong with it.

Comment: But "needs to be more focused on one problem only" is some kind of indication of how to improve it and what is wrong with it. I haven't looked at this question in particular, but couldn't it simply be a disagreement between you and the 4 people who seems to not have liked it.

Answer (score 3):

Back in the day, I didn't dare to ask a question until I had lurked for quite a while and answered a few questions. It was 7 months from the time I *answered* my first question to the time I *asked* my first question; by then, I had answered roughly 20 questions.

Moreover, my first question was so good that today it has 28 upvotes (and two downvotes), and it inspired a now extremely well-known programmer / blogger to respond by creating a powerful new interface object.

And that is how I think it should be.

The bar to entry for asking questions should be *very high*. You should have a certain amount of rep before you can ask a question at all; you should have had to prove your value to the site and your ability to obey the rules. And asking a bad question, for an early user, should generate a significant period of silence, i.e. inability to ask another question.

Stack Overflow has gone exactly the wrong way on this. The day question upvotes changed from meaning 2 points of rep, matching the meaning of downvotes, to 10 points of rep, is one of the worst days in the whole life of Stack Overflow — because it takes a lot of downvotes to give the bad questioner the right message, especially in view of the fact that there is always someone who will indiscriminately come along and upvote a question, thus sending a bad questioner a very wrong message. It now takes all the running we can do to stay in one place, trying desperately to keep the crap off the site, and losing more ground every moment. Be as friendly as you like, but the bar to entry needs to be *higher*, not lower.

Comment: Well said, @matt. Re: _"The bar to entry for asking questions should be very high. You should have a certain amount of rep before you can ask a question at all; you should have had to prove your value to the site and your ability to obey the rules."_  I couldn't agree more.

Comment: "I didn't dare to ask a question until I had lurked for quite a while and answered a few questions." Back then, when there were still so many interesting unanswered questions. But nowadays, where shall these interesting not yet answered questions come from? It seems we probably run out of askers (of good questions) before we run out of answerers.

Comment: @Trilarion If users would _search_ before asking, most of them would not need to ask any question at all. People are so self-centered, they imagine they are the only ones ever to encounter an issue, or that they deserve special hand holding. Instead of treating SO as an encyclopedia, they try to turn it into a code writing service.

Comment: It would be an interesting experiment if we publically required all questions to sit around for a week in a non-published form (in an editable for so you can add research), and the asker to come back and explicitly make them public. It seems like that would discorage an awful lot of homework dumps and other low effort questions.

Comment: @user1937198 You know, I think there's a somewhat palatable way to do the experiment. Create a privileged queue of questions with delayed publishing, let the usual questions go on and we can see what we get there.

Answer (score 3):

I asked my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474164/rails-seeding-database-data-and-date-formats) 11 years ago. I was still a student at the time, and my Ruby web application was not parsing data in the way that the documentation indicated it should. I wanted to understand why, but people just gave me code and said "do it this way instead.". It wasn't my goal to "get it working" -- that was the easy part; I came here to figure out why my code didn't work when the documentation indicated that it *should*. I'm still miffed, because I *still* don't understand why it didn't work as written.

Since then I've stuck around and answered questions, making sure that I always explain *why* the original attempt doesn't work, in addition to providing a solution. I'm giving other people the sort of answer I wish I had gotten to my own first question.

Answer (score 3):

I asked my first question a year ago after a decade of benefiting from reading other questions. Overall, it was not as painful as I anticipated. The first few hours were daunting, waiting to see if I would get down-voted or have my question marked as a duplicate (I was confident it was not).

The question was about a source control issue caused partly by my own misunderstanding but I was pleased to see that the answers were helpful and not dismissive in any way, as I half-expected them to be. It appears that the community is constantly improving, both from the top down and the bottom up.

I haven't asked a second question yet as I've found other answers on SO or results on Google already address what I'm looking for.

Comment: I like this answer (and your attitude) overall, but I have to admit I'm bothered by the notion that it would be "daunting" to countenance receiving a downvote. It just means someone on the Internet thought your question was unclear or not useful. In other words, someone disagreed with you. Big deal. Not anything to get excited about. Certainly not something that should be daunting or fill anyone with dread.

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray I think it's more a personal thing... I'd had a bad experience on a hardware forum years ago when asking for help so that may have played into my expectations.

Answer (score 3):

I remember asking early on what `< >` meant in Java. Someone commented something about me needing to read a basic Java book. Another user, though, kindly came to my defense and said that it would be hard to search for those characters. I did get an answer but it was painful. Every downvote in those early days was like a knife stab. Nowadays I don't care much about downvotes, but it was really a bad experience back then. I got question banned, so I opened a new account (this one) because I still needed answers.

These were some some things that helped me to learn how to ask better questions:

- Reminders to show my research (with links) and describe what I've tried
- Reduce the problem down to a simpler version (MCVE)
- Reading topics on SO meta

One benefit of having a bad experience myself, though, was that it gave me more empathy for new users.

Comment: But did you ever read a basic Java book? /ducks

Comment: @CodyGray, Haha, I should have taken that advice, but I don't think I ever did. It was easier to be lazy and get people on SO to answer questions for me. I was your typical new question asker.

Comment: @CodyGray, By the way, I want to say that I've been impressed with how well you've done at being moderator and tempering difficult conversations. Thank you for your service.

Comment: Thank you for appreciating my sense of humour :-)

Comment: RTFM is never ever acceptable. ***They*** utterly failed to find the duplicate among the [1,834,171 Java questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) (out of [22,361,395 questions total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)).

Comment: Absolutely agreed with @PeterMortensen. At some point, the impression developed among certain "veteran" SO users that we don't allow simple/basic questions, or any question whose answer can be found in the documentation/specification/manual/book/etc. That is completely wrong. Our mission is clearly stated in the [tour]: *"With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming."* Obviously, if it's a dupe of an existing question, it should be closed (and we'd prefer you not re-ask it), but simple questions are *fine*.

Answer (score 3):

My biggest problem with asking questions from the first one years ago to this day is the very vague threshold how minimal of an example is too minimal.

I often can trim my question down to a dozen lines of code, but communities feedback is "we don't understand your use case" where my question is basically "I am missing a keyword somewhere. Help me get this to compile"

If I leave to much info, feedback is often "can you simplify your case" / "question is too broad"

This results in me having to edit my question numerous times, integrating the answers to question arising in the comments and trimming down the fat that confuses the community. All this while my question falls down from `new` into obscurity.

I think a staging area where users can help pre-improve the questions, by posting what-would-be-a-comment, and having a conversation that is not limited by comments character limit would be of great help.

I don't propose that every question goes through the staging area, but that there is a place for users like me who need the help to get it, instead of having 20+ comments on the question, and polluting the review queue with "Improved question" edits. (Correct me if I'm wrong and self-edits are exempt.)

Comment: About the staging area: Problem is, this doesn't scale. At the size of SO with 7k questions a day, there are simply too few people who want to invest time into questions that might or might not be answerable at some point.

Comment: Also note, that the more you show that you care about SO and that you are willing to investing effort yourself, the better the responses will be. If the first thing I have to do before answering is to capitalize all I, make sure that every sentence starts with a capital letter and add a few ' (like in don't), then my motivation significantly drops. That's something any author can easily do, even with a very bad level of English. Most of this things are even handled automatically by the browsers spell checking.

Comment: @BDL Just something worth noting, having minor typos like this edited on my post and then receiving no answers or even comments was one of my major friction points as a new asker that made me not want to invest any further effort myself. Not trying to get into reasoning and solutions, it's just another small straw on the camel's back of new askers.

Comment: To clarify, what I mean is "capitalization doesn't help clarify my question, I thought the point of editing was to help the question get answers". So it's confusing, which leads to a feeling that the editor(s) are just being pedantic and not interested in helping, regardless of their actual intention.

Comment: @Appleguysnake: I usually tend to fix typos and capitalization when I read the post for the first time. At that point I usually don't even know what your asking about, whether it's on-topic or if I know the answer. At best, I save other people some headache when reading the question, at worst I wasted a few minutes. IMHO, the point of editing is to improve the question. Fixing tzpos makes it easier for the next person to read, so (in theory) it should improve your chances of getting an answer

Comment: Knowing what's minimal involves a certain level of debugging skill and knowledge. Unless SO teaches debugging to new users, this is kinda hopeless. But I also don't believe a staging area, as a place to teach that, can scale.

Comment: @Valerij Self-edits are exempt from the edit review queue. You don't need someone to approve an edit to your own question!

Comment: If community feedback is "we don't understand your use case", this is *probably not* a sign that you need more code. It's probably a sign that you need to be clearer about what you expect should happen when the code runs, what happened instead, and how that differs (and under what circumstances it differs). Assuming that your question is actually about fixing a problem in your existing code at all. If the question is actually just trying to figure out how to do something, it might not require *any* code example, but instead a clear *specification*.

Answer (score 3):

The first question posted on my account was probably the third or fourth question I've written on Stack Overflow. Multiple times, I have started writing a question, and halfway through explaining the problem in the post, I will realize what I've done wrong and cancel the post.

The first question I did end up posting was some extremely niche and strange question that I couldn't find any discussion about on this site or elsewhere. My question got a few comments from people offering advice without being able to fully answer the question.

Its not a good question but not a bad question either. I had been using Stack Overflow as a learning tool for many months prior to posting, so I knew how to format my question to fit the standards of the site.

My first-time-asker experience was improved by:

1. Researching before posting any question.
2. Having some experience with the site prior to posting.

Comment: This was my experience.  Good niche questions don't garner nearly as much reputation as basic questions.  Over the years, I've asked (and answered) lots of questions, and some of my better work remains hidden in the corners of StackOverflow.  But that's just how the system works.  I've learned more and more to try to forget about the point system and focus on asking and answering questions. At this point, I have more reputation than I need for the level of engagement I desire anyway.

Comment: [See also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416428/introducing-the-staging-ground-an-attempt-at-improving-the-first-time-asker-exp?page=2&tab=scoredesc#comment899960_416621)

Answer (score 2):

I have been using Stack Exchange network for over three years now, and my asking experience was horrible as I didn’t know how to or what/when should I ask.

As a marketer that suddenly shifted his career in 2019 as I really love coding, I must say this site helped a lot, not to mention I had zero knowledge/background of coding.

And here are some of the reasons why my asking experience was horrible.

1. I had 0 knowledge/background of what I’m asking so obvious things for you is what I’m looking for. Refusing to help or acting smart because I didn’t know how/what/when to ask was a great discouragement.
2. Programming languages are evolving so fast I remember buying a set of courses online and all of them were outdated. Most of the code was deprecated or very dangerous to use, so, when I ask about something deprecated or an error or style and get duplicates question, but still this code or concept is no longer in use, that was frustrating.
3. This is a community which means it will have different types of people, different knowledge levels, different backgrounds and different IQ levels. I know that some are very misusing this site and they just want someone to do their homework or acting stupid so you do their code, but generalize it, it is very hurting the community and very discouraging for people who are really looking for knowledge. I, myself, sometimes all I want is a keyword that I'm missing or an example or a reference that has an explanation.
4. Searching for an answer sometimes was a bit hard and sometimes extremely hard as I didn’t know that exact keyword I was looking for.

I guess these were my biggest problems using the Stack Exchange network. I'm not trying to be negative. I deactivated my account like less than two weeks ago and when I found posts on meta talking about doing positive changes, I immediately reactivated my account, waiting for the beta test and I really hope it can help. I love Stack Exchange and will never forget how much it helped me when I really needed help and didn't know where to find it.

Here are some of the suggestions I really hope to see in the future. I'm not sure if it is feasible or on topic, but I hope it can help.

1. Adding tags to answer I guess will help people search for answer and ask less. For example, if I'm asking about something in PHP, so I'm going to use the PHP tag, because most likely I don't know what topic or keywords or reference that suits perfect for my question, but the one who is going to answer it has the ability to define the question more. For example, this problem is in PHP 1~5 in select and its name reference is *foo*.
2. If number one is feasible, I guess adding a flag on the question that this code is deprecated since PHP 5 and have been replaced to and attach the new answer to it would make people less in need to ask questions as they already have the correct reference, the correct tag and the updated answer that suits PHP 5~8
3. if 1 and 2 are feasible and someone asks a new question about an already well formatted answered question, add a button to accept this duplication. And instead of closing the question, you can move it to an archive where only some a few have access too. The duplicated question can be used to only enhance the search system. For example, the title and tags used in the duplicated is now tags or similar ways to ask this question under the chosen perfect answer well formatted question.
4. Add points for people finding the desired answer by searching. Points for good duplicates. Good reinforcement is a good way to encourage behavior to reoccur  and negative reinforcement such as downvotes or closed without good explanation is very discouraging

Now you don't have the need to edit every question as someone like me doesn’t know how to well format his English to be acceptable. You have to encourage people to search. And most importantly, you are going to have a good first time question asked experience with your new wizard

Comment: Some of your suggestions are ok, but unlikely to be implemented. Point #3 already exists and we have the closure as a duplicate.

Comment: @Dharman that’s exactly my point as you generalize closure and there is so many negative reasons for it, duplicated should be treated differently and here come the positive/negative reinforcement .. first ask the person asks if this suits your question if yes find a name other than closed question give points for both .. now my mind doesnt consider this as a bad/negative incident but its okay not perfect and doesnt disencourage anyone to ask a new question

Comment: It is treated differently. Questions marked as duplicate are not as easily removed by the system. They serve as signposts leading to better answers.

Comment: At the same time this wuestion wont be appeared in the search result as an answer/question but a reference

Comment: I've said this many times but statements like *"I'm not trying to be negative. I **deactivated my account like less than 2 weeks ago** and when I found posts on meta talking about doing positive changes I immediately reactivated my account and waiting for the beta test and I really hope it can help."* *(emphasis is mine)*, just highlights to me that a person's attitude to the site is wrong, to begin with.

Comment: @user692942 my attitude to the site ? I deactivated my account as I couldn't find a good way to ask a question which in some cases I have to as i couldn't find the right keyword for reference for my problem and I'm in need of help. right before i deactivate my account " and that was the reason why " i asked a question got a really good answer but no explanation no reference no example of how to actually do it. and after a debate on meta that led to no where i've decided to i realy don't need to ask more question on here I'm just gonna stick with my process of going into an ocean of unrelated

Comment: @user692942 question. and it took me 3 more days to find the right example that doesn't explain how because i still cannot find the right keyword for it or reference. i have nothing negative for this website as i mentioned it helped me a lot and i cannot find a good reason why should i never user stack. i deactiveted my account but still i was using it every day going through question or and checking meta for any changes that can help me do better and can be part of this community

Comment: @user692942 not to mention i took an extra mile to see how it is like to answer bad question. or question that have no prior search and answer just to walk in your shoe. and i still find voting is a bit harsh system and many people misuse it on both sided but not going to go in debate about this as its an off topic for this site. but this makes me wonder your attitude towards less experienced, less knowledgeable and less reputation people on this site. remember this is a community and a perfect system is hard to achieve. i only shared my point of view

Comment: @user692942 which i think this is how you define the problem well to be able to solve it look at both sided no get info from only one side

Comment: @TaaLee Let me ask you this, what does deactivating your account achieve? You might struggle to ask questions but there may be ones you could help answer, the site is vast and covers numerous programming topics.

Comment: @user692942 deactivating my account is to tell myself to not ask question. and take a stand even if it's small action or insignificant. i believe that someone maybe years later look at it and make the change needed. im a big believe of butterfly effect"chaos theory". even if no one ever took a look at this incident. at least between me and myself i took a stand. hoping for a better experience in the future or new users

Comment: @TaaLee Hi. Welcome back. You don't need to explain in deep, I believe everyone understand what you mean. An account deactivation after a failure to post a good question can be percieved as a "rage quit" (in gaming). I don't mean it's the case, I mean, you're on the internet where people have the right to interpret your behavior the way they want : don't bother. What you should do : Think a moment about your feelings, what motivated your decision to never ask a question again, for real, and share that honest feeling, it's not because noone provided you direction, what is the real reason ?

Comment: @KarlStephen the real reason was i couldnt find standard for asking question and sometimes its too much code that no one bothered to look at or sometimes they need more code which after going through stackoverflow instructions to make it as simple as clear i couldnt find another way to achieve it. that is why i got excited to try the new ask wizard and reactivated my account hoping it solves my asking a good question problem or achieve a standard that i can follow

Comment: @KarlStephen and all my suggestion was for if i still fail to ask good question and going back to only searching that would help get good result in my point of view

Comment: @TaaLee That means you lack experience in being on point. Don't worry, most people are like that including me. That also tells asking a question requires a lot of effort : taking the time to observe how other good questions are asked, taking the time to be in the shoes of someone reading your question to find out what he/she may not understand about the issue you're encoutering, and providing the means to help them reproduce the same issue. That also means you must find a way to compress the code to a reasonable length, and last, requires you to read books and sites to have the right keywords.

Comment: @TaaLee Here is my actual example of feeling, on my first question : I was upset because I got so many downvotes and harsh comments, while doing everything I could to meet SO requirements before publishing the question, I wasn't prepared to arm myself with a hard stone mental. While I still believe the way some people welcome new posters is borderline, I learned since SO is not the Q&A resource I thought it was : you can't get here an answer to something too complex (lengthy code and design details), or as simple as a definition, or an evaluation of good/bad design (there are other off topic).

Comment: @KarlStephen i have no problem with any of what you said. very on point. my only problem is why close my question or downvote it without telling me what i have done wrong or what you really need me to do. trust me and i believe most of people here do. if you redirect me to the right path or what exactly you need to see in my question i will have no problem editing it or try to improve. i already do much of searching sometimes days to find a specific solution so i wouldnt mind at all do anything to get answer in less time.. help me to help you is a great concept

Comment: @TaaLee One of the main reasons for the lack of feedback on downvotes is humans are petty and revenge votes are, believe it or not, a thing on [so]. Leaving a comment creates an "impression" that you may have been the user that downvoted the question or answer leaving you open to abuse.

Comment: @user692942 thats why in my opinion vote system should be debated on meta soon. i find abusing it or anyone it hurts community more than it helps. like in my opinion should do something like an open day on meta to discuss the voting system with telling people to participate anyone who really find this network useful will tell the truth about how he feels about it and against or with should make a good case and whatever the result of this should be the undebatable standard that everyone should follow

Comment: @TaaLee You are right, many people just silently downvote, and that's the #1 reason why newcommers leave. BUT, think a moment : you and I are talking here, we have the time (imagine I'm giving you directions to improve your question), but that's not the case of everyone, actually, I won't always have that much time. Imagine someone willing to answer questions, finding one good question among 30 other lacky ones per day. It is expected someone, at some point, will burnout, and downvote in a row without any further direction, and unfortunately, you or the next new contributor get that downvote.

Comment: @TaaLee What I mean is : you can't educate hundreds of thousand of people, it is much efficient to adapt, ignore being slapped, and be better. Changing the downvote system won't solve the problem. A more realistic change would be to inform new members that it takes time to have the right reflexes, and a warm welcome; it is expected the first dozen questions would get negative votes...... a pity, but at some point, I don't want SO to become an MSDN forum where everything gets so hard to find, that side of efficiency explains the strong rules defined here. :)

Comment: @TaaLee What your asking for is a change to human nature, unfortunately, that won't happen. Sometimes swallowing your pride and taking on board direction when it is given is the clear path to success. This site at the end of the day is a resource for "programmers" if you aren't a programmer don't be deterred but also on the flip side don't expect that you won't receive course correction from time to time. If you can't cope with that then I'd say [so] isn't for you.

Comment: @KarlStephen so why not make it like if this question doesn't meet a standard of and i know that most people don't have the time make question based on levels. for example very experienced users have a different queue than experienced users thank moderate experienced user. etc and based on time available people who are giving time to answer questions can choose between which queue and which question not to mention  that all should be treated as a good question good answer or even being visible on search engine

Comment: @TaaLee Most people don't have the time to answer, but many take the time regardless. We all live in a busy world, which I'm afraid is no excuse.

Comment: @KarlStephen i understand a perfect system is hard to achieve but its good to know that everyone on both sided are trying. that why i never gave up trying and id take any chance to improve my skills and improve the quality of my question or my coding

Comment: @user692942 and i appreciate any help and I hope ill be able to serve the community as you "anyone who answer question or take time to help others"do

Comment: @TaaLee The problem with such "experience queue" systems is that there is no automated way to rate content. In order to decide whether a question is fit for experts you need experts to take a look. In order to give feedback how to make questions fit for experts you need experts to take a look. And it won't help people who get their content ratet as "not good enough for experts" to feel less rejected. Ultimately, the downvotes and closevotes that so many people are complaining about *is* the manual version of such a system.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i meant rating based on users opinion .. like instead of downvote add another button that this question doesn't meet the standard of queue very experienced with the score of 5 for example gets transferred to higher queue time and you give the user a warning that his question doesnt meet standards and he will have to wait for more time to get instructions or an answer. And based on everyone time he choose which queue he will be able to help .. and make downvotes for something like off topic .. but still i think its hard .. the good thing is that everyone is trying

Comment: "my asking experience was horrible as I didn’t know how to or what/when should I ask" That's also an important point. People should read much more than ask (books, tutorials, etc.) to get a basic understanding. SO is not good for learning from the ground up. Maybe we should tell that to new askers more often, like as soon as somebody inserts the Python tag recommend some basic online resources about Python. If people then visit these resources they would be more likely to ask a better question afterwards.

Comment: @Trilarion very on point i encourage the idea that people should do enough research of the problem they are having before asking. But from experience when i shifted from marketing to coding in general “2019”everybody recommended to start with python as at this time the demand on python was very high for cybersecurity. I remember i have failed miserably to learn as there was not enough applications “exercises/examples” to make me better understand how it work or used. At this time I decided to start with frontend hoping that when i fully understand it ill be able to go for backend

Comment: @Trilarion ofcourse i was wrong because i had to go for php instead of python and python is no longer my priority. My point is that this should have been an advantage for a site full of resources. Of course not like what is happening right now that everybody just ask whenever they stuck but improving the search engine or at least highlight the basic questions as basic and duplicate every question ask that has a duplicate with the perfect answer well formatted question reference it so by time pass people wouldnt have to ask the same question over and over but just look for desired answer

Comment: @Trilarion one more thing about books and tutorials. I personally prefer tutorials/course. And from personal experience. Some programming languages are evolving so fast to keep up to. For example imagine how many changes have happened in android java in the last 3 years not to mention the stable release for kotline which is similar to swift. Flutter have gained demand. If apple have decided to make major changes to swift or introduce a new language to keep up with being unique and similar to no one. In my opinion that would be a big mess for everyone and specially for new entry

Comment: @Trilarion my point is this fast evolve doesnt space or time to read a book or learn from book you have to keep up with the pace or you are going to get lost or stuck where you no longer needed

Comment: @TaaLee You don't have time to read a book about a subject and are afraid to not keep up with the pace? May be, but then SO isn't a miracle either. I would even say that you can learn faster from books or tutorials than from asking on SO. Asking on SO is only good to fill in the gaps. For all other things it's search and read and search and read. Summary: SO is a terrible teacher.

Comment: @Trilarion im not saying in not reading or buying courses or watching tutorials. Im saying the chances of the book being outdated in the next year in very high. Ive been using stack for over 3 years now, i did ask less than 15 question 4 of them were on codereview, most of them was closed. Very few less than 5 were answered. So i didnt learn for asking. I learned by searching/tutorials/courses/articals about specific matter/and answers on stackoverflow

Comment: @Trilarion i hope you dont get me wrong but i think this site have a great potential something that no other site that have which a combination between different knowledge levels of users. and for the marketing team to be able to attract all of them always provide them with different levels insights to be able to do a good R/D research. i never said SO is a terrible teacher. SO had updated answer more than another sites. sometimes it was the only site that have the updated version of the problem. the problem is its very hard to find which make people ask duplicated question over and over again

Comment: @Trilarion and i believe programming is like physics all version of language is important unless there is consensus that for example that api1 is no longer needed in android which i don't think it will happens soon so old question is as important as updated questions

Answer (score 2):

I had done a fair bit of lurking and answering on SO before asking [my first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68968572/type-is-not-generic-enough-error-when-wrapping-a-function-with-parameters-with-l) (and only) question. I had been around long enough to know to put in the effort at bringing things down to an MRE, make an effort to solve the problem myself (that includes checking for duplicates), and explain my issue clearly.

The end result of my efforts was a very forgettable experience - at the time of this writing, I have received one upvote, and an answer in the comments that was turned into an actual answer that I accepted, and has received one upvote (mine). Neither my question nor the answer to it received much attention, but I didn't really care; I had been stumped by a weird edge case [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_%28programming_language%29)'s type system, and somebody found a suitable workaround within a few hours.

To sum things up, I came prepared, asked a question, and got an answer. No more, no less.

Comment: But that's more or less as it should be. You asked something that nobody has ever asked before (so likely it is very special). You got help. Others with the same problem may get help too in the future. What more could one wish for?

Comment: @Trilarion I am well aware that a timely and correct answer is the best thing I should hope for, but a tiny part of me wishes that my question received more attention, and the upvotes that comes with it, as unlikely as it is for a fairly niche question like this one.

Answer (score 2):

The first two questions I asked were not on this current account.

- It was before 2010 and honestly at the time I was thinking "I'm just going to try this site out". Back then I made throwaway email accounts for sites I wasn't familiar with.
- I don't remember the names of the accounts either unfortunately.

I'm going off memory but, I think my first two questions were:

- A C (or C++?) question, not a particularly good one, my code had Undefined Behavior that I did not notice.
- Some question about Visual Studio, not a very good question again. I think I tried to install it on Windows 7 SP1 but I just had vanilla Windows 7. I guess I assumed that the SP1 requirement was just a suggestion or something and I ignored it.

After that I lurked for several years. SE continued to show up in my search results. For quite a while I would have liked to post comments to questions/answers that were missing information or had mistakes but anonymous users can't do that.

I lurked on meta too, to try and get a feel for what sort of content was appropriate, I eventually found this page: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/261593/1 . I saw that and said "OK, if I post a question, it better be something that I can't even find the slightest trace of an answer anywhere on the internet for."

Several years later, well, I thought I found it: [Why does the behavior of overloaded member functions differ from the behavior of non-member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652707/why-does-the-behavior-of-overloaded-member-functions-differ-from-the-behavior-of)

- It was not super clear to me at the time but overloaded methods use static type resolution, not the dynamic type resolution that calling a method on an object uses.
- There actually was a question that answered this, but it was C#, not VB.NET [Polymorphism and overloading with static methods in C#.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858763/polymorphism-and-overloading-with-static-methods-in-c) It seems silly now, but yes, I could read IL, VB.NET, and assembly, but I had trouble reading C# code at the time.

These days, I can find answers to 99% of things on my own, the remaining 1% is stuff like:

- Esoteric, "10 search results on Google" kind of topics
- Paid libraries that nobody on SO uses
- Extremely localized (specific to one machine, one configuration, etc.)
- Problems that can't be consistently reproduced
- Bugs in libraries/frameworks with no fixes or workarounds
- Quirks in libraries that not even the creator knows
- Ancient Windows secrets probably even Microsoft employees don't know

  - I like ancient Windows secrets though... what if I want to be the Indiana Jones of Windows?
- Hardware quirks that require you to be an Nvidia/Intel/etc. employee
- "Why does X do Y" kind of questions that I find interesting but have mixed results on SE
- Questions that require deep knowledge of complicated subjects (e.g., Linux sound programming)
- Deep questions about less used / unpopular / "uncool" programming languages (like VB.NET), it seems like only languages like C# get thoroughly dissected.

If I run into something like that, I might try books, reading source code (if available), decompiling, "hacking", experiments, finding a project forum, etc., but if it's not something extremely important I just work around it.

Comment: I have no idea how to interpret a downvote on this. -1 for not remembering something from 12 years ago?

Comment: I think the mistake is trying to interpret a downvote

Comment: @KevinB probably, still kinda curious though

Comment: From the tooltip: *"This answer is not useful"*. Implies that someone thinks your answer is unclear, irrelevant, contributes nothing interesting or unique to the discussion, and/or thinks it is wrong. Kinda goes for all downvotes on all answers.

Comment: @CodyGray Right. Unclear: with no comment I have no idea what might be unclear. Irrelevant/wrong/not unique: this is a direct answer to the question posed, asking for a unique experience, and I was there. Not interesting: not sure what else somebody would expect after clicking on a question like this, should I add some fireworks gifs or something to make it more interesting? Less charitably, I can guess that maybe it's "-1 because this experience isn't mine / isn't what I hoped it would be" which... I guess is valid, but a little weird? Why come here other than to read other experiences?

Answer (score 2):

My first question I was asking for help generating a random number within a range with a weighted distribution.

It was closed because it was deemed a duplicate of a question where there was a random selection from a weighted list of objects.

There was no recourse here for me to clarify that the solution deemed a duplicate would require me to populate a list with hundreds of constructed objects each with an individual weight when really I just want a number between 1 and 100 with a greater likelihood around 30.
The question was ultimately closed and I was penalized for asking what I still think was a perfectly valid question.

Ultimately there are a few benefits I think could be done.

1. I think there should be better flow in these questions so that if they are duplicates there is an avenue for the question asker to fix them up to be more appropriate or to clarify points as to why other posts do not solve the problem.
2. Punishment sucks. It makes people feel shitty to have a question shot down **and** points deducted.
3. Point requirements are needed to properly participate in SO. Largely I made an account because I wanted to upvote comments that were helping me on those issues I have spent hours on. But also commenting to add more detail on workarounds and such were also valuable. Entry requirements to this should not be so difficult.

Comment: Out of interest, are you aware that you can edit your question to make it clear the duplicate does not apply? Duplicates can be reopened, but it seems this is not communicated clearly enough.

Comment: I see an edit, but then what it says when your question is closed is telling me to ask a whole new question "Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one." . If I were to edit i guess its just not clear how I am supposed to address that it is not a duplicate, can other users see that it has votes marking it as a duplicate? or do I need to explain the whole situation at the end of my post with a link to the supposed duplicate?

Comment: Thanks for explaining how the information comes across. Indeed I can understand how it does not help you take the actions needed.

Comment: FWIW, yes, people who can vote to reopen do see that it was closed as a duplicate and by whom. Often enough it is sufficient to reformat a question so as to make the differences more prominent or removing similarities, though for edge cases it can be necessary to directly reference the "duplicate" and point out what is the difference.

Comment: Ah ok I will keep that in mind if it happens again thanks.

Comment: "I still think was a perfectly valid question" And it may well be. Mistakes happen. We used to have a five votes requirement for question closure but reduced it to be more efficient in closing stuff that really should be closed but at the cost of a larger error rate. Question that are valid can be closed by mistake. Please do not take it personally. It can just happen.

Answer (score 1):

I got thousands of comments stating my question was a duplicate (it actually was).

Comment: Thousands? Are you sure you're not a few orders of magnitude off? :D Either way, were those comments helpful? How did you experience them?

Comment: It was just 3 btw

Comment: Small margin of error :-)

Comment: If a couple thousand means 5000 then I had a 166,567% relative error.

Comment: Three orders of magnitude is nothing in astronomy. Wasn't there some prediction of [string theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) that was more than 100 orders of magnitude off?

Comment: Ok why are we talking about quantum physics

Comment: @Cerbrus Presumably it was "first-time asker experienced" as thousands.

Comment: Small margin, in the log-scale.

Answer (score 1):

It was fairly early on in the Android days, and I asked what hardware I should buy to test out and develop with the novel USB host stack on Android with my proprietary devices.

It was closed because it'd be an opinion-based question. This was before [Reddit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit) was a big thing and I really didn't know where else to ask. I actually got a fair amount of pity upvotes (and it stayed undeleted up until a few months ago), but I was frustrated that it was closed without really any pointers to where I could ask.

These days, there are plenty of communities I can ask about stuff like this.

Comment: What are some of those communities?

Answer (score 1):

I started my question journey in 2014. While not new to SO (I answered a couple of questions before), it was still a bit nerve wrecking to post a question for the first time. I had learned enough about SO to know that the question better be good.

If I remember correctly, the question was closed (I don't remember the close reason). I looked it over, did not agree with the closure and asked for it to be reopened. If memory serves right, it was reopened by a mod and not the reopen queue.

So despite having some SO experience, not a good experience. I remember feeling put off by the fact that the question was closed with an (from my point of view) invalid reasoning. Today, I know/can guess that the people that closed the question likely did not have knowledge in the question's tags and mistook it for sand.

Maybe that information (people with no knowledge of the tags will evaluate the question) should be added in some form to the Staging Ground so new contributors can take it into account?

I guess the biggest eye opener was to see the mechanisms of SO in practical action instead of reading about them in theory. Maybe the help could do a bit more show instead of tell or add some videos illustrating examples of closed/downvoted questions and what to do about them? The question wizard might also benefit from some examples of bad questions with explanation why they are bad and how they could be improved.

Comment: Did this occur with a different account than the one you are using now? Because your account has never had any questions closed (and you have no deleted questions).

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. Details are hazy by now, but I thought it was this account, since I never had any other (or at least can't remember others).

Answer (score 1):

My [first Question experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271759/how-do-i-programmatically-add-a-folder-to-the-users-favorites-in-windows-explo) was good, it got upvoted a few years later. **The reason is because** **I had read many questions before, checked out how the site worked and had seen people getting roasted for:**

- not including code,
- errors as images,
- no actual question,
- poor format/grammar,
- in a foreign language,
- all to common Plz Show Mez Teh Codez and do my job/homework/assignment,
- or the famous one line "how do I make an chat xyz" tagging 5 different languages.

A tour showing examples of questions getting roasted in the above ways would be the next step IMHO *before* engaging a staging ground. This maps back to my comment here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381759/495455 in the thread [The Ask Question Wizard is Live!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live/381773)

ps Disappointing to see [User:slakx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240733/) the first person to help me is no longer contributing.

I wanted to also quickly touch on answering for newbies. The beginning of my answer history isn't great and you might wonder why I didn't give up. It was so hard to even get 50pts rep to comment! I was awarded an Unsung Hero due to the lack of recognition, that's how high the bar was raised! If I didn't have prior experience working in 3rd/4th tier "coding & database" support I would have given up. So if I see a newbie provide a half decent answer, I upvote them to help get them to the 50rep privilege point.

Comment: Upvoting the "user" is generally frowned upon, because this implies that downvoting is also towards the "user".

Comment: @StephenRauch are you replying to the right answer? We are talking about people here, I didn't once use the word user. The problem is that for almost 15 yrs newbies (and old schoolers like stackx, Jon Galloway, etc) have had bad experiences. I'm suggesting a few examples to accompany the Question Wizard.

Comment: *I upvote them to help* <-

Comment: This is the second time you've tried to twist my words. `So if I see a newbie provide a half decent answer, I upvote them to help get them to the 50rep privilege point.` I clearly say upvote them because it was half decent. You can check out my 11yrs of voting history, 80% up, 20% down, 50/50 on Q vs A's. It's disenchanting for you to insinuate that upvoting is bad (or is someway unhelpful) or that I do it discriminatorily. End of conversation.

Comment: *End of Conversation*.  Didn't view this is as much of a conversation, but sorry I twisted your use of the word *them* to mean "user".  I guess the pronoun "they" referred to "half decent answer".

Comment: Could you please edit to clarify what the "them" in "I upvote *them* to help" to help means? Because I read it the same as @StephenRauch. When upvoting the answer, I would have expected "I upvote *it* to help".

Comment: Ahem, folks, I think we got a little bit too hang up on the wording - it's pretty clear the OP did not mean the user (although the usage of "them" is, indeed, a bit unorthodox, so I see how it could be misread)

Comment: I mean, it was pretty clear the upvote is targeted on the post, but it's being done *to* give the user rep as stated in the answer, so both are correct, and one could certainly argue that's clearly a case of upvoting for reasons other than quality/usefulness. I read it as, you would use the user's (new user) standing to help you decide to upvote a post that was at minimum decent.

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever asked a couple of questions, although I have been an active user of SO for multiple years. I found it a bit tricky to ask the first question in a way that I thought the community would like, as I have experienced that people can be a bit harsh in their critique of inexperienced users. Based on my own experience, it can be a bit hard to decide to post the first question, as I was afraid of being shut down for either asking a stupid question, asking it in the wrong way, or being told that I should have done more research myself before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the first question of most people is not a specific technical detail. On the contrary, they often need a technical implementation idea and specific executable code, but these questions are often asked by people for technical details.

They are newcomers, and if they can clearly know the technical terms corresponding to the technical problems they encounter, why don't they google it?

Even if they have made it very clear that these posts are finally closed, I think it can be replaced by setting up a【newcomer section】for these low-quality, but helpful posts for newcomers.

Comment: Consider the entire rest of the Web as the "newcomer section", containing "low-quality but helpful posts". That is not what Stack Overflow intends to be, nor is there any lack of places containing low-quality but possibly useful content.

Comment: @CodyGray But there is a point here. People with better search skills will ask less. The ones that remain and do ask will probably be biased towards not being able to search that well. Or saying it another way: the average asker may even have below than average skills because of a selection bias.

Comment: Re *"setting up a【newcomer section】for these low-quality, but helpful posts for newcomers."*: No, they ought to be condensed into (real) [FAQs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAQ). A mechanism for it is lacking; the closest is/was *some* tag wikis, like the [one for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) (e.g. sections *"New to C++?"* and *"Stack Overflow's C++ FAQ"*) [and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) (now destroyed). (The length limitation of tag wikis is also sometimes a real problem (32,000 characters?).)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Can you explain what you mean by "now destroyed" in reference to the PHP tag wiki? The length limit is 30k characters, as far as I recall. So, yeah, that's a bit of a limitation if you're trying to create a consolidated FAQ. But I oppose that strategy. On a Q&A site, the FAQs should be... wait for it... asked as questions.

Answer (score 0):

I asked my first question in 2012.

By this time, SO had already gained a reputation for being unfriendly to new users.  I took the time to research other questions and search elsewhere and write what I thought was a good question.  It was moderately successful -- no downvotes, a couple upvotes, and an amusing comment.

I was probably the exception as a new asker -- one who did what the community hopes a new asker would do.  And I was frightened into doing it by an unfriendly community.  Did I care about contributing to an encyclopedic Q&A?  No. I just wanted my question answered.

I've still asked very few questions.  22 in over 10 years.   Why?  Because I know that this community has such high ideals for questions that it doesn't tolerate stupidity.  As a programmer, I often make mistakes and ask stupid questions.  But not here.

Comment: I really won't say it's stupidity. For most bad questions, it's either plain bad communication, where I really have no idea what might constitute an answer, or absence of effort, e.g. homework dumps.

Answer (score 0):

I admit did not put a ton of research effort into my first question: [How can I create a directory in C in a cross platform manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67962497/16217248) But at least I made the question clear understandable enough be, unsurprisingly, marked as a duplicate of another question, rather than as unclear or not about programming. At the time my thoughts were probably like *'At least I the answer (or lackthereof because in my particular question the answer is 'you cannot'), maybe I should put more effort into searching for similar questions before posting.'* Upon reflection I made mistakes such as asking for the 'best' way, now knowing that 'best way' questions can be closed as opinion-based.

Many of my next questions were extremely niche questions (particularly ones associated with developing MacOS apps in unconventional ways) that I was sure would not be closed as a duplicate. But being niche comes with being generally low-activity questions.

Answer (score -7):

Researched the topic before asking the question, read several other questions on the same problem, none of them helped, despite me following the answers, so I asked my own question, citing the preceding questions and my own research.

About 10 people said my question is a duplicate and gave a link to the very same questions I cited in my own question, explaining how they did not apply to my case.

3 more were unsatisfied how my question wasn't pretty enough, therefore they weren't going to answer it.

~3 posted answers that were just copy-paste of some standard response template (that they did not understand) for my general problem.

All in all approximately 16 people were commenting on my question without reading it, at all.

Then 1 lone soul answered my question and that fixed my problem.

So, just your basic, everyday experience on SO.

Comment: So... you think this kind of hostility and abuse (calling users "illiterate") is OK, but you were annoyed by the lack of thoroughness of volunteers? Why, exactly, do we owe you so much when you don't even treat us with respect?

Comment: @CodyGray, because I started treating you disrespectfully only after my experiences on SO.

Comment: "So, just your basic, everyday experience on SO." That's a rather fitting description for the casual abuse of over a dozen people. As far as I can tell, none of your (undeleted) question are anywhere near this badly received. Why paint such a bleak picture?

Comment: As with a couple of the other users posting answers here, the account used to post has no questions (deleted or undeleted) that match the descriptions given. The only one of Tessaract's questions that have *ever* been closed is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70501171), which is the third most-recent question they've asked, certainly not one of the early ones. So... I don't know what is happening. Either users are operating multiple accounts, or they are misremembering what happened. (cc @MisterMiyagi)

Comment: @CodyGray, yes, the first question I've asked was over 9 years ago, if I remember correctly, and I've lost that account to time. If it was only me it would seem possible to misremember what happened, but seeing other people having similar experiences I'd say we are remembering pretty well. Also, that wasn't an isolated incident, hence the "So, just your basic, everyday experience on SO.". Only after experiencing so much negativity did I start to tailor my questions to really picky people, which demotivates me to ask questions, at all. Hence not a lot of questions on this account.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, please see my response to Cody Gray.

Comment: "About 10 people said my question is a duplicate" What a waste of valuable time. 2-3 would probably have been enough to establish the fact with sufficient accuracy. Really so much energy is wasted while trying to curate the content.

Comment: @Tessaract "but seeing other people having similar experiences I'd say we are remembering pretty well" Sorry, I am not convinced by this. The internet is full of echo chambers for SO bashing and hyperboles. Even SO itself is no exemption – when cleaning up my curation-following list I'm regularly surprised myself that most question interactions *aren't* as bad as both sides on Meta would make it seem. Despite the "bad" experience you asked 30 Qs in 11 months – I'm at less than 10 Qs in 9 years – so even the assertion that you are demotivated to ask needs to be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: Re *"my question wasn't pretty enough"*: In what way? Can you elaborate? They can't possibly literally have said that.

Answer (score -11):

> What was your experience like when you asked your first question on Stack Overflow or on the Stack Exchange network?

That's very easy to answer. It felt almost exactly like how answering this question feels. I'm an experienced software engineer, not even the dumbest one around (excuse my arrogance) there is a good discussion to have, and I genuinely feel I can contribute to it, and... despite all of this I have absolutely no idea if I will be downvoted into oblivion for:

- my tone being too informal
- breaking yet another rule I was not aware of
- posting supposedly irrelevant anecdotes
- not taking the discussion seriously enough
- someone being on a downvote spree (yes, this happens)
- someone methodically downvoting my questions (even old ones) because
  I got into an argument with them (or more likely one of their friends)
  on an unrelated stackexchange site

I think the elephant in the room is this:

https://abstrusegoose.com/590

As it had been explicitly pointed out in the past, with the exact same comic strip, but it was dismissed as 'anecdotal' and as 'just a silly webcomic'.

Let me state it verbally then: gamification, on what idea this whole site is based on, only works until someone comes up with the genius idea that "I can spend the next 30 minutes improving this question and get +25 reputation tops, or... downvoting a hundred questions, making questionable punctuation edits in two dozen other ones, and closing literally any question that involves a tradeoff as 'opinion based'".

It was a good idea in the beginning but - in gaming terms - the meta has shifted. In the current meta for the vast majority of users, it is not a viable reputation- and trophyfarming strategy to spend time on providing genuine help to question askers and then write detailed well thought-out answers, when they can simply mass-edit their way into the ranks of the top half million users, with 1000+ reputation and additional privileges to prevent those pesky 'newbs' from climbing the ranks through asking and answering.

I am not saying any foul play is involved, but the current system does motivate the described behavior, and the whole point of gamification is that such motivators do work, even if just subconsciously.

Ask literally anyone outside of this 'community' they will tell you the same.

By the way, what's the reason again for this being posted here instead of reddit, hackernews, twitter, facebook, etc? Obviously the answers here will be extremely biased.

Comment: Aaand... just as expected I got my first downvote in 30 seconds for an answer I spent 30 minutes on. Totally worth my time, thanks for the experience.

Comment: A downvote on a Meta site such as this one typically means that someone disagrees with you. Votes are not meant as a way of compensating you for your time; they're meant to signal community agreement regarding the content, presentation, usefulness, relevance, etc. of a particular post.

Comment: Just in the first few paragraphs of this answer, you off-handedly use a turn of phrase that my experience tells me may be indicative of your negative experience using this site: "[I feel] there is a good discussion to have…". Probably! Likely, even! But Stack Overflow doesn't *do* discussions; we actively discourage them (at least on the main site; Meta is a bit different). So, if you're here trying to have a discussion, you're likely to experience a great deal of friction, both from the site tooling and also from other members, who are trying to quell discussions in favor of strict Q&A.

Comment: Regarding the webcomic, it's obviously hyperbolic (we don't close questions for being stupid), but that's the nature of comics. Otherwise, I think it's quite apt. This is meant as a Q&A site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Often times, the answer to a question asked by a professional (or someone aiming to do professional-quality work) *is* going to be... use the existing tools. And that's OK! It's the answer I'm looking for 99% of the time. It isn't the *only* answer that SO permits to be posted—reinventing the wheel is OK. But it's rarely the correct solution for our audience.

Comment: "Votes are not meant as a way of compensating you for your time; they're meant to signal community agreement". Have fun in the echochamber then.

Comment: Also, unlike in the cartoon, we do not close or downvote **users**, we close or downvote **posts**. If the same user came back later and asked an on-topic, well-researched (meaning it was not asked before), well-written, high-quality question, it would be upvoted and not closed. By the way, no one gets rep for closing questions, and only new users get rep for successfully suggesting edits, so I'm not sure what that whole thing is about. Much more likely is a user answering several hundred duplicate questions, with the attendant upvotes those answers receive, if one wants to rep-farm.

Comment: Allowing people to express opinions doesn't make it an echo chamber. It would be an echo chamber if moderators (or anyone else, really) systematically *deleted* posts that they disagree with, but they don't, and I'm especially sensitive to anything that might even remotely border on that type of censorship. Being able to express unpopular opinions is one of the key features of Meta Stack Overflow. So is, of course, others being able to inform you without confrontation that your opinions are unpopular. This is why the voting system is important.

Comment: I mean... if you assume bad faith _everything_ comes off as bad faith.

Comment: I don't quite follow the point on gamification, perhaps you can clarify it a bit? Downvoting, editing and closing gets me *no reputation at all* – in fact one of them *costs* reputation. Curating even a little has left me far behind the people who answer questions no matter what (I'll leave the "detailed well thought-out" up for debate) in terms of the site's gamification. So perhaps you could explain a bit better how gamification does "motivate the described behavior"?

Comment: _"Ask literally anyone outside of this 'community' they will tell you the same."_ That's a blatant example of a selection bias. The people who tried to ask a question and failed will tend to link Stack Overflow to a negative aura, and report it as such. On the other hand, most mentions of Stack Overflow in social media pose the site as a (very) useful source of knowledge.

Comment: _"By the way, what's the reason again for this being posted here instead of reddit, hackernews, twitter, facebook, etc? Obviously the answers here will be extremely biased."_ Those venues are just as prone to biases, and are not known to foster constructive discussion. It is only natural for the company to prefer their own system designed to discuss about Stack Overflow itself.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi 100% this! It gets disheartening but it's the difference between caring for the quality of the content and answering questions for imaginary internet points.  It's clear the OP doesn't realise that curation is more likely to hurt a curators rep then increase it.

Comment: @szmate1618 I want you know that your answer is appreciated because it does a great job summarizing the very obvious problems with the site, and is a perfect honey trap for comments demonstrating exactly what you explained.

Comment: @Appleguysnake The comments only describe that there are many reasons for downvoting which are considered reasonable. This is the only part which goes more in line with the answer's concerns. Everything else in the answer, primarily the argument alleging that gamification is the root of the problem in curation, was only counterargued constructively.

Answer (score -16):

My first experience asking a question on Stack Overflow was fine.  Which is why I am still here, many years later.

Things are different nowadays.  Often, the first questioner's experience is horrible.  The site is crawling with users who delight in picking problems and voting to close any question that is not perfect, often within minutes.

I suggest that no question should be closed for a time, say four hours, after being first asked.  This would allow time for well intentioned people to drop by and help out the inexperienced askers.

Comment: Using this space to make suggestions on how to make things better, is only going to result in people voting on this answer in agreement/disagreement with the suggestion

Comment: Sounds good to me.  Anyway, I was answering the question posed in the OP - but I don't like to complain without offering a solution.

Comment: Is the implication of the last sentence intentional? That people who vote are not well intended?

Comment: I get the impression you may misunderstand the purpose of closing questions. In fact, we close questions precisely to give well-intentioned people the opportunity to drop by and help out the inexperienced askers. While the question is closed, answers are blocked, so the question can be freely discussed, edited, reformulated, or even completely rewritten (either by the original poster or by anyone else), without concern of invalidating existing answers. Once the question has been polished into shape (i.e., to meet Stack Overflow's specific requirements), then it can be re-opened and answered.

Comment: @CodyGray But there are a lot of questions answered before they can get closed and ravenspoint wants to have this chance even increased. With your model of the life cycle that shouldn't happen at all because closed questions are unanswerable by definition and by rules. Don't want to disagree with anyone here, just pointing out the differences in the approaches.

Comment: Yes, I think closure should happen earlier and more frequently, @Trilarion; thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately, the site has gotten large enough that it doesn't scale without an excessive amount of effort. I appreciate the work that everyone puts in to reviewing questions.

Comment: In the same tone, but opposite perspective, the site is crawling with lazy/spam users who ask low-quality/duplicate questions, and don't care to research or help others.