# Can't post question because of error: "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length."

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, error-message

When I try to post a question on Stack Overflow, I get the following error message:

> Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

[image]

Nevertheless, I see no "Comments" area to add a comment. Is this a bug?

Comment: Wild guess: some changes were pushed to production too early. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar We're pushing a fix shortly. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: I am also facing same problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. The issue has now been resolved in  Production.

This issue came about as we're working behind the scenes on [the recently-announced Staging Ground project.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416428/introducing-the-staging-ground-an-attempt-at-improving-the-first-time-asker-exp) The new Ask Wizard is our "foot-in-the-door" for the project and a missed configuration was attempting to validate a field that isn't active yet.

Comment: Well it's not really behind the scenes when it's leaking to the front, but yeah, thanks for fixing it.