# Question Quality Control

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, question-quality, ask-question-wizard

NUMEROUS Python questions are of extremely poor quality. It's a pandemic of barely decipherable posts. One of the driving factors are users that have some arbitrary file format that they want to perform formatting on, and, instead of posting the file or some workable part of it, they try to explain their file format. They seem to be struggling to ask a proper question. Explaining the arbitrary file format is not making things better.

My suggestion is to ask them a simple question before they post. "Does this question entail manipulating a local file?" or something else along those lines. If the answer is "yes", the user literally cannot post their question until some workable portion of that data is included. Maybe you could even give them an upload prompt or something and the file(s) could be addressed like an attachment to the post.

I realize that this could potentially be used for abuse. Something has to be done, though. Posts are getting closed left and right and one big part of it is the user's negligence in simply supplying the file they are working with. If you take out their need to explain the file, presumably the question would be better.

Comment: Not an exact dupe, but regarding (part of) your suggestion, supporting attaching files [hasn't been received well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421696/how-can-i-attach-code-files-to-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers). Regardless, yes, improving question quality is important, though I don't personally agree with attach-able files as the solution

Comment: Welcome to the club, I guess. Most questions in popular tags about technologies with a very low entry bar (think JS, et al) are utter and complete garbage. Ain't much we can do about that, though. I don't think your idea can be done at scale, unfortunately - there are just too many use cases to account for (and that's just given the Python tag family alone). Generally speaking, though, we've been asking SE for improvements on that front for years with little to no avail, I am afraid to say.

Comment: Well, that's my best attempt to try and fix the problem. I new before I even posted it that it wouldn't be accepted "as-is", but I was hopeful that it maybe had some weight in getting some form of solution in the works.

Comment: Are these question on-topic anyway? Sounds to me like questions that needs more focus. Could you make an example of an on-topic question ?

Comment: Are you downvoting all of them? Voting to close all of them too?

Comment: @RobertLongson ~ I only vote to close posts that are virtually undecipherable or show absolutely no effort. Often I will actually tackle their problem even if it is vague and poorly worded.

Comment: Eh, I mean, in a better world we could probably have automated contextual prompts for askers forcing them to take steps to fix their questions *before* posting them. Unfortunately, that's highly unlikely to happen any time soon. There are initiatives like [the Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416428/11407695) with somewhat similar goals, @OneMadGypsy, but I sincerely doubt they'll be a success given how SE chose to approach them.

Comment: @Thingamabobs ~ I feel like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74592944/update-character-position-in-fixed-width-file) is a good example.

Comment: *Often I will actually tackle their problem even if it is vague and poorly worded* -> You're actually encouraging the bad behaviour you're talking about. Maybe stop answering bad questions?

Comment: @Lino ~ I'm not arguing with you, but I highly doubt I'm keeping the "poor questions" community alive at stack. I could leave forever and there will still be zillions of them. However, if I stopped answering poor questions, I'd basically just have to stop answering questions. Any of them. They are primarily poor.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy OP does not ask a specific question. In fact they didn't even decide what data structure to use. This either leads to opinion based answers or open end questions. I feel like it is not a question like `How do I flatten the list with content X?`, you would need to write them the entire code and explain it to them. Since this question is more of an order than a question I would tell them that [so] is not a code writing service and they should come back with a specific problem. A question that would be also valuable for future visitors and not a code written for them specifically.

Comment: @Thingamabobs ~ I understand that. However I came here to answer questions. If I followed that stack rule to the T I would basically be forced to leave stack because there wouldn't be much left to answer.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Can relate to it, I barley find questions to answer. I do also have some *floating boundaries* for it and answer some of these "not really good" questions but rather when I see there is a honest attempt and a desperate need for guidance, due to a confusing matter. But they all (should) have a central point that needs to be cleaned up in their minds.

Comment: I don't even understand what there is to downvote. I clearly stated the issues I am witnessing and offered some form of a solution. Do my downvoters hate the truth or something?

Comment: They were already told on composition to give an [mre]. Moreover if a question involves a file format, they indeed should be trying to describe it. But also giving the rest of a [mre]. And as cut & paste & runnable text in the post, including input/initialization--not somewhere else. "I only vote to close posts that are virtually undecipherable or show absolutely no effort. Often I will actually tackle their problem even if it is vague and poorly worded." Then you are rewarding the posting of bad questions.

Comment: @philipxy ~ I understand. I wont do it anymore. I'm given no choice but to find somewhere else to apply my skills. I'm not new to any of this. I know what I'm saying is a reality. To follow stack rules to a T doesn't leave much programming to do for the `python` topic. I just want to solve code problems in a way that upgrades the askers education. That's it. That's what I came here to do. You're telling a mechanic to pump gas for you and get over it. No.

Comment: But a closed question is only closed until improved & opened. You can still comment the things that you wished the system would. Moreover because AI is still insufficient, there has to be some human review for minimal quality & whether to flag (for closure or other rejection) is that review, it is unavoidable. It is not clear what exactly you are saying is a problem. Too much review effort needed? Closure of questions that are OK? Your comment but not your question talks about wanting more to answer. But blocking bad questions that don't get improved doesn't fix that.

Comment: "Against turbidity the mods themselves contend in vain."

Comment: @philipxy ~ My original question got watered down by somehow the focus being turned to the style of my participation. It's like calling the cops cause you got robbed and they want to see your ID. Honestly, I wish I would have never started this thread. It's clear that nothing is going to be improved because of it. It's also clear that stack isn't a place to help people. It's a place to waste life judging questions instead of solving them. My suggestion was an attempt at providing a tool that helps improve the quality of questions. Personally, I'll answer any question you have, cause I can.

Comment: Regarding downvotes: despite your tagging this as a [discussion], it reads like a feature request to add a specific feature.  In that case, downvotes would tend to mean "I don't think adding that feature is a good idea."  See [Voting is different on meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @RyanM ~ Thank you, for the information, but starting from the moment I wake up tomorrow I am leaving stack. I'm just looking for one more goodbye question to answer tonight, and I'm done. Apparently I already have a CodeProject account and a little over 600 points. I don't remember ever doing that, but I'm going to go audit their system and see if it's a better fit for me. If I manage to work my way through the alternatives without satisfaction, I will build my own. If you ever see a code answer site named "NineTail", know that I was frustrated, built it (by myself), and hope you like it.

Comment: I don't understand your frustration. Ultimately, poor-quality questions that can't be fully answered shouldn't be answered, because an answer would be incomplete. Your profile shows that you have only edited 34 posts, cast 240 downvotes, and raised 19 helpful flags. The moderation privileges that you've earned are supposed to be used to improve the site, so I suggest using them more liberally. If you see a question that can't be answered, VTC and downvote it. If you really want to try to answer a bad question, you can always leave a comment pointing the user in the right direction.

Comment: @MichaelM ~ I don't know how to make y'all understand that I don't want to be a moderator. I view it as a complete waste of my time. What about poor quality questions that CAN be answered? Look, I answer questions successfully that I can't even test, and don't even know anything about. It's called the docs. I'm very good at reading them. I have at least 2 answers here that qualify my assertion. I have way more than 2 on raspberrypi.org. I pick up languages like they're comic books. Next week I start with Rust. My 28th language! I am a programmer, not a moderator.

Comment: @MichaelM ~ "If you really want to try to answer a bad question, you can always leave a comment pointing the user in the right direction.". We're just not on the same page. I'm not trying to be lmgtfy.com. I solve code problems. You know what really brought me here? I needed to learn tkinter, but instead of reading docs I came here and answered every last tkinter question I encountered. Yes, I am saying I answered questions from a point of knowing nothing. I am positive that I've taken many starters here and gave their understanding an immediate upgrade. That's my purpose in life.

Comment: Rage quitting? Oh no, not again. I think [Code Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Project) has been practically dead for a long time. It hardly ever comes up in search results.

Comment: @PeterMortensen ~ What are you talking about? Foremost there is no rage, and secondly there is no "again". There has to be a first time for an "again". Your comment is so weird I don't even know why I'm responding to it.

Comment: What do you mean there is no rage? You have been a member for more than 4 years, have about 3,000 reputation points and 300 answers, post a meta post, and the same day declare *"I am leaving stack."*, giving up. "Again" refers to the same pattern we see here at meta, people posting something here (a sort of a final post) instead of leaving quietly. Yes, it ***is*** very discouraging with meta downvotes, but expectations must be set very low. After all, Eternal September has been ongoing for 12 years now here, and there is nothing that can stop it, short of somehow start it all over again.

Comment: @PeterMortensen ~ You completely misunderstand. I don't care about a bunch of downvotes that have nothing to do with my stack points. I can't even figure out what effect that has. It means nothing to me. I'm being told that my style of participation is promoting garbage posts. I know for a fact that there isn't much of anything left once you eliminate the poor posts. I'm then being told to be a moderator and waste my time clicking a chevron all day. If there are slim to no questions to answers then what is there for me to do here?

Comment: @PeterMortensen ~ I think I've made it very clear that I have one agenda ~ help other programmers with their code, and that is literally it! I'm adding this because my last post had an open ended question that would allow you to come and suggest all the things I am definitely not going to do.

Comment: @PeterMotensen ~ To be clear this was never meant to be a final post. It was meant to be a suggestion. Trust me, I highly regret it. This place has been an outlet for me to share 40 years of programming experience with the next generation of programmers. I'm not "giving up" or "rage quitting", my purpose is diminished by having severely less options in which to apply it. In a way I'm not even really leaving. There's just nothing to do. Maybe I'll be back in 2 weeks when I learn Rust and see what that tag has to offer. And I have almost 4000 points.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like this is a well-covered circumstance in which, if the question is explicitly *missing* details that are required for some layperson to answer the question, it should be closed as off-topic.

If the question is unclear, then it should be downvoted.

While those two things are distinct and orthogonal actions, they can coincide with one another nicely if need be.

Now to [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74592944/update-character-position-in-fixed-width-file) - these days I abstain from voting on questions if they show up in Meta first since I don't want to be seen as improper, but if I had stumbled upon this question I'd vote to close it *anyway*.  All the OP has is a file format and they need to parse data out of it, but they've made no real attempt at showing what their issue is or where they're stuck at with their own code.  Being stuck *period* isn't the best use of the site, so I'd close that as a variant of "too broad".

Comment: I understand. The only problem is, the greatest majority of questions fall in that category. If we really followed that guideline to the T you could basically say that SO doesn't support python questions, because too many users don't know how to ask one. I'm working with what I have. I came here to answer questions, not be a free moderator. I accept to do both, but you have to have BOTH to do both.

Comment: Pick your battles wisely then @OneMadGypsy.  Either you're going to answer questions and acknowledge that the askers aren't exactly following protocol, or you're going to dogmatically downvote/close vote every question that isn't following protocol, and never answer questions.  There's a balance in-between that's not *that* hard to strike, and it starts with not jumping so quickly to hyperbole.  There are plenty of Python questions that are answerable even to our exacting standards.

Comment: I'm not jumping to anything. Yesterday I was on here for almost 14 hours and I watched question after question drop like flies. I didn't count them, but I promise you it wasn't negligible. I feel like I have already struck some form of the balance you speak of. I didn't elicit my suggestion to complain about questions. I elicited my suggestion in the hopes of improving the questions so they don't get downvoted or closed.

Comment: Eh...don't hold such an attachment to whether or not a question gets downvoted or closed, @OneMadGypsy.  If they're bad, they're bad and will be rated as such.  If they're good, they're good and will be rated as such.  I do take umbrage to your remark of not jumping to anything, since the second paragraph-ish of this question leads with "numerous" in all caps, and implies that there is a "pandemic of barely decipherable posts".  Given that it's 2022 and we know what pandemics are by now, there's no way you could pass that off as *not* jumping to hyperbole.

Comment: Or you can join the dark side, @OneMadGypsy :) Most of us here went through the existential realization the vast majority of questions on main are, frankly speaking, trash, and decided to do something about it. Pick your poison: closure, editing, tag management, flagging, automation, etc

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine ~ I appreciate the suggestions, but I'm a programmer. I've been programming since the trs-80 was invented. I was 6. I write code and I solve code problems. That's my thing. I'd be more inclined to go to some other code site if you can recommend one that would be a fit for me.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine that is a movement I do understand but it does not work well because, they often judge on matter where they simply do not know enough.

Comment: Well, you can always write bots, userscripts, and all sorts of automation. We have a strong culture (in all sorts of languages to go for) for that here, @OneMadGypsy.  That's what I mostly do these days on SO anyways. Frankly, it's much more enjoyable than solving the same boring problems over and over or trying to find a worthy candidate in the pile of garbage (which ain't easy as I am sure you know).

Comment: Even though I don't have a question, you put effort into your answer, so I accepted it. Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine ~ "Well, you can always write bots, userscripts, and all sorts of automation" ~ How do I do that here? Point me to a page.

Comment: Sure, @OneMadGypsy - one of the most prominent orgs for bots is [SOBotics](https://sobotics.org/), they can hook you up if you are interested. There's [Userscripters](https://github.com/userscripters/) [I am one of the founders - apologies for any messiness there], there's also [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/) - folks that fight spam and abuse.