# Training Mode: A Guided Approach for New Members in Asking Quality Questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

What do you guys think about adding a feature to Stack Overflow where new members with one reputation may have fake accounts to ask fake questions? Stack Overflow would use AI to teach these new members that their questions should not be "opinion-based", "too broad", "unrelated to programming languages", or inform them that their questions must be asked on "webmaster", "Ask Different", or "Server Fault" using the fake account created by all newly members.

The reason for this feature is that some new members find it difficult to determine which questions are acceptable for Stack Overflow and which ones are not, even with the help of this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

The idea for this feature comes from a financial app that I came across yesterday. It is an investment app that allows new members to learn how to invest their money in different stock markets using fake accounts with a large amount of fake money, that enable them to use that money to invest, just to learn how the market works.

The fake questions that I'm talking about wouldn't be displayed on general question in Stack Overflow. They should be posted somewhere else, and only the author of that question would be able to see it.

Comment: I'm wondering if this proposal is poorly timed intentionally or not right now. :/

Comment: Pet-Peeve: Using `code markdown` for non-code.

Comment: @ThomA you're welcome :D

Comment: Why would the community want a feature that supports asking fake questions? How about we just not answer questions from users who can’t accept questions seeking our opinions isn’t allowed?

Comment: @SecurityHound said community is also not too unhappy with fake answers. We must allow the possibility that we, the old farts who actually write code, are outnumbered.

Comment: I don't think (m)any of us have a "problem" with people consuming (bad, wrong, highly inaccurate) AI generated answers if that's what the individual wants, @Gimby , just that we don't want that *here* on [so]; if people want to do that then they could just, I don't know, talk to ChatGPT directly.

Comment: @SecurityHound the fake questions that I'm talking about wouldn't display on stack overflow, it should be posted on somewhere else, only the author of that question can be able to see it.

Answer (score 17):

Aside from the fact that there's no automated way to actually provide any feedback to these new questions, what you're describing is basically the [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416428/introducing-the-staging-ground-an-attempt-at-improving-the-first-time-asker-exp).

There, new users' questions are vetted by experienced users, before being passed through to SO proper.

Comment: The bad questions might be posted if the moderator isn't available. How technically good is staging ground?

Comment: I can't answer that. Better than nonexistent AI solutions, at least.

Comment: There could be (real-time) automated voting (upvote, downvote, neutral (actively ignored or simply very few views) on those fake questions, depending on the likelihood and timing of such votes (based on some model). As feedback, the system would explain each vote (or non-vote). For instance, ***posting text/code as an image*** could be a nearly instant five downvotes.

Comment: cont' - Part of the game could be to quickly save a downvoted question (incl., system provided questions, like the training rounds in normal computer games), within a set time (with a count down timer). Winning or losing the game could be reaching certain reputation points thresholds. It could even be multi-player.