# What should I do when my accepted answer turns out to be inappropriate?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, wrong-answers

A long time ago, I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2382399/34509), and it got accepted.

The other day, a comment informed me that my "answer" was not really answering the question. I tried to delete it, but I can't because it was accepted.

I therefore turned my answer into a community wiki and removed the answer text in order to not confuse people.

Is there official advice on what should be done in a situation like this?

Comment: The answer is correct, the question was wrong.  That's entirely normal, questions are often wrong, the point of asking them.  Unfortunately programmers google questions, not answers, so you'll inevitably get hassled in the comments for not posting the cargo-cult answer.  The DVs obviously suck too.  Best thing to do is to ask for a comment clean-up, tends to slow down the me-too voters.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks. I worry more about social reputation than the SO reps these days though, so I did not even recognize the DVs

Comment: You can request that the answer be [disassociated from your account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Comment: As @HansPassant said, your answer is legit. You are basically saying: "You should let the optimizer do that", which is a reasonable answer. However, I would have put an expanded explanation first (with a heading like "You should let the optimizer do that"), not place the (too brief) explanation after the code. Without seeing the explanation first, people are expecting to see the unrolled loop when they look at your code. Immediately seeing the loop in your code sets up a discontinuity between the Q and your A, which I would expect would unsettle people: (i.e. get comments and some downvotes).

Comment: The second most-upvoted answer doesn't compile, and even applying some of the 'obvious' fixes doesn't seem to make it work.  Yet the second answer also has a lot of up-votes — which leaves one scratching one's head.  On what basis was the answer up-voted?  (Me-too-ism at work, presumably, combined with 'that looks about right, but there is no need to try it'.)

Comment: It may not work in your case, since the answer is six years old, but I had a similar situation and I simply commented with an @ tag of the question's author asking them to unaccept my answer. Once they did, I could delete the answer.

Answer (score 26):

## Don't

- Remove all content and replace it with a "deleted" message.

## Do

- Add a disclaimer or notice at the top of your answer stating that it's wrong.
- Flag your answer for moderator attention and ask a mod to delete it for you.

Comment: Thanks. Although your reply seems to be inofficial, I will follow

Comment: `Flag your answer for moderator attention and ask a mod to delete it for you.` -> IIRC mods have made comments they're reluctant to remove accepted posts, even when incorrect and requested by the author.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I remember a few accepted answers being deleted upon OP's request. But I haven't found any official statements for that.

Comment: Is it acceptable if i copy the text of another answer?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb No, but it may get your answer deleted because of plagiarism :)

Comment: @Floern nice, is that done automatically? I may do that, as a workaround.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb no, only if a mod sees it. And worst case you get your account suspended.

Comment: Do you think if I say "this is the text of the other answer" as a disclaimer, it's OK?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb doubt it. Copied or duplicate answers are not really constructive.

Comment: @Floern but if the target has the accepted mark? perhaps search engine favor the accepted answer (not sure what google does). so if the accepted answer contains the text of an unaccepted answer and promotes it that way, why not?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb How about just put "See xxxx's answer" and an explanation of the problem.

Comment: When I see a question that an answer is the same as in some other similar question, then I usually put a short summary of the solution, and then put a link to the original.