# How to become a non-member for Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: support, meta

I want to become a non-member from Meta Stack Overflow? But I want to be active on Stack Overflow.

How is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean the overall Stack Exchange Meta or the Stack Overflow Meta? (There's a Meta site for the entire network and one for each of the individual sites).

Comment: @EJoshuaS Non member for MEta stack overflow

Comment: Basically *you can't*...but you don't have to engage if you dont want to. What we really don't understand is the purpose behind your request. Is this membership somehow an issue?

Comment: You can't get rid of your Meta.SO account but there is nothing forcing you to come here.  If you don't want to be here then just don't visit.

Comment: Agreed. Nothing forces me to come here. I want to know only about exit process. If its not possible, thats ok

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes. usually i observed joining any site in this network is too easy.. But the process designed to delete the questions, becoming unmember from the site is very difficult. I found that unknowingly i am a member of too many sites and want to get rid of member ship from few sites in this network. But i am surprised to listen that there is no way

Comment: The best you can do is ask to be disassociated from your posts on meta, and never come here again. That *should* be as simple as using the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page, according to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/215552...

Answer (score 2):

The only winning move is not to play. The account for Stack Overflow is also your account for Meta Stack Overflow. You can't leave one without leaving the other.

Comment: You can technically have your meta account deleted, but it will be recreated when you visit meta next.

Comment: @tiny straight to the point.. thanks