# What should I do when the OP edited a post and deleted most of the content?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-edit

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70057380/applying-sparsity-pattern-to-other-matrix-in-matlab). After it is answered, the OP deleted his/her code and most of the content, leaving only one line, which is almost the same as the title. This makes the post not understandable even with an accepted answer.

My guess is that the OP wanted to delete the post, but couldn't, because the answer has already been upvoted.

What should I do with this? Is there a suitable flag to raise?

Comment: That's vandalism. I rolled it back. You can custom flag for mod attention if you come across this.

Comment: What is vandalism?

Comment: Related: [Should we say "vandalizing" to refer to defaced content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372007)

Comment: [Vandalism](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vandalism}): any activity that is considered to be damaging or destroying something that was good.

Comment: Please use google before you consider asking somebody or some site a question.

Comment: @philipxy I did. Hard to find helpful results without knowing the word vandalism in the first place.

Comment: I guess you are trying to say that without knowing to call the user's action "vandalism" you couldn't properly google to find an answer to this question. I don't believe that googling reasonable multiple phrasings of what you observed with "meta.stackoverflow.com" (even without google 'site:' functionality) doesn't answer this question. Moreover, you should have googled "vandalism" & "vandalism" with "meta.stackoverflow.com" before commenting asking what it meant.

Comment: @philipxy *"I don't believe that googling reasonable multiple phrasings of what you observed with "meta.stackoverflow.com" (even without google 'site:' functionality) doesn't answer this question"* -  What a worthless comment, for the same reason people ask questions on main, and in real life. It saves time. Why waste time looking for a solution when you can get it faster by asking?

Comment: Not a big fan of blind googling when approaching a problem from no-or-little information. You won't have sufficient tools to detect when you're being mislead. I'd look the word up in a dictionary.