# How can I edit my questions so they could be upvoted?

Tags: support, downvotes, upvotes, editing-help, quality-improvement

When I was new to Stack Overflow I did not ask good questions and therefore my questions received downvotes. My problem is not "How to ask a good question?", but how to improve my existing downvoted questions:

1. [Multiplying vector elements in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894304/multiplying-vector-elements-in-c)
2. [how to set ImageButton randomly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322151/how-to-set-imagebutton-randomly)
3. [Change ImageButton Drawable automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642384/change-imagebutton-drawable-automatically)

Looking at the dates, one can see how later questions improved as I began to understand the rules. The formatting and the way I asked changed!

Can someone suggest ways to edit these questions so they get better reception?

Comment: Yeah, that was a pretty big mistake.  Live and learn, but the teaching moment was to be patient and not force anything.  These questions now need to be found back by the Googlers, they typically vote once for every ~200 visits for good Q+A.  At the clip they are going that will likely be years before their score goes above 0.  Which is fine, we do create Q+A for the long haul.

Comment: There is no difference between ""How to ask a good question" & "how to improve my existing downvoted questions".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I could give you some advice:

- [Multiplying two large vector variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894304/multiplying-two-large-vector-variables): you should provide a `main` and all the includes instead of just the function, so your code can be pasted and compiled without any effort from the others: a *minimal reproducible example* (aka *mcve*). Apart from that there's nothing much you can do.
- [Setting Image to ImageButton randomly on every click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322151/setting-image-to-imagebutton-randomly-on-every-click) probably difficult to create a *mcve* in this context, but the last sentence *describes* the error message ("However, I still get an error that the image is not found") instead of quoting it literally (the real error message often gives more information). That generally annoys people.
- [Change ImageButton Drawable automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642384/change-imagebutton-drawable-automatically): at least you could have formatted your code properly (I've done that for you). Apart from that it's unclear why you're asking how to call your code several times to get several random results...

If the question has no answers or non voted up answers, you could consider deleting those. This would stop the downvotes (but would still count for question ban). It's unfair if instead of voting the answer up/accepting because it's useful to you you prefer using it & delete the question (it happens a lot...)

Generally, editing old questions, even if it bumps them, rarely draws attention/votes on them, specially if they've got voted up/accepted answers. So just forget about it, and be extra careful when you post your next question (formatted properly, clear, reproducible example, reactivity to comments, the usual...)

Of course, posting a meta question about your posts like you just did draws attention on them. You gained one edit from me, and possibly votes from others. Of course they can also be _down_votes. Fame is a double-edged sword.

Comment: If I did what you say and the question ban didn't left what I should do? I do not want to close the account after earning those badges and privileges @Jean-François Fabre♦

Comment: I'm not a question ban specialist, this link explains it better than me https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222939/how-long-does-a-ban-or-suspension-on-an-se-site-last. The algorithm is secret but it seems that posting _answers_ that get votes help. Moderators can't do anything to lift a ban (unlike for site suspensions or reviews)

Comment: @AhmadAlwareh First, there isn't much we can do to help you in terms of coveting the wrong things; the site isn't about badges and privileges (those are nice things, but not the core of how the site works, so they shouldn't be your goal). Second, patient is a virtue. Improvements themselves don't make any difference: they make the post more attractive to readers. It will take time for readers to visit the post and vote it up (or remove a downvote). Finally, if the ban persists, you can still ask a new question at least once every 6 months; be sure when that happens to make it a great question!

Comment: @AhmadAlwareh - If you currently have a question ban, then creating a new account isn’t a solution, the system will detect that behavior and your new account will be automatically question banned.  However, if you wait 6 months, and asked a higher quality question you might get enough votes to get out of the 6 month question ban system.  Otherwise, posting positive contributions, participating in other activities (edit, review queues) will also help.

Answer (score 8):

My advice: Don't sweat it. Even [the best of us have some bad questions in our past](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11530491/13860).

Rather than dwelling on the past, focus on asking good questions, and posting good answers now.

Having said that, there is one partial recourse you might take in an extreme situation. Once, I believe on [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) I asked a very poorly received, but popular question (during private beta, no less). Although it had been closed as off-topic, it remained on the site, and continued to receive downvotes. Since it had highly-voted answers, I was unable to delete it. To divorce myself from the poor reputation, I made the question community wiki. (The question in question has apparently since been deleted, or I'd link to it.)  This won't completely remove your name from the question, though. The question is still in your history.

Comment: You can also [ask to be disassociated from the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/215552), but it should be used sparingly.

Comment: Marking an answer as Community Wiki doesn't remove any reputation loss (or gain) you've already incurred from it, it just prevents you from earning or losing reputation due to it from that point on (it also doesn't prevent you from continuing to earn badges from the answer). Additionally, I don't think it would affect your standing due to an answer ban, either.