# Unable to delete old question. Keeps getting voted down

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

I no longer need this question: [Split a word document into new files keeping the formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150501/split-a-word-document-into-new-files-keeping-the-formatting)

Neither answer are voted up or useful. Since other users don't seem to like the question, I would like to delete it, but am told that I can't because other users have spent time answering it.

What can I do? I do not want to flag it since such flags get declined in my experience

Comment: Why can't you delete (isn't the message explaining a little bit what's blocking you?)? My understanding is you should. Cause while you have answers, none of them have a positive score or are accepted.... or am I misremembering what the criteria is?

Comment: Questions with multiple answers can't be deleted, I think.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery - [true](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/284827): "*You can't delete your own question if it: ... has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)*"

Comment: @Patrice “question cannot be deleted / people spent time answering”

Comment: Is it worth closing? That could be an appropriate path for deletion. Otherwise, you can simply request for disassociation.

Comment: @Mplungjan then it's the multiple answers that tripped me. Seems to be the system WAI :/

Comment: @yivi what does that mean?

Comment: If it's worth closing?

Comment: @yivi request disassociate

Comment: if it gets closed, it will get roombaed. Vote to close yourself, so it goes in the close queue.

Comment: I don’t see why this needs to be deleted. There was obviously some effort put into the answers, and even if you don’t find them useful, that doesn’t prove no one else ever will.

Comment: First result on Google: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395

Comment: @CodyGray it irritates me to get voted down in a question that does not have working answers!

Comment: downvote the answers (if they are not useful), vote to close. Already 1 close vote. It'll be closed in no time with negative scoring answers => roomba.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I would not want to punish the ppl who did try to answer. Their answers are not wrong, just not complete. But thanks

Comment: I apologize for not following up on this with you - I can't remember having seen the second comment. But even so, it's not clear what you mean by "it revealed errors", nor what the short-comings of the suggested approach are. It's not that the question is not interesting - I imagine it's getting downvoted *because* it's intersting, people want an answer, and there has been no follow-up.