# Should I delete this old answer that keeps getting random votes/comments?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer

I have an answer from 8+ years ago:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028086/1310604

Its not the best answer, and I feel its votes clearly reflect that. Regardless, I dont believe editing the answer will provide any value, anything worth saying has already been posted in other answers.

I have considered removing it in the past but I don't want to simply hide my mistakes.

What should I do with the answer? I would like to stop getting downvoted/passive aggressive comments. My comment response might not be the best either, but that's for another discussion.

I considered making it a community wiki but that seems like an incorrect use of the feature.

Comment: If editing it would bring nothing new and just repeat existing answers I'd delete it.

Comment: If you think the answer isn't really a good fit for the site, wouldn't deleting it be a case of correcting a mistake rather than hiding one?

Comment: Yes I suppose that would be true, but I dont think its fundamentally a bad answer. 8 years ago I thought it was great lol. I just dont care to keep getting updates about it really... I wish I could lock the answer

Comment: You can request for [disassociation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request?noredirect=1&lq=1). But if you keep the answer associated to your account, you'll receive the notifications. On the other hand, maybe the whole question should go.

Comment: Expand on it and see if you can't find something new in 8 years. even in java there something new to tell, ne ce pas

Comment: the whole question was a duplicate and the meta effect gathered enough people to delete it. Problem solved. We're not losing a great question, and the answers bring nothing to the original post. No need to merge.

Comment: Not the resolution I expected but I am happy with lol. Thanks for all the input, I think nbk brought up a good point, maybe if it wasnt a dup it would have made even more sense.