# Is there an easy way to turn all my answers into community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

For personal reasons, I would like to distance myself from SO and consequently want to turn all my answers into Community Wiki (CW).

Doing that manually takes a long time so I'm wondering if there is an easy way to do that?

I'm aware of [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395), but I don't actually want disassociation. I'm fine with having my name on those posts, and I would like to keep all the privilege and rep that I've earned from them so far. However, I don't want to earn any more rep from those posts, so I'd like to convert all of them to CWs.

Comment: Why not just delete an account? Wouldn't that be simpler?

Comment: Hmm, could you clarify *why* you want to make your answers into CWs? I realized that disassociation (or more simply, deleting your account as Dharman suggested) won't actually make the answers CWs, which seems to be mostly what you're interesting in doing.

Comment: @Dharman Not if I don't want to delete my account...

Comment: @cigien No, I won't clarify.... No need to - I'm just asking if it's possible. I have already been beaten sufficiently for telling why. Don't want that again. So I just politely ask if that's possible.

Comment: Looks like the API doesn't have an option to CW posts: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs so I'm afraid you would have to scrape and script that.

Comment: @cigien [They did so here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416548/so-long-and-thanks-for-all-the-fish?noredirect=1#comment899118_416548), but as a warning this link is not visible for < 10k.

Comment: @rene Thanks for your answer. Then I need to evaluate what takes most time ... script or manual... after all I only have 1900 answers to change ;-/

Comment: What is the motivation to make your posts Community Wiki? Community Wiki means that the posts are owned by the community (not a specific author) and communal editing is encouraged. (As part of this, the rep requirement to edit a CW is reduced.) Is that your intention? If you want to completely relinquish ownership of the posts, dissociation would be a more appropriate choice.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Because one can only edit 10 posts a day, as is stated in the linked rate-limiting guide.

Comment: @Daedalus hmmm... can't be true for CW edits as I change +30 to CW yesterday

Comment: @SupportUkraine If you don't intend to come back, why is a (question/answer) ban something you want to avoid?  I know you didn't say anything about a ban, but I assume you're not deleting your posts because a ban is something you want to avoid.

Comment: Yeah, we're not going to allow you to delete all your Meta answers, either. Normally, vandalism like that would result in an account suspension, but since you're posting here, I'll just notify you in this way. Those answers have been undeleted and will continue to be. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted SO the ability to distribute that content under the CC by-SA license for as long as it sees fit to do so. Deletion is not an option. Dissociation is your only route.

Comment: @CodyGray yes, I want to turn them over to the community

Comment: It is still not clear to me why you want to turn over *all* of your answers to the community. That does not make any sense. If you want to delete your account, that is a much simpler way to relinquish ownership of all posts.

Comment: @CodyGray I didn't delete on SO as I consider that community property. But I did delete on meta-SO as they are opinion based posts representing my personal view. And I don't consider that community property

Comment: @CodyGray I have already told that I don't want to delete my account. I also told that I don't want to explain further... I have done that. I was hardly punished for it. No need to repeat that

Comment: @CodyGray I'm simply and politely asking if this is doable. Is that a problem?

Comment: I have no idea what is going on... If you want someone to help you, you're going to have to stop playing games and evading the truth. All contributions to this site, regardless of whether they're on SO or Meta or some other SE site, are licensed to SE for distribution in compliance with CC by-SA. You have the ability to relinquish your ownership of those posts under CC by-SA, which means that SE can host them *without* your name attached. That's called dissociation. Everything else falls under vandalism. Your personal views don't matter.

Comment: There needs to be a legitimate *reason* to turn a post over the community. Marking *all* of your posts as CW makes no sense. No, there's no easy way to do it, because it doesn't make sense to do. If you aren't willing to tell us what you are trying to accomplish, then we cannot help you to accomplish it. (It is a standard X-Y problem.)

Comment: @CodyGray They explained why [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416548/so-long-and-thanks-for-all-the-fish?noredirect=1#comment899118_416548).

Comment: Marking posts as CW isn't going to help Ukraine or hurt Russia, so that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @CodyGray Turning my SO answers into community wiki can't be a violation of anything. It's a standard feature of the UI. I'm just looking for a faster way to do it than to click, click, click...

Comment: @CodyGray No, but it helps me... and once again... I'm not going to defend my motivation. Been there, done that... and was hardly beaten

Comment: That premise is flawed. The UI allows you to do all sorts of things that, if you did them to *everything*, you would be breaking the rules and abusing the system.

Comment: @CodyGray So you are saying it's a violation to turn all my question into CW?

Comment: *How* does it help you? Or anyone? Is that a sufficient justification for doing things? There is a specific use-case for CW posts. It isn't just meant as a button that users can click at random.

Comment: @CodyGray It helps me because it makes me feel good that I no longer will be considered part of it

Comment: @CodyGray "It isn't just meant as a button that users can click at random." okay, there do I find a description saying when it's allowed to turn an answer into CW and when it isn't

Comment: You will still be listed as the author of CW. Community Wiki is not dissociation. It just means that you want others to help you edit the post.

Comment: You would be considered “part of it”, though. Your username would still be linked to the cw-converted posts. As opposed to account deletion or disassociation. Just saying that those would fit better to your objectives.

Comment: @Dharman I know but I'll be out of "the game"

Comment: @SupportUkraine But... you still keep your rep, your account, and your name is still on the posts?  CW doesn't disassociate you from the posts; you would still be considered part of it.  You wouldn't be out of the game, because you would still have your rep, so what are you trying to achieve exactly?  The only way you'd be out of the game is if you deleted your account and relinquished your rep.

Comment: What does it mean "out of the game"? You will still be in the game as you will still have an account on the site and 1900 CW posts.

Comment: @Dharman But no further rep....

Comment: @SupportUkraine But you **keep your current rep**; that's still in the game, because you're not releasing any of your privileges.

Comment: Interesting that you all have a rush beating me for my action which isn't violating any SO rule but no one is answering the question...

Comment: @Daedalus What I earned yesterday when things was different is okay... but not what I ean tomorrow

Comment: Nobody is beating you. We are just trying to understand what you want to achieve. As for the answer, we told you it's not possible.

Comment: I already answered the question: no, this is not possible. All I'm trying to do now is to help you come up with an *actual* solution.

Comment: You can go through all your posts and manually set them to CW, but that will probably take few weeks. You can also script it, but it won't help you much with the rate limits

Comment: @Dharman Why? You all ready know, right? You  were the first to attack my point of view and close my message... wasn't you? So why do you need to repeat it... you already won... what more do you want?

Comment: @SupportUkraine Disagreement and trying to understand isn't beating.  You haven't lost any rep for this experience; none of your main posts have even been downvoted as result of this discussion.  While this post itself has been downvoted, you haven't lost any rep for it because meta doesn't cause you to lose rep.

Comment: @Daedalus "You haven't lost any rep for this experience; ..." Rep means nothing now

Comment: Maybe we have different understanding of what "beating" means. I am not aggressive towards you. I am not attacking you in any way. I do not want you to suffer. You came to Meta where topics are discussed and that is what we are doing.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Then delete your account if it means nothing.  But you want to keep it; for a reason we have yet to figure out.

Comment: "Rep means nothing now" Then you can delete your account which will be the easiest solution. You can always recreate it if you decide to come back

Comment: @Dharman Because... when SO get their ethics in place again I'll likely want to contribute again

Comment: You can recreate an account. You can even request to associate your old posts with your new account

Comment: Effectively, you want to disassociate from your content. Yes, technically community wiki can serve that purpose, but that's not what it is for, your needs are served by disassociation. Account deletion would be a far more effective tool for this purpose, given you don't want to be associated with SO.

Comment: @KevinB "Effectively, you want to disassociate from your content" No, I never said that... I said that I want my answers to be CW

Comment: @SupportUkraine  "no longer will be considered part of it" is disassociation; just because you call it something different, doesn't make it any different.

Comment: Why do you prefer CW, over disassociation? I can think of one reason, but I'd rather not assume in this case.

Comment: @KevinB I'm not sure what you are think so please speak up

Comment: Making it a community wiki, as opposed to disassociation, allows you to keep all things you earned from the post, as well as allowing you to continue earning badges from it. It also leaves your name on it, meaning it's not truly disassociating you from it. so... from my PoV that doesn't really do anything.. to serve the action you're taking. You could just stop logging in and get the same end result without all the hassle.

Comment: @KevinB exactly... but I wont earn further rep, right

Comment: You would stop earning rep, but you'd continue earning badges, receiving notifications, etc.

Comment: well badges I can accept... don't find them important anyway... but yep, no more rep is what I want

Comment: @SupportUkraine Why is disassociation not an option for you?

Comment: I mean, sure, but that's a bit shady isn't it? You want to give up ownership... but keep the benefit of the rep it gave you? you can't have both.

Comment: Earning rep shouldn't make any difference for your account anymore. You already have all available privileges. Earning further rep is meaningless. It doesn't give you anything new, so earning more reputation shouldn't matter to you. Marking your answers as community wiki would stop your account gaining new reputation, but you would still keep your current rep and all privileges except dupe-hammer.

Comment: @KevinB Why not ? Isn't that exactly what CW do?

Comment: @Dharman Exactly... so why is that a problem for you?

Comment: It's not a problem for me...It's a problem for you judging by this question. I was just trying to find a solution like the rest of us. One of my proposals is to do nothing. You won't really gain anything by marking all your posts as CW, and since it's not easily possible and you don't want to delete an account, just do nothing. Ignore all the reputation you receive from now on.

Comment: it's more a matter of intent. You aren't looking to CW to provide the community the ability to maintain your posts easier, you're looking to CW to disassociate without the negatives of disassociation. CW was never meant for disassociation.

Comment: @KevinB Perhaps think about it like... Company X has earned money doing Y in site Z. For some reason they don't want to do Y in site Z in the future so should they return all money?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for your purpose, if you kept ownership of the posts so that your name and avatar, and link to your profile, was clearly displayed on them?

Comment: @Dharman "It's a problem for you judging by this question. I was just trying to find a solution like the rest of us." No, it's not a problem for me... it's simple and easy... I don't want further rep for the answers I posted so I want to CW them. You decline to understand my position even if you know it - well, I don't require you to but you could at least respect by stand point

Comment: @KevinB If I did, I will still get occasional rep from visitors which I don't want

Comment: I understand that you don't want to receive any reputation any more. I have suggested ways you can accomplish it. I also tried to make you see that new reputation is meaningless. You have an odd request and I am out of options. I can't help you even though I tried.

Comment: @Dharman All I did was to ask whether it was possible to do something. I mainly got people questioning my motivations. If you knew it wasn't doable, all it required was a: No, not possible. I know from other interactions on SO/SE that I'm pretty alone with my point of view so I didn't post them here - just a simple question. Still I had to go over it again.

Comment: @all How can this be closed as a dupe that is about disassociation when I explicit ask for something else? Come on...

Comment: @SupportUkraine Because it still boils down to disassociation; why is it not an option for you?  Maybe describe that reason in your question, why you can't use disassociation?

Comment: @Daedalus No, it doesn't boil down to "my reason for wanting that". That's irrlevant. It's a simple, precise question: Can I do X and if so how? Why I want do it is not important. And that some readers thinks I should disassociate is no a reason for closing the question. They can write that in comments/answers but a close reason it can never be.

Comment: @SupportUkraine That's not what I'm asking; I'm not asking your reasons for wanting to do the action, I'm asking why a particular action is not possible for you.

Comment: @Daedalus Well, I all ready answered that. I don't want further rep from these answers but I don't mind to be listed as OP.

Comment: @Daedalus As I sad... I don't mind my name being OP

Comment: @SupportUkraine The only other idea I have is to make a feature request and hope it gets implemented.  Otherwise, as you said, you already have your answer.

Comment: @Daedalus fine... but no, a feature request is not an option. No one here feel like I do so imagining that a feature request will be well accepted is impossible. I'll either do it manually or make a script... but now Cody Gray says it's illegal (without any reference) so... I don't know what to do but I kind of doubt Cody is right

Comment: @SupportUkraine Then just close the tab and delete all bookmarks to it; as Dharman
said, it's not like rep means anything anyway for you at this point; you have everything that could be attained from it.

Comment: @Daedalus nah... that's not a solution... Closing my eyes doesn't mean it doesn't happen... it's only means I don't see it... and the irony is that that's exactly what this is about

Comment: @SupportUkraine You have explained that disassociation isn't what you're after, and therefore, this post is not a duplicate. That said, I believe that sentence that made all that confusion is _"I like to **disassociate** myself from SO"_. So, I advise you to edit the question and replace it with something like _"I would like to stop receiving any further rep from my existing answers"_. I would edit it myself but I don't want to put words into your mouth.

Comment: @41686d6564 To be fair, the wording originally said "detach", and I suggested that the OP use "disassociation" instead, as I assumed that's what they meant. I've edited it a bit now. BTW, feel free to edit posts to clarify them, so long as you don't feel you're changing the intent of the post.

Comment: @cigien Yeah, I normally do that. But given that the OP seems a bit defensive, I didn't want to add more fuel to the fire. Good edit nonetheless.

Comment: @Dharman "You can even request to associate your old posts with your new account". While you can certainly make the request, such requests are generally declined by SE. Associating your old content with a new profile isn't done, as is very clearly stated in the page to delete a profile: "Deletion is irreversible, and you will have no way to regain any of your original content, should this deletion be carried out and you change your mind later on." There, however, is an edge case which will result in migrated posts being associated with the new profile on the destination site.

Comment: The only cases which I recall where SE associated old posts with a new profile were accounts which were nuked due to the user being under 13 (or 16 in the EU). In some cases, if the user can demonstrate ownership of the old account (hard, because SE doesn't have records to associate the user with the account, as deleting such records was the point), then SE has associated older posts with a new account once the user is above the age limit in their jurisdiction.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, there is no easy way to accomplish this. There is no option for it in the UI, and even the moderator tools do not provide a way to make all of a user's posts Community Wiki. Furthermore, attempting to do it from a script will quickly put you on the wrong side of rate limits.

Of all the features curiously missing from this site, though, this is not one of them. This is not something that you should be seeking to do, as [Community Wiki has a specific meaning](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki). It does *not* remove your name from a post, it does *not* disclaim your ownership of that post, and it does *not* register your dissent with actions taken by the company. It is also not meant as a rep-denial mechanism, although it does have that side-effect. The [privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) summarizes when you should make answers Community Wiki:

> 1. When you want to enhance the "wiki" aspect of your post, so that it can be a continually evolving source of good information through repeated editing.
> 2. When you feel your post would benefit from less concern about voting affecting the reputation of those participating in it.

As with programming questions on the main site, this smacks to me of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you could provide us with more information about what you're hoping to accomplish, then we might be able to come up with a better solution for you.

You already know that deletion of your posts is not an option—when posting content to this site, you agreed to cross-license the content to Stack Exchange under the CC by-SA license, which allows them to distribute the content for as long as they see fit, as long as they comply with that license. One of the primary requirements of the CC by-SA license used by Stack Exchange is that all content must be attributed to the original author. That's why your usercard appears below all of your posts.

Mass removal of posts, regardless of motivations (whether due to a rage-quit, a political stance, or whatever else), is considered to be *vandalism*, and moderators will be forced to step in to reverse it. Typical solutions involve issuing an immediate account suspension to put a stop to the problem, and then undeleting (or rolling back) the posts.

If you want to disclaim ownership of or affiliation with your posts, then you have an option to do so. It is called "disassociation". This removes the posts from your account, turning them entirely over to Stack Exchange, freeing them from complying with the attribution requirement of the CC by-SA license. To seek disassociation (which is always your right), start reading here: [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa)

Comment: BTW: You undeleted the meta-SO I deleted... did you also reverted all the SO-answers I turned into community wiki?

Comment: I don't know how *anything* is relevant, because you haven't told me what you are trying to accomplish other than "I want to make all of my posts CW". Frankly, that's a stupid thing to want; it makes no sense. So I have to assume it's an XY problem, and that there is probably a better solution. I was willing to try to help you find that better solution, which is why I chose initially to engage by posting comments, rather than posting an answer that amounts to, effectively, "no", and will admittedly not be very helpful. Unfortunately, you weren't very forthcoming, so I'm out of options.

Comment: Can posts of any type be re-associated with an account at a later point if an account is deleted with the disassociation option?  I don't know if this is an actual thing, I'm only guessing that it is based on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/is-there-an-easy-way-to-turn-all-my-answers-into-community-wiki#comment899416_416584) comment.

Comment: I have not yet reverted CW status, but only because (A) I haven't decided yet what to do, and (B) I don't have time to do that at the moment. Do not assume that a decision has been reached on the permissibility of that action. *In general*, you should assume that applying an action to massive numbers of posts will *not* be OK, regardless of whether that action would be permissible on a smaller scale.

Comment: @CodyGray "that's a stupid thing to want; it makes no sense." Thanks. I'm just stupid. Nice to hear from a mod. I have already said that I do want any rep from those answers going forward.

Comment: It should go without saying that there is a big difference between being a stupid person and thinking you want to do a stupid thing. I consider myself not the former, but I have wanted to do stupid things and even *done* stupid things way too many times to count. Again, the XY problem is a perfect analogy here. You've settled upon what you think is a solution, but it isn't.

Comment: @Daedalus As far as I know, the team considers dissociation to be a one-way process, so requests to associate dissociated posts with a new account are not likely to be honored.

Comment: @CodyGray There is no XY problem here... I don't want rep from those answer so I want to CW them.

Comment: Making a post CW doesn't remove the rep gained from those posts, so it sounds like it is not even a solution for you.

Comment: @CodyGray No and that's not what I want... but it "removes" any future rep. And that's what I want

Comment: I have accepted this answer as it actually answer the question with a clear NO

Comment: @CodyGray To address the XY problem and after reading all the comments, I believe that the OP's objective is this: 1) Keep all the reputation they earned/lost from their answers in the past. 2) Stop receiving any further rep in the future from those answers. 3) They don't care if their name is still associated with the answers or if they receive badges from them. AFAICT, that (specific goal) can only be achieved by turning all their answers into CW, but it's my understanding (based on your answer and comments) that that's not allowed.

Comment: Now, I personally think that achieving that goal wouldn't really benefit the OP in any way because new rep earned after 25k is pretty much meaningless, but others have already explained that to the OP in the comments and the OP still insists that that's what they want, regardless. @SupportUkraine Please correct me if I failed to convey your objective.

Comment: @41686d6564 That is, indeed, the impression that I have now gotten, after playing a game of "extract the truth" in comments (note the comment thread extends far over 50 comments that you can see, with more being deleted). Of course, I can't help but wonder whether the statements of what the asker is intending to accomplish have been colored by the explanations which were provided of what the tool he's aiming to use actually does. It is a familiar pattern with X-Y questions, too, and it is called "digging in one's heels".