# Do GDPR's protections on "personal information" entitle users to vandalise/remove their own posts?

Tags: discussion, users, licensing, gdpr, vandalism

[This revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65052256/4) is the result of a user's reasoning that the GDPR entitles them to replace an accepted and upvoted answer with things like "Content no longer relevant to the question".

I was so sure that it was a clear case of vandalising a post that I rolled the edits back multiple times. I also recommended that they flag the post for moderator attention, but the user kept vandalising the post.

Now, I've taken a step back and am wondering whether their claims are true. Do the protections provided by GDPR with respect to "personal information" entitle a user to vandalise their own posts when deleting their account?

Comment: Related: [Can GDPR affect the structure of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368899/11682469)

Comment: After the second rollback I would have notified a moderator. This is a relatively clear case of rage quitting.

Comment: @Trilarion The user moderator-flagged themselves already at that point. But I do not believe in rage-quitting. It seems more a case of righteously-knowing-the-law-better and trying to make a point. I do not expect that account to be deleted. This is not the last we have seen.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

No.

GDPR is about the control of your [personal information](https://gdpr.eu/companies-outside-of-europe/) - assuming that you are an EU or UK* citizen, what you post in questions and answers should not be personal information. If you have posted personal information by mistake then you should edit it out and raise a flag asking for the previous revisions to be redacted.

If you don't want your personal information held by Stack Overflow then you can delete your account. However, this will not delete your posts - it will just anonymise them. When you post something on Stack Overflow you are giving Stack Overflow the rights to republish that information, in compliance with the CC BY-SA license, under which all content published to this site is licensed, per our Terms of Service.

* Despite leaving the EU, GDPR is still UK law (for now).

Comment: What’s maybe not explicit enough in this answer is that the rights which users give Stack Overflow under the EULA are not unilaterally revocable. Users are giving Stack overflow a *perpetual license* to publish their contents under specific terms. If a user decides that they don’t like the terms any more, though luck. Of course the EULA do not override the GDPR but there’s simply conflict here.

Comment: Do note it also applies to a bunch of non EU (or UK) citizens, for various reasons (e.g. "processing of personal data in the context of the activities of an establishment of a controller or a processor in the Union, regardless of whether the processing takes place in the Union or not" and any data subjects (e.g. tourists) in EU member states)

Comment: individual questions can be disassociated from an account without deleting the account as a whole.  I'm not sure if moderators can do so, or if that needs to be escalated to the SE community management team.

Answer (score 22):

No, it doesn't entitle users to remove their posts.

Note however, that some information attached to their post may be subject to removal via the GDPR.

For example, their username, the date/time when they last edited the post, etc may be considered personal data until it's anonymized.

[As ChrisF states in his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404171/6047804), the user can delete their account if they wish to anonymize their data.

Additionally, even if the post had personal content, **blanking the content still keeps the content in the edit history**. So the data wouldn't actually be removed. **More drastic action would have to be taken to remove the data, if it in fact was considered personal data** under the GDPR.

Answer (score 6):

No, that does not entitle the user to do that. ChrisF explains that very well in his answer.

One issue I didn't see addressed here was the aspect of edit wars that happened...

**One rollback is all you get.**

Beyond that, if someone rolls back to their edited version, *even if it is vandalism*, just use a custom flag for a moderator, use as much detail as possible in your flag message, and move on.

Engaging in a back and forth in either comments or by repeatedly rolling back an edit is not productive.