# "I've thought better of my QUESTION" message when deleting an ANSWER

Tags: discussion, bug, deleted-answers, deletion

When deleting my sixth answer on a given day I am presented with the following message (emphasis mine):

> You have already deleted 5 of your own posts today; further deletes
>   are blocked. See "[I've thought better of my **question**; can I delete
>   it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)" for alternatives.

I was deleting an answer and the linked post is completely irrelevant (does not say anything about deleting answers). I believe a different post should be linked to the popup message when you're deleting answers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you deleting so many of your own answers in a single day? Do you regularly delete 5+ answers in a single day, or was today an anomaly?

Comment: I have done this before too. Sometimes, you just go through and look at answers which just didn't quite meet your personal standard, so you remove them. Once you have posted 2776 (as Salman has) 5 isn't really that many at all.

Comment: @TylerH yes I regularly delete 5 answers in a single day.

Comment: The basic reasoning is the same here; don't delete that many things at once. Edit the post to make it better. Disassociate yourself from the post instead of deleting. I think they should just edit the help article to replace "question" with "post" and maybe call out those few question-specific items in separate paragraphs.

Comment: @SalmanA That's... a lot. Why are you deleting so many answers on such a regular basis?

Comment: @TylerH *a lot?* At this rate it'll take me 1.5 years to delete *all* of my answers.

Comment: @SalmanA Why are you trying to delete all your answers? Why not just have your account deleted? The point of the restriction is so that we *don't* have users going around and removing proverbial tons of useful content from the site wholesale.

Comment: @TylerH I never said I want to/trying to delete all my answers.

Comment: I used to post ~two dozen answers a day and used Sunday to clean up.  But yeah, the machine is not compatible with that answering style, so I had to adjust the way I answer.  There is no limit on comments, yay.  You can vote on the "disassociate" idea in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288274/17034), it got bumped into a 6-to-8 years schedule.

Comment: @SalmanA Well you never answered why you were deleting so many answers directly, but you did say "at this rate it'll take me 1.5 years to delete all my answers", with "it will" being the operative phrase here, indicating you *are* planning to or are currently in the process of deleting all your answers. Regardless, I don't really see a good reason for deleting so many answers on such a frequent basis. The two possibilities I see are you're either not giving enough consideration to the question before posting an answer, or trying to circumvent a check to prevent wholesale loss of site content.

Comment: @SalmanA I've specifically avoided making assumptions by listing all the possible reasons for doing it. It just so happens that I can only think of two possible reasons and neither of them are good justifications. I'm perfectly open to another reason if there is one; I just can't think of it. The thing is, the question you asked here is really a minuscule thing (change 1 word in 1 modal) and has already been addressed, but what you've revealed is a much bigger concern: that a user is deleting 5+ of their own answers a day every day without any apparent justifiable reason... hence my question.

Comment: @SalmanA Neither of those comments address my question of *why*, they only state that they do the same thing as you. They certainly don't address why *you* are doing it.

Comment: @TylerH I am cleaning uo some of my answers. Now you do the same with those comments.