# You have already deleted 5 of your own posts today; further deletes are blocked

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, rate-limiting

I'll often hit this when deleting my own redundant or zero-upvote answers. It happens frequently that two users will simultaneously answer the question with essentially the same answer, no point in having them both there.

The point of the block was to prevent rage-quit. Please change it so that answers with 0 or lower score do not contribute to the limit of 5 per day. If that's too difficult to implement, just raise the limit a little (10 or 15 should do).

Comment: Answers that tread the same ground are OK.  In fact, when you see one of your answers treads the same ground as another answer; see how you can improve your answer?  Is it really and truly that there is no possible improvement you can make from your own experience?  We have hundreds of kinds of coffee, and hundreds of different coffee shops, and no one ever says, "Gosh, I can't open a coffee shop, someone already did that!"  Think about how you can add your unique point of view and add it to your answer. Maybe it's a different way of solving the problem, maybe it's going deeper?

Comment: This is old.  Always got rejected and never got community sympathy. Ultimately blew up pretty badly when an ultra-high rep user got suspended for doing this.  There is however an angle, the new CC by-SA 4.0 license explicitly gives you the right to disassociate yourself from the post.  [This way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288274/17034).  Getting traction on that however require things to normalize, that still seems pretty far off.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker  That's not a good analogy. The coffee shop will fill up if there is too much demand, and then service will become slow. S.O. is not like that, another answer just covering exact same ground is not adding any value.

Answer (score 25):

I have to say, I’m disinclined to raise the limit.

My personal feeling about this is that experienced users are too eager to delete zero-scored answers, perceiving them as not useful. What you have perhaps not considered is that the vast majority of our audience doesn’t upvote, either because they don’t even have accounts or because they just don’t bother. So, the fact that your answer hasn’t been upvoted doesn’t necessarily mean it is not useful. Often, an alternative phrasing of the same solution will be more clear or seem more relevant to someone than the original, which means that these answers *can* add value.

If they’re truly redundant, then of course go ahead and delete them. But why in the world do you have so many of these redundant, no-value-added answers that the ability to delete 5 per day is not enough?

It’s not something I’ve run into, and not something I can really appreciate.

On the other hand, self-vandalism *is* something I do run into with distressing frequency as a moderator, and the tools we have for dealing with this are…not great. All corrective actions are manual and reactionary. The only way we can stop someone and request that they reconsider is suspending their account, which we’ll do, but is admittedly a nuclear option.

Comment: 5 per day is not enough when you have 2000+ answers. It forces you to do this task over separate days, rather than getting it all done in one day. It doesn't actually prevent you from doing the task. So, that's just annoying.

Comment: @wim Then just don't delete them. Who knows, maybe they could be useful to someone in the future?

Comment: Yeah, “batching” your cleanup of older answers is the edge case. I’m sympathetic to that. But on balance I think the rate limits do more good than harm. This is one of the few cases where reputation isn’t a good basis on which to reduce the rate limits. Amount of rep has no correlation to self-vandalism, and, in my experience, more rep tends to increase the odds of someone underestimating the value of their own zero-scored contributions. As Hans says, this is an old debate. He comes down on the side of removing old zero-score answers. I think he purges a bit too heavy-handedly sometimes.

Comment: @wim - I have also have over a thousand answers, the amount of times I have deleted an answer, is a handful of times.  Perhaps it's not the system that should change?  Why are you removing so many of your answers?  Even if you have thousands of answers, you could in theory, eventually reach a limit with the system and be unable to submit any answer.

Comment: @SecurityHound  I literally explained why I'm deleting answers in the first paragraph of the post.  Was it not clear..?  Today I delete [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58826197/674039) answer because it's redundant (other user posted same thing), there is no edit necessary to add anything to answer, and the system blocks for no good reason - nothing to do with the reason for the block existing (ragequitters). Just removing redundancy / improving signal-to-noise ratio on site.

Comment: [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58826197) seems to be a perfect example. The code you include is ***not at all* equivalent** to the code in 9000's answer. You're using a `with` statement, you're opening the file in binary format (I assume, based on my knowledge of C's `fopen` function), you're calling `requests.post` instead of passing a "POST" string to `requests.request`, and you're using some of kind of property bag or whatever in the last parameter. Since I don't know Python, I have no idea if your example is preferable to 9000's example. But I do know it's different. @wim

Comment: Hmm, I think we have to disagree.  Other reasons you mentioned are trivial, is same answer for the fundamental issue to the question (which is: file should be opened in binary mode not text mode).  Anyway, I will delete it tomorrow so moot point.

Answer (score -6):

As a moderator on a couple of other StackExchange sites, I find it absurdly limiting that I can only remove *5* of my *own* posts per day.  I'm not interested in removing helpful, upvoted or accepted answers, I just want to curate my own old out-of-date answers that simply no longer make sense.

As a for instance, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11977294/1595565) doesn't answer the question, and I'm absolutely not interested in updating it to reflect the comment-answer that *is* correct, unless the comments on the answer are deleted.  In my experience, the SO mods are too inundated with work to attend to the constant barrage of comment flags, so that's not going to happen any time soon.  The expedient option is to allow me to make the choice myself.  While I'm by no means a high-rep user on SO, I am a *moderator* on two other sites, and clearly understand moderation.

Another example is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11977197/1595565), where there is no need to explain it in more depth or with a different assemblage of words; it can just *go*.

And in case you need another example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11989839/1595565) is not specific enough to be helpful to any future visitors to the question.

This per-day limit is silly in my opinion, and just means my attempt to do what would otherwise be perfectly normal curation and house-cleaning must instead take days of mental capacity to complete.

Comment: Just flag them if you want. Cases of users rage-quitting are abundant enough for the limit to make sense on this specific site. Maybe it's not the same on smaller SE sites.

Comment: This rate limit isn't specific to Stack Overflow, and applies to all sites. Maybe as a moderator on other sites it looks a bit restrictive to you but please try to understand the point of view of this particular site's moderators as well.

Comment: Is it really that restrictive? You have about 20 0-score answers. That’s just 4 days even if you wipe them all out.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi 4 days is 3 days more focus than I have time for right now.  But oh well, it's not the end of the world if some low quality answers stay on SO needlessly.  It's not like there aren't egregious examples everywhere that have nothing to do with *me*.

Comment: @yivi as a moderator, I am reticent to needlessly flag things when I could just look after it myself.  The flag queue on SO is huge all the time, without me adding to it.