# why I can't delete more than 5 post per day?

Tags: discussion, support

today I decided to delete some of my answers which I thought were not good enough(all of them were zero score and non them were accepted). after 5 post , it didn't let me delete any more answer.(and I didn't know there was such limit ,I'm new in this site)

then I answered a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61029325/really-dont-get-why-my-array-doesnt-sort-ascending-but-descending/61029418#61029418) then OP edited his/her post and I became sure my answer was wrong , so I tried to delete it ,but it didn't help and meanwhile a lot of comments and a great answer was given to question. and I get down-vote and since I couldn't  delete my answer I edited it and recieve a comment about copying other people words ,I apologized and promise to delete post as soon as I can (I didn't copy, just misunderstood and also tried to delete post after that).

what can I do for deleting post or solving this problem?

Comment: You can wait till tomorrow..., edit them to be better quality... or not delete your posts? There's nothing wrong with zero scoring answers, or unaccepted ones. Also you may be interested in [the rate limiting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

Comment: Related: [You have already deleted 5 of your own posts today; further deletes are blocked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391220).

Comment: All the stuff mentioned aside, I highly recommend you don't delete posts based on score or whether it was accepted, but by the quality. Votes don't always symbolize quality. High quality answers have been downvoted, and complete trash has been upvoted far more than it deserves. Look at the question; assuming it's on-topic, how well does your answer actually address it? Is it accurate? Does it say something you now know is wrong? If you can't fix the answer, or the question is off-topic, by all means, delete it. But if you answer the question, and you believe it's correct, leave it there.

Comment: As has already been mentioned, it could be useful to someone else in the future.

Comment: The number of times I have deleted any contribution on a day, is a handful, but I have never deleted more then one or two in a month.   Deleted questions (and answers) are still considered when determining if you or cannot submit a question (or answer).  The more contributions you delete the higher the chances you will be question (or answer) banned.  Once that happens the only way out of a ban is to positively contribute (and basically never delete anything).

Comment: @SecurityHound Does a deleted post with a positive score count towards a ban? Or is it only the ones with negative score?

Comment: @SecurityHound how can I know more about this ban to submit answer or question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only wait until tomorrow, because you're allowed to delete only 5 of your own posts per day.

**However**, you should really just leave your answers. I have plenty of zero-score, unaccepted answers that I have around. You never know; one of those may help someone in the future.

Comment: so I have to wait and there is no other way?

Comment: @hanie Just don't delete your answers. There's nothing to be ashamed of about zero-score, unaccepted answers.

Comment: Sonic corrected the FAQ; he had misinterpreted material describing delete vote differences on your own posts vs other posts.