# What is the best way to contact a moderator privately?

Tags: support, moderators

I can't understand some things that a moderator does. I want to request a clarification from them. In most cases I use the meta site for that. But sometimes it can be impractical because of the following reasons:

- I suspect, it would start a pointless flame on the meta site, which I want to avoid.
- I think they might see it as an insult.
- I suspect, although the mod didn't assess it as an insult, other people here on meta might.

On the link https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact I can contact only the SE employee and not the mods. *(Extension: although they might forward the request to the moderator, it would be something out of their direct responsibility and thus I can't want any cooperation from them.)*

Pinging the mod in a comment (using @modname) could also work, but their exact name is not always visible.

Sending a mail to the mod:

1. Would be probably an extraordinary thing, and in best case it would cause the silent ignoring of the mail.
2. The mail address of the mods is in most cases unknown.

Sending an answer in a private mod message could also work, but it is possible only in special circumstances (if they contacted me earlier).

Using the chat would have the same disadvantages as asking this here, on the meta.

So, what to do in a such situation?

Comment: NO, DO NOT SEND EMAILS TO THE MODS.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I said very clearly, why I won't do that.

Comment: @Tanner Thank you very much your grammar/spelling fixes! But this question goals explicitly the contact of 1) a single mod, 2) privately. This is I why I need to change back partially your changes now.

Comment: It would have to be quite an extraordinary case where you need to discuss something with a mod in private. Any dirty laundry should be aired in public here on meta; it informs everyone about things that are going on and also acts to watch the watchers. Having said that, this is not an unreasonable question in the abstract sense, it should simply happen *very very* rarely if ever.

Comment: @peterh no problem, I was going to comment about my edit to ensure your question content remained in tact after I edited it but then it kept getting edited again and again.

Comment: If you want clarification on a mod action, Meta is where you should ask. If clarification is all you want, then no one in their right mind will take it as an insult.

Comment: I guess this would be the [sample case](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288229/why-was-balusc-temporarily-suspended-from-so)? I would say to try post on meta, but focus on the problem, not the user...

Comment: @AndrewT. No, it is not visible (maybe for 10k+).

Comment: @Yannis Yes, it is so in most cases, but not in this.

Comment: @deceze Exactly.

Comment: About the close vote of the question: my question goals generally, similar cases as mine. This is why I didn't mention any circumstances about my current, actual problem - to avoid, that the special circumstances influence the answers to a general question.

Comment: Why was this closed?  The question is quite clear.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I have often received a flag I find odd and would like to contact the moderators about. This question and its answers were useful and stopped me from doing something silly like emailing the mods.

Comment: @NoahHuppert They vote everybody down, it doesn't matter why. If they had clear, fulfillable wishes, there would be an option to fulfill them, and to be cooperative with them. But they have no. Thus, the only way is to ignore them, and this is what I suggest also to you: **the only way to fix this community, if you free yourself from the downvote pressure, and ignore them**. Actually, being downvoted in *this community* is not a shame, it is a reason to be pride...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Flag one of your posts (preferably the one that was acted upon) with the "other" flag explaining what your issue is. It will enter the queue and be dealt with in due course.

Obviously this depends on the situation. It might not be appropriate in all circumstances, but if you think a mod handled a situation badly then the situation still hasn't been resolved so a new flag *is* appropriate.

By doing this you can address the mod who handled your first flag, but it also leaves it open for them to pass the situation onto another mod or even a community manager should it be necessary or if there's now a conflict of interest.

Comment: This is what should be done. This is the mechanism created for this purpose, so don't try any other way. It will not help you!

Comment: But requests for explanation are *not* valid flags. Are they now?

Comment: This doesn't precisely work in this format or fit into the problem.

Comment: @Mooseman That depends on the issue really. It then becomes up to the moderator to initiate the chat or not.

Comment: @ChrisF But wouldn't this still further clog the system?

Comment: @Mooseman - no more than it's already clogged ;)

Comment: A flag seems less disruptive than seeking a mod in chat. At the same time, it seems to me the circumstances would have to be really extraordinary to make it a more desirable option *overall* than bringing the issue up on Meta. I know the OP does not want to use Meta but it seems to me we don't want to encourage users to raise complaint flags *instead of* bringing their issues to Meta. As I've argued before, the regulars on Meta can explain a lot of moderation actions.

Comment: This isn't useful in many cases.  For example, I want to ask a moderator why they locked a question as "off-topic."  Since a question can be off-topic for many different reasons, I'd like to speak directly to the moderator to understand why they thought it was off-topic.  Since the question is locked, I cannot comment nor flag it nor vote to re-open.  (I cannot even update my own answer?!)  The moderator acted unilaterally, so they are the only one who can explain the reason, and the action seems to have closed all opportunities for rebuttal.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy You can always contact the SO team via the link at the bottom of the page. Or bring it up on Meta. so there are at least two opportunities for rebuttal which are not closed off...

Comment: The problem with flagging is that there is next to no feedback and no way to enter any kind of dialogue. The text entry field is small and may not be capable of containing all the relevant information, plus you have to either anticipate every possible misunderstanding and counter-argument. It's not a very effective communication method.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The problem with meta is that it's reputation suicide in most cases. Particularly for new users with little rep they aren't going to risk losing everything just to ask why a mod did something. It's unreasonable to expect them to.

Comment: @user10325 I'm not sure why it would be "reputation suicide". Down votes on meta don't affect your rep score, and anyone mass-voting on the main site is generally taken care of. So I don't believe I'm asking anyone to risk any rep. Nonetheless, and again, there's the contact us link to contact a community manager.

Comment: @ChrisF is there anyway to get my last question removed or for someone to answer my suport ticket? i really dont want to make a new account. I know that the last question I made was bad and no one will find it helpful. I know if i fix it it still will get ignored so there is no way for me to be able to post questions again unless that bad question is removed. it says on the thing not to delete questions  because this wont lift the question ban. been mega stressed about this because i want to work on my program and i cant

Answer (score 11):

If the moderator does not have contact information in his/her profile page then the answer is simple: no way to contact the moderator privately. Period.

So, what you can do instead? Contact Stack Exchange team, who is responsible for the moderator.

How do to that? Just click the "contact us" link in the bottom of any page, and choose "Other" under "What can we help you with?" section, then explain what exactly you want to know and why.

This can be seen only by Stack Exchange employees, who won't share it with anyone, and they can contact you back via email - that's as private as you can get.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer. My only problem with this is, that although they might forward the request to the moderator, it would be something out of their direct responsibility and thus I can't want any cooperation from them. But generally, in similar cases, it is also a possibilty (if there is a significant chance it is relevant also for them).

Comment: Just to clarify, even if a moderator has contact information on their profile contacting them outside of the normal SE channels isn't appropriate.  If someone emails me about one of my actions as a moderator, I'll direct them to Meta or to the SE contact. The preference would be to keep those discussions within the network so there is a record of it.

Comment: @bluefeet this better be made clear then in the profile. Otherwise leaving contact information is kind of inviting others to, well, contact you.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Which is partly why I have _If you have questions about moderation, then post on meta or chat. I won't discuss this elsewhere._ in my profile. ;P

Comment: A requirement of being a moderator should by that they provide some reasonable channel for communication.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy not really. Being contacted in private is NOT part of being a moderator, and should not be, in my opinion.