# Is it possible to flag a revision of a tag in order to get some clarification/guidance?

Tags: support, tags, flags, moderators, revision-history

I edited one tag in Stack Overflow and a moderator reverted it to be blank (first commit).
Tag is [hpcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hpcc) and the edit is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39416279/revisions

I would like to get some understanding of what I did wrong and see if I can amend it.
I've read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294695/what-is-the-best-way-to-contact-a-moderator-privately) that I should *not* contact a moderator privately.

I also read that the best way seems to flag the edition... but I cannot find where to flag. Nor I can find any text where the moderator explains the reason for her change.

Am I missing something? I can easily find a flag link to flag questions or answers... but cannot find (if it exists) the link for flagging a post revision.

So my question is:

**How can I flag an edition of one tag made a moderator in order to get some clarification/guidance on how to fix it?**

Comment: The bulk of the text is copied from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HPCC with tiny alterations (notably, a dropped comma, (2011) added, and "similar to Hadoop" added. Wouldn't surprise me if there's an exact match somewhere too, but it's more than enough text to qualify as plagiarism

Comment: lol. I also edited that wikipedia page.. long time ago (user is cad). Thanks for answering @zoe. So...  may I try to create a better and original description?

Comment: @OscarFoley feel free to - as long as it's original content, it's good to go. Please, do review this before doing so, though: [How do I write a good tag wiki?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/how-do-i-write-a-good-tag-wiki-is-it-okay-to-use-copy-content-published-elsewhe/318338#318338)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll try a better tag description. Cheers!

Comment: I still wonder.. is it possible to flag a tag revision?

Comment: @OscarFoley best you can likely do is custom flag one of your own posts with a link to the specific tag revision and your query

Answer (score 4):

> How can I flag an edition of one tag

You cannot. Wikis and their revisions are not flaggable (probably should be as there are a lot of plagiarised wikis, but the whole tagging system is an unloved child of Stack Exchange and haven't received any attention for several years). You can start a Meta discussion just as you have done here — it's usually sufficient to get things sorted out.

> I would like to get some understanding of what I did wrong

As mentioned by [Zoe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6296561/zoe-stands-with-ukraine), the moderator who rolled back your edit:

> The bulk of the text is copied from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HPCC with tiny alterations (notably, a dropped comma, (2011) added, and "similar to Hadoop" added. Wouldn't surprise me if there's an exact match somewhere too, but it's more than enough text to qualify as plagiarism

While in many cases (likely including yours), copying and pasting from an external resource such as Wikipedia is done with good intentions it, unfortunately, creates far more issues than it solves (relicensing and lack of proper attribution under the [CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license).

What's more, defining what something *is* is not what we have tag wikis and excerpts for. They are supposed to give guidance to users adding the tags to their posts (the fact that nobody reads them is unfortunate but does not mean the goal is not there). It's nice when the description is included, of course, but it should not constitute the whole body of the wiki.

> see if I can amend it

You still can. Create a new tag wiki that is not copied and provide usage guidance for the tag such as accompanying tags, etc. The [How do I write a good tag wiki? Is it okay to use/copy content published elsewhere?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318337/11407695) FAQ entry has a detailed description of what is considered a good tag wiki / excerpt.

Comment: Also worth noting that while tag wikis cannot be flagged, flagging a regular post instead is an accepted alternative, at least as long as you don't expect a long and/or detailed reply. We're constrained to 200 character replies (which is _so_ annoying, for the record)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine yeah, I wanted to add that but decided to leave it to those with the authority to speak for the mod team. Re: limit - yeah, I know, even [dug up the history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412818/11407695) of complaints about the length of replies :)

Comment: I don't have any problem with the character limit. I just type whatever I need to say and expect the reader to be able to fig