# Should I point to other answers (in the same question) or avoid overlapping with them?

Tags: discussion, answers

Say I answer a question and my answer gets upvoted (maybe even accepted).

Then, another answer pops up (in the same question) or I later notice an already existing answer (again, in the same question) with valid/valuable information that's not present in my answer.

In that case, which option is preferrable?

1. For the sake of *completeness*, edit my answer to include at least a brief mention of the information presented in the other answer (with an attribution or link). The rationale is that many people (including me) tend to read only the highest voted answer(s) and it's better if these answers are as complete as possible.
2. For the sake of *not overlapping* with the other answer (and not feeling like I'm partially "stealing" someone else's upvotes for simply mentioning their thought), leave my answer as it is (without a mention of the other information, at all). The rationale is that it's not my responsibility to ensure that people read all the information in the page (by referencing it in my own answer).

Comment: option #1 looks safer (especially if that _other_ answer was posted by [BalusC](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288242/839601):). One only would better avoid [overquoting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Overquoting) if they pick that option

Comment: @gnat One small clarification (in case I phrased the question ambiguously): I'm talking about *mentioning* vs *not mentioning*, not about *quoting* vs *mentioning* - I've edited to point that out more clearly. In any case, can you post your input as an answer?

Comment: I see. Then it more likely depends on how you feel about _your_ answer, on whether it feels incomplete without the reference or not. If it feels incomplete, you better add the reference. Otherwise, it makes better sense to use other means to promote good content - upvote, bounty, comments (I need time to figure if I can build a solid answer from my comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the readers of your answer. Unless you designed and explicitly presented it as a ["reference farm"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/108298/31260), you better avoid turning it into one. With this in mind, first thing to consider is whether *your answer* feels incomplete without a reference to another one or not.

If your answer is okay on its own, it makes better sense to use other means to promote good content in another one - upvote, bounty, editing, comments. Spare readers from redundant effort - redundant because they already have means to easily find another answer.

On the other hand, if other answer adds something that is necessary for readers of your answer to be aware of, you better refer it. Rationale is, again, to minimize their efforts, but in this case it goes the other way. If you don't refer an important addition, they would have to spend extra effort to figure that something is missing in your answer and where to get it.

In the latter case, it would be safer to not just [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) to another answer but also briefly summarize (not [overquote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Overquoting)) it, for its author has ability and right to remove it [for their own reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288242/839601).