# Are internal link-only answers advisable?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

I believe it is advisable to provide link-only answers when linking to content on Stack Overflow, and the standard advice to provide a summary isn't necessary, because the linked answer may evolve over time and the summary may become obsolete. I'd like to hear what others think.

**Marking as duplicate** might not be appropriate, e.g., one question might be a special case of another, thus an answer to one question, might not be an answer to the special case of the question.

Comment: Here is an example of when link-only answers are advisable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33764971/3664487

Comment: i mean... you could just mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @KevinB, sometimes this is possible, but not always. The above example demonstrates such a case. (One answer appears in the context of *Sign APK without putting keystore info in build.gradle*, whereas the other appears in the context of *How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?*)

Comment: If the answer to question A is also the answer to question B, is question A not a duplicate of question B? of course it's a duplicate. but.... in this case there are subtle differences between the two questions that do make them unique. Shouldn't you then modify the answer to tailor it to the "special case of the other"? If the answer is still the same, then maybe the subtle differences aren't enough to make it not a duplicate.

Comment: @KevinB, in the above example, I provided an answer to the more general question (*How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?*). Subsequently, I read a special case of the question (*Sign APK without putting keystore info in build.gradle*) and provided a link-only answer. In this case, my answer to the general question was also an answer to the special case, because the special case happens to be the "right" way of doing things (putting sensitive information in build files is *really* dumb).

Comment: So, essentially, we have two questions. "How do i do x", and "How do i do x *without doing y*". All answers to question 2 are valid answers to question 1, but only some answers to question 1 are valid answers to question 2. All answers in question 2 are the "correct" or "best practice" way of solving the problem, so maybe the right move would be to mark question 1 as a dupe of question 2.

Comment: Or to simply provide the link to the other question in comments, but a dupe closure would be a far better signpost.

Comment: @KevinB, I suppose that depends on the dupe policy. There are special cases when "best practice" doesn't apply, e.g., when you're operating outside of standard practice. (In the example, this could be the case when keystore info isn't sensitive, for instance, in non-production environments.)

Comment: @gnat, which bit is a duplicate?

Comment: this bit: "See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)"

Comment: basically, a link to another answer or resource is not an answer and should not be provided as one. (i don't see how this is a dupe of that though, since you're requesting that there should be an exception.)

Comment: Important thing to remember is duplicate closure doesn't make the question hidden, it simply makes it a signpost and disallows further answers from being posted on that question. The existing answers will remain, and a link to the duplicate will be visible on the target question in the "linked" section.

Comment: (In the example that I cited, I have now flagged a duplicate.)

Answer (score 22):

If the same answer applies to both questions, modulo trivial surface differences, it's a duplicate. [I don't know of any especially solid counter-examples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267318/are-there-any-non-trivial-examples-of-exact-duplicate-answers-to-non-duplicate-q).

If the answer must be modified to actually answer the question, it *should* be modified. I.e. an answer written up, possibly using the original as a quoted source. In this case, there's no need to worry about a provided summary getting stale, since the whole point is that you customized it to correctly answer the question.

So no. I will continue to flag/recommend deletion on **all** link-only answers, including SO-internal, and I strongly recommend everyone else on SO do the same. There is no reason not to.

Comment: also worth keeping in mind that authors have a right to delete their answers ([some do that a lot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288242/839601 "example"))

Comment: "What color is the sky?"  Blue.  "What color is my car?" Blue.  Not the same question at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Per the linked discussion, such questions are too broad to be left open anyway, or are lacking details, or any answer worth leaving would be much longer than that to actually include an explanation... and the explanation would make those two answers entirely different.