# LQP - Delete reason for link-only to Stack Overflow answers

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers, vote-to-delete

In the Low Quality Posts, I frequently see answers receiving the standard comment ...

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

... when the answer links to another answer on Stack Overflow.

However, in this case, I think *the last thing we want* is someone to copy parts of the Stack Overflow answers (or the whole answer) and just add a link to the source. We'd rather want them to vote as duplicate when it's appropriate, or share the link in a comment. I'm an optimist, so I think such link answers are often posted by inexperienced, benevolent users that aren't yet fully aware of how the site works. This standard comment doesn't help them build this awareness. On the contrary, it teaches them bad practice.

This happens often enough for me to wish there was another standard comment I could use in these situations. It should explain that voting to close as duplicate or commenting may have been better alternatives and that linking to other Stack Overflow answers is useful when it illustrates or supports parts of your own answer but should never be an answer in itself. I'm sure someone more eloquent than me will be able to compose a concise text for this.

Comment: related: [Internal link-only answers are advisable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311044/internal-link-only-answers-are-advisable)

Comment: Seems like if the answer is a link to another SO post then the question is a dupe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree we need another canned reason in the LQP queue. I like Code Grays proposed text in a comment, and I am blatantly copying it because it think it is the best way to formulate this.

Add another canned reason stating:

> Please don't post answers that consist merely of a link to other $SITENAME$ questions. Instead, [flag](//$SITEURL$/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other question. If the questions are not duplicates, you must provide a complete, self-contained answer that is tailored specifically to the question being asked, providing [attribution](//$SITEURL$/help/referencing) to the users whose answers you are drawing information from.

Answer (score 3):

In [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) we have some [canned comments](https://comments.socvr.org/) that help with these

> Please don't post link only answers to other Stack Exchange questions. Instead, include the essential portions of the answer here, and *tailor the answer to this specific question.*

I've actually had good success with the above in getting people who post link-only answers to other SO questions to add some more content

Comment: Surely you should be trying to get them to dupe close/flag not duplicating content?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder not all questions that have 1 similar answer are duplicates. Duplicates are for when all possible answers for A are the same for B, since they are asking the same thing.

Comment: @Braiam I understand duplicates I just think it's worth mentioning it in the comment. That sort of comment if placed everywhere leads to people not understanding the system properly.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Understand I pair these with a LQP flag. But the problem is that it's not necessarily a dupe. I've answered a few questions with a quote from another question that wasn't necessarily a dupe. Sometimes a related question helps with answering. Since we can't be expected to understand all questions, I tend to leave it to people in that tag to flag/close dupes

Comment: @Machavity I agree, and I know you're more active in moderation than I am. I was mainly pointing it out so people not so familiar don't go blanket posting this everywhere which will do more harm than good.

Comment: @Machavity If the answerer felt that posting a link to the other answer with no additional information was a good answer, then clearly they feel that there *aren't* any differences in this question, and it *would* be a suitable duplicate.  If they felt that additional information was necessary, they would have already provided that additional information.

Comment: A better comment, taking TheLethalCoder's point into account, is: `Please don't post answers that consist merely of a link to other $SITENAME$ questions. Instead, [flag](//$SITEURL$/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other question. If the questions are not duplicates, you must provide a complete, self-contained answer that is tailored specifically to the question being asked, providing [attribution](//$SITEURL$/help/referencing) to the users whose answers you are drawing information from.`

Comment: And many others agree with @Servy: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311044/are-internal-link-only-answers-advisable

Comment: @CodyGray That's exactly what I'm looking for :)