# Should I delete an answer that the asker did not accept?

Tags: discussion

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063954/modify-configuration-properties-of-ejb-jar-xml-during-deployment-in-glassfish-4/35677257) but OP turned out not to use it. I'm fairly confident that my approach was technically sound (albeit not my favourite), I was awarded the bounty on it but I've since deleted it because OP didn't use the answer. A few things of note:

- OP framed the question like a portable, code-based solution was preferred (otherwise, a simple google search would have turned up the "solution" he arrived at)
- I referred to a barely used mechanism, [`@AroundConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/interceptor/AroundConstruct.html) in my solution. I should also mention that based on a search, no other SO answer uses this mechanism.
- Yeah, I'm slightly heartbroken that my answer wasn't used

Is it ill-advised to have deleted the unused answer?

Comment: If it was useful, no reason really to delete it.

Comment: You have two upvotes, no downvotes, and a bounty. Clearly your answer has helped someone! Certainly this answer shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: The upvotes and bounty were granted for an earlier approach that I erased because I found it to be wrong @FredLarson

Comment: Your goal should surely be "What makes this StackOverflow page the most useful resource for people with this problem?" not "What satisfies this one person?". The asker may have different requirements or just be stupid and reject your perfectly good answer, but that doesn't mean others won't get here via Google and be saved by your work.

Comment: Perfectly fine to leave it, most of the time on other people's questions, I use the non-accepted answer as they apply to me more. The idea is to give a range of ideas applicable to different scenarios, as well as answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it ill-advised to have deleted the unused answer?

It depends.

- A deleted answer can gather no upvotes, so it cannot contribute to your reputation. You never know, until you actually give it some time, how many people an answer will help and how much reputation it may gain you. So if your goal is to help people and/or to gain rep, deleting an answer might just be shooting yourself in the foot. (A vast percentage of my own rep comes from one answer that has been upvoted nearly 700 times, but which the OP didn't accept.)
- On the other hand, one of the things I like about the Stack Overflow format is that you can answer and then later delete your answer in a nimble way. I certainly have often deleted an unaccepted answer, because I felt that, in the long run, it was deservedly overshadowed by the accepted answer or by other answers. I guessed wrong, or I didn't express myself clearly enough, or my answer was incomplete, and other answers took the palm, and rightly so; I had nothing more to contribute that had not already been stated by others, and what I had contributed wasn't all that good.

In sum, Stack Overflow is crowd-sourcing, so you might want to let the crowd help you decide. There's no time limit on deletions, so you can revisit the matter in a month or a year and see what's happened. Keep in mind, it's not about the OP, who after all may not recognize the best answer when he sees it; it's about collecting the best possible encyclopedia of answers.

Comment: I'm not sure that 4.4% counts as a "vast" percentage, but I concur... [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13254002/211627) originally received a single downvote (since removed). I decided to just leave it and [a couple weeks later](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13254002/timeline) it got an upvote. It's slowly but steadily grown in vote count, and now it's my most highly upvoted answer (representing nearly 4% of my rep... so I guess it's "vast").

Answer (score 19):

> Is it ill-advised to have deleted the unused answer?

If you think that there would be other people faced with the problem the OP described in the question, and that they would find your answer more useful than the other answer, then yes, you've made the world a worse place by deleting the answer.

If, on the other hand, there either wouldn't be anyone else ever facing that problem, or those other people would be better off reading the other answer(s) than yours, then yes, deleting your answer has made the internet a better place.

Answer (score 14):

If it might ever be useful to a future visitor, and as long as it's relevant to the question, don't delete an answer.

I suggest you undelete it and let it stand for what it is. Voting, bounties and points are all secondary to content. You shouldn't feel like you need to delete something because of one person (the OP) or because of the bounty that was awarded.

Answer (score 4):

I see no reason why you should delete an answer which you think solves the purpose of problem stated by OP. That's why there is an upvoting system to make sure the best content rises on top. I have sometimes seen the OP accept an answer based on his/her ability to judge the answer and which he/she thinks easily worked for him/her. But it may not always be true. The other answer may provide much additional information regarding the root cause of the problem, and possible aversion techniques.

**There are many instances where other answers are more highly voted up than the accepted answer, and clearly the quality differs.**

Answer (score 2):

This isn't anything new; [someone's already done this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288242/1079354). There's also the matter of what the check mark actually signifies, and in the grand scheme of things, it's actually *very little* - it only ever means anything to the OP.

That said, I feel you shouldn't delete your answer.  You're not just answering for the OP, but you're answering for anyone else that may come across this situation.  Losing answers because the OP didn't select that as *their* favorite shouldn't happen.