# "Unfriendly" flag on a comment threatening to delete his answer declined?

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags, unfriendly-or-unkind

Yesterday I asked a debugging question that didn't attract much attention.

Later a user posted an answer that looked decent to me. There are no problem with the content, but I was 1) doing school homework and assignments, 2) planning to wait for some extra time for more input, so I didn't respond to the answer right away (I had my browser open).

After less than 4 hours and a half, the same user posted a comment with the following content:

> You are not interested by the answer ? I delete it ?

Due to time zone difference, I was sleeping at that time, and only checked out Stack Overflow this morning after waking up, which was already 8 hours after the above comment was posted. Nothing further happened and the answer stayed sound. Seeing that comment, I immediately responded with:

> @*redacted* Don't be so mean, man, I was busy with school homework back then...

After wandering around Meta for some time, I noticed that the comment wasn't appropriate on Stack Overflow, so I went back and flagged it as "unfriendly or unkind".

The confusing thing is, just a few minutes later a moderator saw the flag, deleted his comment and my reply, upvoted my question, and **declined the flag**.

That means the comment wasn't "unfriendly or unkind", right?

Comment: Odds are that was either a misclick or a misunderstanding. Misclick is obvious ("delete" looks almost indistinguishable from "dismiss" in the mod tools, at least to me). Misunderstanding could be because the moderator thought the commenter was offering to clean up after himself by deleting a useless answer. Unless you know that the comment just came clean out of nowhere, you'd miss the bullying aspect. It looks like someone with weak English skills offering to remove an answer that you did not find helpful.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm still confused, when I read the comment listed, even coming out of the blue, I still read it as "someone with weak English skills offering to remove an answer that" they thought might not be helpful. That sounds to me like someone misunderstanding Stack Overflow and the lack of response, not someone attempting to bully. Even with your comment saying that there's a bullying aspect that's easily missed, I'm really struggling to see it, even though I'm looking for how to interpret that comment with bad intention. Could you elaborate so I can understand what's bullying/mean about it?

Comment: Meh. I understand the declining of the flag. Unless there is more going on than that comment, I find "unfriendly" unfit for that comment. We should not offend others, but also we should not offend so easily.

Comment: I'm not sure what was meant, @Davy. But I can kind of see iBug's interpretation, that this comment just came out of the blue, posted on the question by someone who had left an answer that had not received any upvotes. Kind of like a "hey, I answered! pay attention to me, or I'm taking my toys and going home" sort of thing. Still not really rude, but definitely unnecessary.

Comment: *This reminds of a top SO user deleting answers when OP was unresponsive*, it's not so strange that some people like some feedback after they spent time to answer

Comment: It might be natural to desire feedback, but that isn’t how Stack Overflow works, @Petter. It isn’t a real-time chat platform (well, Q&A isn’t). You aren’t entitled to a response, timely or otherwise. Answers may get no feedback at all, and yet that’s okay, because they may be useful to anonymous users.

Comment: @CodyGray sure, my comment was only related to that it's normal that users may ask in comments for feedback (hence nothing unfriendly about it) and yes some user do really dislike "radio silence" and even delete answer *[getting suspended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288229/)* unfortunately google+ is not a thing anymore, but for those who don't know his reasons was "unresponsive OP"-->probably useless answer. Right or wrong behind answers there is effort and it can be "friendly" to acknowledge this effort in some manner, and diligently later self clean up (if just a NLN comment)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> The confusing thing is, just a few minutes later a moderator saw the flag, deleted his comment and my reply, upvoted my question, and declined the flag.

I deleted the comment because it was not constructive. I deleted your comment because it was obsolete after deleting the previous comment. I upvoted the question because it was well written.

I declined the comment flag as there was nothing unfriendly there. The user was trying to ask if they need to delete their answer, just in case the answer is not necessary due to it being incorrect/wrong. There are numerous posters who want some feedback from the OP so that they can improve their post. This user was probably one of them.

The underlying issue here is, many users see the "last seen" and assume that the OP is ignoring their answer, and therefore either comment asking for more information from the poster, or just delete their answer. The users are not aware that on Stack Exchange, we post answers for the community and not for just the OP.

Feel free to use a "no longer needed" comment flag on those, if you come across any answerer asking the OP to look at their post, or to accept an answer. Do not use the "unfriendly" flag here, unless the user is really unkind in their comment.

Comment: I agree with this, I am also some times tempted to ask the OP if my answer solved the problem they are facing, as many a times the question is answered and then there is radio silence from the OP after that, I have learnt to ignore that now, but when I started answering I used to write let me know if that worked or not at the end of the answer. I never deleted an answer that was correct, but yes I think OP has the responsibility to respond to accept one of the answer which worked and if none worked, comment what failed.