# Destroying possibly good content for high acceptance rate

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, deleted-answers

So recently I came accross this data query: [Users with highest accept rate of their answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1433/users-with-highest-accept-rate-of-their-answers)

I noticed that the top results here have an *incredible* high acceptance rate, one of them even having a 100% acceptance rate. After checking out his profile, I realised he (among others on the top list) must have simply deleted their answers that didn't get accepted.

But aren't they actively destroying possibly good content by doing that? Even if the answer didn't get accepted, it could still be helpful for future readers.

What do you think of this behaviour? Should something be done against this? Why would someone find acceptance rate so important?

Comment: It was not accepted...so it was not the best answer for that question. I don't see how value got lost. What would be an acceptable acceptance-rate if 100% is suspicious?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146403/248731, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270274/3001761

Comment: Eh, too much guesswork for my taste. That said, thanks for pointing me to that query, it was quite surprising to find out that I have the highest accept (on Programmers, for users with over 100 answers).

Comment: @rene: What about upvoted answers then?

Comment: @rene: accepted => best answer? That's tenuous, and quite often flat-out wrong.

Comment: Pfff, I assumed that the rep hungry users would not delete their own highly-upvoted answers. User that care might go over their answers and remove the ones that add no value. I don't think those kind of users should be penalized. I assume good faith, is that wrong?

Comment: @rene I still disagree, as long as an answer does not have a negative score, it can usually still add value. Maybe it has a score of 0 now, but that doesn't mean noone can upvote it later when they stumble across it.

Comment: We have to agree to disagree then. I'm not convinced this is a problem, I think the answer provided covers all bases and has my upvote.

Comment: @rene: This isn't a widespread problem, no. That being said, it doesn't mean the problem doesn't exist. I can tell you that at least one user returned by the query absolutely doesn't care about whether their answers add any value to the community except the OP of each question.

Comment: @BoltClock and how much 'value' (let's define that as the score of the post) is been deleted and how much 'value' is left on those questions? I promise this will be my last comment on this ;)

Comment: You *assume* it is because of high acceptance rate, but there are plenty of other possible explanations.  Maybe the user wants to look good when potential employers look through their profile.  Maybe he's not thrilled about having to maintain the post for the rest of his natural life.   Answers have too many strings attached, very hard to unwire yourself until [this happens](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288274/17034) some day.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> But aren't they actively destroying possibly good content by doing that? Even if the answer didn't get accepted, it could still be helpful for future readers.

If they **are** deleting unaccepted answers, then: yes, they could be removing good content. The accepted answer is the best answer *for the OP*, but that isn't the only person we care about - this is why you get rep for upvotes on answers irrespective of whether they're accepted.

However, most of the time when a user reaches his daily rate limit (see below), it's users pruning old or duplicate answers.

> Why would someone find acceptance rate so important?

I have no idea! If they've deleted unaccepted answers with upvotes, it's actually *costing* them rep. to keep their acceptance rate up.

> Should something be done against this?

**No, I don't think so.** For one thing, there's only three users with 20 or more answers at 100% (who could have got there without deleting anything, remember), and the acceptance rate seems to drop off pretty quickly. There are already limits to prevent users deleting too many of their answers:

- A maximum of five answers per day can be deleted;
- Every time a user hits this daily limit, a flag is automatically generated so mods can look into it and determine if any action needs to be taken;
- [Mods do warn users about deleting good content if they are found to be systematically deleting answers with more than a few upvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293617/destroying-possibly-good-content-for-high-acceptance-rate#comment190001_293620); and
- There are disincentives to discourage the behaviour (losing rep if your answer had upvotes).

If an individual user decides they're happy with that trade-off, I think that's fair enough, and it doesn't seem to be a particularly large problem.

---

That said, if there are *individual cases* where an unaccepted but valuable answer is deleted by its author, I think that should be brought up, either by flagging for mod attention or on Meta - we don't want to lose good content, and it can be dissociated from the author's account if they really don't want it in their answer list.

Comment: We do warn users about deleting good content if we find them systematically deleting answers with more than a few upvotes (even if they're not ragequitting). But if a user is, say, cleaning up overlooked duplicate answers to easy questions to reduce clutter, more power to them.

Comment: It's also worth noting that every time a user hits the daily rate limit, a flag is automatically generated so we can look into it and determine if any action needs to be taken.

Comment: @BoltClock good to know, thanks. I agree that there's a major difference between pruning zero-voted answers on questions with lots of others and removing good answers just because they didn't get accepted. Do you have a sense of how often this is happening; is it a big issue?

Comment: `There are already limits to prevent users deleting too many of their answers (maximum of five per day)` Ah I didn't actually know about this. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I think what the OP is describing is more of an edge case. We get plenty of these automatic flags but the vast majority of them are simply users pruning old answers.

Comment: `it can be dissociated from the author's account if they really don't want it in their answer list` This is actually a pretty good idea. Perhaps we should encourage these odd cases (like the 100% acceptance guy) to change their answers to Community wiki instead of simply deleting them. I don't have enough rep to view deleted answers, but maybe someone that does could go over his profile and see if there were any answers that are worth being undeleted and made into Community wiki?

Comment: @DarkAshelin CW is there for content that is being curated by multiple people and that isn't representative of a single user's contributions.  It's not a tool to just let people post answers without affecting their stats.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287603/1927206