# Delete Questions/Answers too often?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, rate-limiting, bad-questions

Is it generally a bad thing to do, if you *hypothetically* delete a little bit too much of your own Q/A?

Is there a limit?

Are there some consequences given it is interpreted as not helpful?

PS: I searched Meta and did a bit googling but found nothing, so here it is..

Comment: There is a daily limit IIRC; moderators will intervene if it's a clear case of ragequitting. You an always have your contributions disassociated from your name/account.

Comment: related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262643/do-you-get-question-bans-by-deleting-your-own-posts?rq=1

Comment: also related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311810/can-self-censoring-end-up-with-a-question-ban http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide

Answer (score 12):

> Is it generally a bad thing to do, if you hypothetically delete a little bit too much of your own Q/A?

That depends on what you delete. If it is only negative scored, non-accepted posts you'll be out of trouble (unless you're in or close to a question or answer ban) but deleting posts that are accepted or have a high score might be a case of destroying valuable content. That can be reversed by undelete votes from users with delete vote privileges.

> Is there a limit?

Yes, there is. You're only allowed to delete 5 answers per day as explained in the [answer from Bart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270275)

> Are there some consequences given it is interpreted as not helpful?

It might if your delete actions raise a moderator flag. The system detects certain delete behavior (upvoted posts, accepted answers) so a moderator can step in to prevent any loss of quality posts due to rage quits or other cases of abuse or mishaps. One of their options is a [temporary suspension](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288229/why-was-balusc-temporarily-suspended-from-so) of the user so the moderator team can sort out what is going on.

Keep in mind that the sole purpose of Stack Overflow is to be a repository of quality questions and answers. If you feel you need to delete posts often go ask yourself if you should have posted at all. <s>Crap</s>Low quality posts that aren't on the site doesn't need moderation or deletion and doesn't set a bad example for other users. This is probably more troublesome.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Well, never have I deleted anything upvoted.

Comment: "deleting posts that are accepted or have a high score is a case of destroying valuable content." not necessarily. I deleted a Q&A pair with 10 upvotes because the post was getting in the way of people looking relevant information. Valuable content that needs to get deleted to make way to more useful content wasn't valuable to begin with.

Comment: @Braiam yeah, reworded slightly

Comment: I'm not sure why you answered this, rather than closing it as a dupe, yes, you could add, there was an addition question in there, that is also a dupe. So does putting together duplicated questions no longer mean they're dupes?

Comment: @Yvette Because I felt none of the duplicates I found addressed the question completely. The current dupe target isn't correct IMHO. Beyond that, I want to raise the number of posts I have in the support tag so I can, oh irony, dupe hammer support questions.

Comment: @rene too funny! Good one and I [tag:support] that :D